# Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

Over the past week, I've made several fairly significant changes to the close reasons and associated documentation on Stack Overflow. I've been monitoring and tweaking those changes, and believe they should now be reasonably stable; so here is a summary of the currently-available close reasons, with changes and their rationale noted.

### Background

In June 2013, we made [a major set of changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) to the reasons available for closing questions. As a result of these changes, several very heavily-used reasons were significantly narrowed in scope or no longer available at all. Simultaneously, the scope of the Off Topic reason was expanded to include site-specific reasons that could be used to provide specific guidance for common misconceptions regarding a site's scope... Or fill in the gaps left by the changes to the other close reasons.

At launch, I created and added a set of predefined off-topic reasons for every Stack Exchange site, including Stack Overflow. SO presented some unique challenges due to its size and history: in many cases, the usage of existing close reasons had deviated significantly from their original intent. So I spent a lot of time sampling actual closed questions and attempting to classify the problems underlying them before [proposing an initial set of off-topic reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185142/what-should-the-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be-for-stack-overflow). I noted at the time that I would try to revise them based on how they were *actually used* after the changes went live.

Over the months that followed, it became apparent that two of those off-topic reasons were particularly unclear: the one intended for debugging questions lacking in code, and the one intended for homework / assignment dumps lacking any clear understanding of the question (or lacking a question entirely). These problems were discussed extensively in the following threads:

- [Improving "demonstrate a minimal understanding" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason)
- [Questions .. must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258856/questions-must-describe-the-specific-problem-and-include-valid-code-to-reprod)

### Top-level changes: "unclear what you're asking"

This is the only top-level close reason to see changes at this time. Adjusting the wording of top-level close reasons isn't easy: they instantly apply to *every* site, so tailoring them to a specific audience isn't really feasible. I've attempted to work around this by deferring specific guidance to [a site-specific /help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **unclear what you're asking**

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

That last sentence is the addition here. The page it links to is customized to Stack Overflow, and currently being revised and discussed here: [Can we create a Help Center topic that outlines what a SSCCE / MWE means for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta)

This close reason *should* cover the bulk of what was being legitimately closed for "minimal understanding". Questions where...

- ...No specific problem is identified
- ...A specific scenario or set of requirements are described, but the asker fails to identify what he wants as a result of this.
- ...The wording or formatting is so poor as to make reading the question exceptionally difficult.

### Off-topic reason changes

As noted, two off-topic reasons were removed. As of today, two new ones have been added:

#### Typos and "the problem went away" questions

These questions are often resolved by correcting a simple syntax error or by the asker himself after realizing he was looking at the wrong code, forgot to restart the server, etc. They tend to be an embarrassment to the asker *and* a source of unhelpful noise for others with superficially-similar problems:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Note that the original wording proposed for this reason has been tweaked several times in response to confusion observed here on Meta and on Stack Overflow itself. The target remains the same though: "face-palm" problems that no longer affect the asker and whose solutions will never benefit anyone else.

#### Debugging question missing crucial information

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

This addresses a specific subset of "unclear what you're asking" questions, so I originally omitted it to see how often its absence made things difficult for either closers or askers. It didn't take long; this is a *very* common problem, so calling it out directly and offering specific guidance is well-worth chewing up an extra slot in the list. Note that this is *very* similar to one of the removed off-topic reasons.

### A note on SSCCE

One of the reoccurring complaints with the old off-topic reasons was the reference to http://sscce.org/. While a very nicely-written and information-rich resource, it wasn't specific to Stack Overflow and the wording of the close reason subtly implied that including such code was a *requirement* for asking a question, which was never the intent of the page's author. As a result, *both* of the new off-topic reasons reference [a Stack Overflow-specific help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and attempt to cast it as a useful resource for helping others reproduce your problem and *not* a laundry-list of additional hard requirements.

### A note on Effort

There were a handful of people who interpreted "minimal understanding" as a euphemism for "visible effort" or even "a wall of code". That was never the intent, as it's never been something I've observed as a widespread *implicit* requirement on Stack Overflow: a clearly-written, reasonably-scoped, answerable programming question should strive to include as much information as necessary *and no more*; doing otherwise is a much more frequent source of frustration. You can find extensive discussion on this topic here: [Should Stack Exchange in general be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

### In closing

I apologize for any confusion generated by these changes; unfortunately, it can be hard to stay agile on a site as large as Stack Overflow, where every change is [guaranteed to make *someone's* life harder](http://xkcd.com/1172/). As the many meta discussions over the past months demonstrate, a review of close reasons has been long overdue; I sincerely believe the eventual results of these changes will be easier for all involved in the long-term, but I will try to do a better job of responding more quickly to complaints or confusion going forward.

Comment: The featured tag does not do on MSO/SO what it does on other sites, @gnat. It'll increase visibility on MSO only, and the folks who see it tend to be the same folks who've already been party to all of the related discussions. I've added a link to it from SO's bulletin board though.

Comment: I like both new close reasons very much. The "debug question"  one could be further enhanced by having pointers to additional info on how to debug stuff. That info would have to be tag-specific, though, and I can't think of a way to automate that without goign back to the old idea of canned comments

Comment: ... maybe if we, in a site-wide effort, ensured that every major tag wiki has a "debugging basics" section? And then added a link to that section to the close reason? Hmm

Comment: Yeah, that would work *if* we could do section links, @Pëkka. [Vote for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts).

Comment: It seems inappropriate to me that "not enough diagnostic information" is under "off-topic" rather than "unclear". It's not that such a question is inherently inappropriate for the site (unlike the other off-topic reasons) - it's just that it's not got enough information at the moment. It feels to me like "unclear" means "can't be answered"; "off-topic" means "*shouldn't* be answered on this site". Not providing enough information is an example of the former, not the latter.

Comment: It *is* weird, @Jon - but I can't add sub-reasons to Unclear, and there are an awful lot of questions that benefit from the additional guidance so... Ugly hack.

Comment: @Shog9: Well that feels like a problem that should be fixed then. You're probably in a better position to request that than I am (as a non-mod) :)

Comment: Are `icanhazcode` questions still Too Broad?  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216577

Comment: They certainly *can be*, @Robert. Too Broad hasn't changed though; folks just aren't using it enough.

Comment: *"folks just aren't using it enough"* ... that statement will never come back to bite you. ;)

Comment: If working here has taught me *anything*, it's that everything comes back to bite me sooner or later, @Bart.

Comment: To be fair, it takes a mental leap to apply "Too Broad" to questions like the one [Robert references](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216576/how-should-do-my-homework-questions-be-closed-missing-demonstrate-minimal-u). It's a *fine* leap, but it turns on the single word "good" in "good answers would be too long for this format".

Comment: @JonSkeet if you can't get decent backing for a feature request then there's no hope for the rest of us. I for one would strongly support that

Comment: @Shog9 ** CHOMP! **

Comment: Wonderful. Now can we do something about the readability of the text? A simply `line-height` tweak to the `.action-list .action-name` span would do the trick. http://i.imgur.com/Q4iYxSS.gif

Comment: Please post a [meta-tag:design] [meta-tag:feature-request] for this, @j08691

Comment: @Shog9 - I did...half a year ago.

Comment: @j08691 [this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186868/please-fix-the-big-gap-in-the-line-height-of-the-new-off-topic-reason-list)

Comment: @Joe - a yup, sorry I should've included the link in my last comment. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent changes -- this is a really solid build!

Comment: In my mind, there are 2 types of questions that show no effort: questions that can be found on the first page of a google search (how do I vertically align with CSS?), questions that don't show any code (in the case of CSS questions, they don't even provide markup), or questions that can be answered by RTFM (is there a function that makes a color transparent in Sass?).

Comment: We really do need to add WebApps to the migration list.  People keep trying to use the Super User reason.

Comment: @smci Please take a bit more care in your edits. This isn't a new post. It's from January 2014. The "Last June" text was in the original version, which means it's referring to June of 2013, not June 2017 (3.5 years after it was written).

Comment: @Makyen: then 'Recent changes' is a total misnomer. Why not edit it to correct it being way out-of-date?

Comment: Kudos in the use of *Other - changes specified by user* to provide convenient ability to duplicate that reason. (On downside - I can't give you the exact text because it won't let me look at the menu after having voted -- it is stuck at the [Retract Vote] -- that should be fixed)

Answer (score 35):

Another related issue worth mentioning is that all these changes are always silently introduced. Unless you are some sort of meta-nerd, spending more time on this site than on SO, you get no information about anything.

If the users are supposed to be moderators, then perhaps it would be wise to inform said moderators about changes to the moderation tools? Moderators who hang out on SO and not on this site.

Personally, when this particular change was silently introduced, I just sat there scratching my head while looking for the appropriate close option, which was not appearing, for some strange reason. And since I couldn't find it, I ignored the mediocre "code plz" posts and left them as they were.

This is not unique to this particular change, but to every change of the SO site. You log into SO one day and suddenly the whole edit review system has changed. Or suddenly, posts appear `[on-hold]` instead of `[closed]`. The first reaction to that was "huh, what did I do wrong, did I click the wrong close reason?" Etc etc.

We aren't informed of the change nor about how we are supposed to act on it from now on. We are supposed find the information ourselves, on our own initiative, on the Meta site (where at least I find it hard to sort out "official" threads from random discussions).

This discourages users from moderating the site, ultimately passing more burden upwards to users with more privileges, in the end to the diamond moderators and site admins.

A simple notification message of site changes, sent to all SO users who have the relevant moderator privileges, would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only facility I have for such notifications is email (which would be entirely too much for something like this) and the bulletin board (which I did put this post into, albeit only for a day). I'm trying to avoid over-using the bulletin for now; in the near future [we'll hopefully have a better way of feeding it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own).

Comment: @Shog9 A simple notification system that can be used by diamond moderators would probably be a great tool to have then. Something that pops up among the other SO notifications that you get when someone answers your post, perhaps with a special icon to mark it as important.

Comment: @Shog9, a little banner in the close reason window with a 'who moved my cheese?' and link to this question would probably work. (Like I do for new versions of the AutoComments script). But obviously that is specific to this particular case.

Comment: Inbox everyone? Perhaps not. (As it happens, it wouldn't have worked for me; thanks to Session Restore I was using a really old version of the review page on which the Inbox wasn't actually working; for instance I only found about about the election when I came here to look for the "missing" close reason!)

Comment: @Neil What is the Inbox? I've never seen an inbox round here.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier On the topbar of every StackExchange page, the first icon to the right of the "StackExchange" image is a dropdown for the inbox

Comment: Oh the new comments icon, of course. Never did figure out what it was meant to look like, until now.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is really the kind of questions that go like this:

> "I need some code to solve problem x. I have looked all over the web
>   for it but can't find it. The code should behave as [detailed
>   specification]. Please give me code."

So how do I close vote this?

*"Unclear what you are asking"* No, it is not unclear what they are asking. They are asking for code that behaves in a certain way, for which they provided a specification (likely a copy/paste of homework assignment). The question is perfectly clear, but shouldn't be on SO.

*"off topic because... it lacks sufficient information do diagnose the problem"* No, the poster provided plenty of information.

Other closing reasons than the above ones are even more far-fetched.

We used to have *"Off-topic because questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding..."*, which is the exact reason why the post should be closed: **it is a perfectly clear question with detailed information, but it still off-topic since this isn't a code begging site.**

So please bring back the closing reasons as they were.

---

Also a nitpick, the word "diagnose" seems a bit out of place to me. We are supposed to give an answer to a specific technical question, not to "diagnose problems". If someone asks the question

"Why does the following program suddenly crash"

then the *answer* is:

"it crashes because you are allocating too much static memory in runtime and get a stack overflow, allocate dynamically instead, like this..."

while the *diagnose* is:

"it crashes because you have a stack overflow"

The former is a good answer, while the latter isn't helpful.

Comment: "Unclear" fits your first example perfectly. "*As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*" - you don't know how much programming knowledge this person has. Do they want pseudocode? Do they want the complete program? Can you just show the important bits of code, and leave out the imports / etc? Does an answer need to explain how to set up the development environment? We don't know. It's unclear what they're asking for. They need to "*highlight exactly what [they] need*."

Comment: @jadarnel27 How much knowledge you have is irrelevant, everyone is free to ask questions on SO no matter experience (and experienced programmers asking for free code are just as off-topic as homework questions by beginners). As you can tell from the artificial example, they want code. Whether it is the full program or just an algorithm is also irrelevant, they have shown no effort in understanding the actual problem. They have however highlighted exactly what they need by providing a detailed specification of how the program should behave.

Comment: Asking for code isn't off-topic if the question is asked well (and clearly).  The style of question you describe in your example is unclear (because we don't know what is needed), so it *is* off-topic.  If they described more clearly what they were confused about, or showed some code and where they got stuck, the question would be fine.  See [this great answer by Tim Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason/216496#216496).

Comment: "*How much knowledge you have is irrelevant*" - That is wildly incorrect.  I have posted an answer where the solution was to handle a certain event, so I showed the code that goes in that event, and the OP followed up asking how to attach the event handler to the control in question.  The asker's knowledge-level is often perfectly relevant to the answerers.

Comment: Lundin: before you ask "what close reason should I use?" always ask, "what problem is this question likely to cause other people using this site?" That will generally point you in the right direction.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Sigh. This thread isn't about asking or answering questions. It is about _closing_ questions that are inappropriate. To clarify: you cannot close a post because the OP seems to lack knowledge, and that would be why their knowledge is irrelevant. Of course, if they completely lacks knowledge and expects someone else to do their job, well then the question should be closed.

Comment: @Shog9 Okay so I ask myself that question, the answer is "he is a code beggar who intends to do as little effort as possible to get his homework done." The harm would be: "it annoys every other user of the site, making them less likely to answer questions or even leave SO because code begging decreases the average quality of the topics discussed". How exactly does that point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't see anything about the actual *question* there. What problem is the *question* causing - that's what close reasons are built for, you can't close *people*.

Comment: @Shog9 Then let me do the abstract thinking for you. Change my comment to "the question is begging for homework code, with no effort shown nor any example posted". Or you could just read the above post, where there is an abstract example of a bad question.

Comment: And I'm asking you specifically what problems a given question is going to cause... So perhaps the issue here is that you're fixated on your own abstract template rather than *anything* specific. Here are three questions matching your example - describe the problems in each: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612164/avi-html5-or-jquery-player), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469272/how-do-i-store-a-python-object-in-memory-for-use-by-different-processes), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200917/c-how-to-get-a-binary-representation-of-a-decimal-number)

Comment: @Shog9 1) seems to be asking for a a tool or off-site resource rather than code, so it is possible off-topic for an entirely different reason. I wouldn't close it since I know too little about web stuff to judge it. 2) isn't asking for code so it isn't relevant to this topic and 3) is indeed a code beggar as described, and it was correctly closed because of it.

Comment: @Shog9 The problems caused by 3) were that it annoyed a lot of people, 5 down votes, yielded one bad answer with yet another "read that old floating point link" (which would have been closed as link-only if he had only bothered to link the paper) plus a bunch of snide non-constructive comments. All in all, the question added little of value to the site. So what would _you_ do with question 3), given the currently available closing reasons?

Comment: Number 3 is unclear, @Lundin. His requirements were imprecise, and the answers suffered for it. Given the information presented in comments on the accepted answer, it would be easily possible to clarify it now, but standing alone this is not a good question. #1 is a duplicate, and #2 is a fairly reasonable question (though it could use a bit of copy editing). Unfortunately, all three of them are a rough match for your example template (and for the common interpretation of the MU close reason) - which is why I've backed away from using such approximations to identify questions for closure.

Answer (score 6):

I miss the "minimal understanding" close reason. Sometimes it's just clear that someone is over their head and they're asking for far more than a Q/A forum can reasonably provide. Today I ended up leaving a rude comment out of frustration over not being able to cast a close vote on a question.

Comment: If you're finding yourself frustrated by a question, don't comment - downvote. Please! It does a lot more good than folks realize.

Comment: @Shog9 I use downvotes as a weapon of last resort. It penalizes the recipient and I believe it's unnecessarily discouraging. In this case the question was perfectly legitimate, it's just that they didn't show even the most minimal effort in trying to solve it on their own.

Comment: @MarkRansom If the question didn't show the least bit of effort then it's *not* legitimate, at least not on this site.  If users aren't going to post questions appropriate for this site they *should* be penalized in some small superficial way; if they aren't, and are instead *encouraged* for performing actions we don't want here, then they'll continue to perform them.  If they are discouraged by negative feedback, then not participating at all is still better than participating in a negative manor.  They can either learn to improve, or leave.  Both are **much** more preferable than staying.

Comment: @Servy, the question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392710/extract-rgb-using-simplecv). With the right context it might have been interesting. I *did* say I wanted to close the question, which is the ultimate penalty. Maybe in retrospect a downvote would have sufficed, I don't know.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, the question *got an answer* so closing it afterwards, while helpful, isn't successful in its goal of preventing answers to the question.  The OP is in no way learning to change behavior as a result of the question being closed at this point.  Downvoting on the other hand is informing other readers that the question is of low quality, contributing to a question ban, adding significant signal to the author that something is wrong, etc.

Comment: **YES** - the minimal information reason, **which is indeed the overwhelming close situation in many tags**, must be there.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314902/294884

Answer (score 4):

I came to this post because I keep coming across questions that are clearly about programming then seeing the following as the reason for closing the question:

> off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

The Help Center may say otherwise, but to my eyes, the questions that are supposedly not about programming are almost always about programming *as a reasonable person would define it*.

If I drill down further on "Off Topic", I see the following (paraphrased) reasons:

- Should be on Super User
- Should be on Server Fault
- Seeking product/service recommendation
- Seeking debugging help without good example
- Too narrow or minor
- Should be on another SE site
- Other

Then if you go back to the top level, you see (besides off-topic):

- Duplicate
- Unclear
- Too broad
- Primarily opinion-based

I'm sorry to be negative, but I really struggle with this information architecture and feel it could use a rethink.

Some examples changes I would suggest:

- Group together all things relating to the question being a better fit for a different SE site (Super User, Server Fault, and other).
- Incomplete questions seeking debugging help really shouldn't be under "off topic". Rather, they should be somehow grouped with "unclear what you're asking". (In both cases, it's more that the question is inadequately written than off topic.)
- "Seeking product/service recommendation" should be grouped with "primarily opinion based".
- "Too broad" and "too minor" are basically two sides of the same coin, so it might be helpful to group them as well.

It seems as though the current organization of close reasons is to put popular reasons at the top level and lump everything else under "Off Topic" (even though only half of them would really be thought of as "off topic" by the average user). It's not necessarily bad to put frequently used things at the top level and less frequently used things as a drill-down, but frequency concerns should be balanced with properly named and organized categories.

Comment: At present, the software is limited to putting custom reasons under off-topic, under the somewhat shaky original reasoning that custom close reasons are always about narrowing the scope in particular ways. There's [a proposal on MSE to change that](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons), but before that happens there's no point in trying to wordsmith anything; it simply can't be done.

Comment: This was brought up right at the beginning, and basically ignored: [Shouldn't "off" topic be only about..off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086)

Comment: @NathanTuggy (and JoshCaswell), Thanks for that context. I didn't realize this was so "hard baked" into the system. And yes, avoiding wordsmithing definitely makes sense under the circumstances. I was trying to stay a level above that by merely categorysmithing :)