# What should be done when questioner asks for answers irrelevant to original question in comments?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, asking-questions, etiquette

I have seen an issue where the questioner asks about a problem, when the solution is given (even as accepted answer), the questioner asks for further help in comments, like he/she wants more features than initial question, what should be done here?

I have also seen that other answerers (who gave answers other than accepted solution) tries to grab that opportunity to be the accepted answer.

What should I do here if I am in the position of the accepted answerer?

Comment: Ignore the requests.

Comment: I tried to ignore but it was kind of annoying when other answerers gave those solution with the request "please accept my answer"

Comment: Related: [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer?cb=1), [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: Suggest that they ask a new question.

Comment: It sounds mean-spirited, but often this is a sign that the question was very low quality and you shouldn't have answered the question in the first place.

Comment: Well, its true I guess @roippi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Said asker of questions should be pointed towards opening a new follow-up question which is about his *new* problem specifically. It's up to anyone's judgement at what point a follow-up comment thread goes off the rails into territory which is too broad to be covered by comments, but I'd say if the follow-up comments clearly can't be answered within the length of a comment and/or if the length of the comment thread exceeds half a dozen comments, you should probably point the user towards the "Ask Question" button in the top right.

Comment: Refer for asking a new question is probably the most logical response for this kind of problem I guess. Thanks a lot.