# Would it be wrong asking questions to an answer-er?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday while browsing some questions at work, I saw someone asking questions to an old answer under the comments, to  which he/she didn't receive an answer after doing it multiple times. Also the answer-er seemed quite annoyed.

I wanted to indulge in-between stating they could ask a separate question, just as the answer-er said, but I didn't. Well in this scenario he/she should have asked a separate question while also including a link to the answer to provide some context.

But then I thought what if the seeker is having questions about a particular answer and expects clarification **only** from the original answer-er. Thus asking a separate question may not be seen by the original answer-er.

What should be the appropriate way to address it, if the seeker has the mindset as above?

I have already checked [Is there a way to ask a question on a well received answer without commenting on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253836/what-should-be-done-when-questioner-asks-for-answers-irrelevant-to-original-ques?rq=1)
 and some related questions, but can't make up my mind.

---

Edit: now that I think of this whole scenario again, If I was the one to follow-up an old answer, what should I do given the same mindset as above? Start a chat or something!? I'm asking this as a lesson to myself and also to properly address seekers in comments.

Comment: I've seen times where one answer's quirkiness inspires somebody to ask a new question and somebody else explains. Just because there's something striking about an answer doesn't mean only the original answer-er can explain it. And on the other hand, if there's something odd about an answer, that's part of what the comment section is for. I'm not sure where the line is, unless you can somehow predict that the answer to your question will be long and involved.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The wibbly-wobbly line is between what constitutes a clarification (comment) and what constitutes a new question (question). I don't think there's a great way to tell that. You have to go on a case-by-case basis. Consider your question and try to determine that yourself.

Some things are much better suited to being posted as questions. Actual questions allow more detailed answers, more focused discussion, are more likely to be seen by other people, and are [not as ephemeral](/search?q=comments+are+ephemeral). If you suspect that your question is a non-trivial question, definitely ask it as a question.

Beyond that, the answer-er may or may not *want* to answer in the comments. Maybe they realize that the discussion would be too long. Maybe they think you're a [help-vampire](/a/258279/5764553). Either way, no need to press them in the comments. If they say to ask it as a separate question, they're probably right.

(If you get the feeling that your follow-up question is part 2 of 50, maybe try chat instead, or go take a class or find a mentor.)

I will note that there aren't many questions that can **only** be answered by one person. Maybe a detail about a C++ compiler that only one person on Stack Overflow knows because they actually wrote the compiler? I have however seen [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5916690/5764553) [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42996825/5764553) where somebody saw some weird thing in an answer and asked a separate question and an entirely different person explained it. In point of fact, I've also seen people comment to ask for clarification and some kind third-party replies there, too.

And one final note: Stack Overflow is voluntary, so nobody has a right to demand that one particular person take the time to explain something.

Comment: I agree with the points you stated, just wanted a clarification of sort, as my conscious was stuck between the *mindset* I stated in the question. Also stating "go ahead and ask it as a separate question" seemed rude/direct to me in some sense. Because I tend to attend questions in comments if I'm the answer-er, not everyone might do the same thing. Anyways thank you! :)

Comment: My experience is that *most* answerers are happy to elaborate and expand their answer, even if that answer was clear to the original OP and I'm only passing by and curious about some detail. Only once I got a comment "%#$? With your rep you should know to post that as a new question!" ... I still don't know if I actually deserved that ...

Comment: Even if the answerer is the only person who can answer a specific question, there is no reason why they should be enforced to do that in the comments, where they get no rep points, the answer is unlikely to be found by others and may eventually get deleted together with other comments during a cleanup.

Comment: @Holger I'll sometimes edit my answer to include the information for a follow-up question, if I find it a worthwhile extension.

Comment: @Holger wouldn't that be solved by the questioner having the courtesy to upvote  an old answer if they are asking for new work by its author? (sweet, sweet +10 rep! ;)  )

Comment: @DaveS: that is indeed what I meant with my comment above – not a "new" or "follow-up" question, but rather an *expansion* of the answer. And if it gets better, I upvote of course. I've also seen the reverse – an unclear answer of which the author flat-out refuses to explain ("the code speaks for itself"), in which case I sometimes choose to downvote.

Comment: @CindyMeister nothing wrong with that; if someone asks you a question in a comment, you can decide to include it into the answer or even to answer with a comment (sometimes it’s appropriate) or to tell the asker to open a new question for that. As Andrew Myers said in this answer “You have to go on a case-by-case basis”.

Comment: Agree with this post. I'd say that if question-asker-#2 has the exact same scenario as the OP, and doesn't understand some aspect of the answer, then that constitutes "asking for clarification". If, however, q-a-#2 has a different scenario than the OP, rendering the given answer incompatible, then that is clearly a case where a new question is needed.

Answer (score 8):

> I will note that there aren't many questions that can only be answered by one person. -[Andrew Myers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363626/1026459)

Andrew pretty much sums it up. If you have another question as a follow up, then simply ask it separately and someone just as capable will answer it. Make sure you link it back to the previous post for context.

Generally, this situation shouldn't happen often. If you find yourself breadcrumbing a feature together by having Stack Overflow provide the answer to each iteration then you are doing it wrong and are probably heading for a question ban at some point.

That said, if it is the rare occasion where you have a question related to an answer from a question you asked, and you would like to let the answerer know you posted a separate question, then a one time simple comment such as "I asked a question related to this answer `[here](link)`" would be appropriate, and preferably nothing else. Even still, this is a bad habit, and shouldn't really be done at large and especially not on posts which were not your own.

In no circumstance is it really appropriate to ask a separate question of an answerer in comments; extensions are a gray area of "it depends", and clarifications are encouraged.

Some historical debate on this topic: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/178816)