# OP changes a question after it has been answered

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

A user asked a question:

[How do I make github.com exclude my rebase linecount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146529/)

Originally, it said:

> ### How do I make github.com exclude my rebase linecount?
>
> I just rebased my repo, and the line count doubled.
>
> I'd like my line count to remain accurate, so I thought I'd ask here.
>
> I didn't see any other questions with a quick glance at search and I
>   already checked every settings menu I can find on the site.

I posted an answer which was up-voted and accepted, as it showed where the problem was and even a way to fix it.

Now the OP just decided he wanted to change the question, and now it says:

> ### How do you maintain an accurate line count in git?
>
> I just rebased my repo, and the line count doubled. Now we know why...
>   I'd like my line count to remain as accurate as possible, so I thought
>   I'd ask here. What are the best practices on git to ensure the most
>   accurate line count? (IE how can I avoid this in the future...)
>
> And how can I fix my duplicate commits?

IMHO, that would be a different question, and could only be made after knowing the information that was posted in the answer to the original question. So I added a comment to suggest OP to post a new question for that instead of changing the original question. I also reverted those changes in the question (my changes to go back to the original question were peer-reviewed and accepted by unanimity).

OP didn't like it or didn't read my comment or whatever... but now has changed again the original question.

- What is to be done in this case?
- Am I wrong trying to keep the original question?

I think it could be rewritten, but the changes OP made resulted in a different question. I would rather not revert the changes in the question again, as OP may repeat the operation and we'll be stuck in an infinite loop. And I already suggested OP to just create a new question.

Comment: Users use this trick to work around a question ban.  Avoid getting into an edit war about it, just flag a moderator.  He can lock the question if necessary.

Comment: @ArunA.S: well, that seems to ask what to do with the answer that is no longer valid. I'm asking about the question and whether it should be reverted or not. Also, that case would be one of a change made in a very short period of time (<5 mins), so it could not be reverted.

Comment: @ArunA.S: it seems my question will be closed anyway... xD (4/5 votes already)

Comment: Hm. Dupe-closed with a different post. Though the wrong one stays in the dupe-notice...

Comment: @Peque: you're right. Voting to re-open because this indeed is about one specific question. It may take a field expert in [tag:github] to decide what to do – all I have to offer on its content is, "euhh-h.."

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer