# Editing an answered question

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, editing-help

If I've asked some questions in the past, and there are answered and I even selected desired answer, is it OK to edit that question a while later?

If I do so, should I remove accepted tick from accepted answer? Should I notify owners of answers to come and edit their answers?

It is mentioned in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer) that

> Any fundamental changes to a question that change it enough to invalidate correct answers are a no-go.

But if I ask a new question which shares some materials with the previous one, and a moderator marks it as duplicate while it is not an exact duplicate, what should I do?

What about version changes? For example in Apache httpcomponents-core-v4 there were some lack of features that in the new version it is no more.

Now correct answers are invalidated, **not just by editing my question**, they are invalidated by version changes. What should I do in this special case?

I'm sorry if I couldn't find my exact answer in meta before asking.

Comment: You can always leave a comment on the answers, so they know that it might be a good idea to update them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your case is version dependant, then feel free to ask a new question with a link to the original question for reference.

Keeping legacy questions about older versions is an important part of the site, not everyone updates as often as they should, and some get stuck working on older systems/projects.

If you're worried about your new question being marked as a duplicate, just be sure to mention the version you're working with in both questions. (Note that this may not save the new question in all cases, sometimes the version doesn't really matter.)

Comment: Nice answer about legacy questions. Thanks