# Question edited by the OP after someone answered

Tags: feature-request, questions, edits, answers

This is my first meta-post and I couldn't find this exact discussion here yet.

I often see new or newer users edit their question after an answer has been given. The reason for editing is that the OP has not thought enough about the sample data. Meaning that there is not enough cases in the sample data or that new users think editing questions after they are being answered gives them better answers.

What is the appropriate way to deal with this? Should I flag the edit? Should there be a feature that newer users can't edit their question after it has been answered?

In my experience the answers are good. But then some new OP asks experienced users to revise their answers, because OP forgot something. This seems wrong to me.

Often the user asking the question seems to have trouble comprehending the answers or issues transferring the answer to her/his problem.

For clarification, I distinguish two cases:

1. Answers to the edited question would create different answers. There I guess everyone would comment once and kindly ask the user to open a new question. [This thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322735/editing-an-answered-question) covers this quite well.
2. Answers to the edited question are still the same as the answers given or to a large extent the same. With the latter I mean, that if you think a bit about the existing answer, the OP should be able to answer the edited question.

My questions are about the second case.

Comment: About the downvote -- it does not cause automatic question ban, but generally asking a duplicate question is bad. If you know you made research (use Google, SE search is bad, with `site:meta.stackexchange.com`) before asking, it's fine.

Comment: Thanks will try that next time. Yeah I was quite surprised when I couldn't find anything about this. It's just odd. I just usually find my answers via the SO search. When I ask on Google I usually get mostly SO answers which aren't tagged for the code they're written in. I guess it is because SO search is good at distinguishing answers which are tagged in a very distinctive way and that kind of tagging doesn't occur on SO-meta.