# Is it OK to use comments to highlight a related unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, comments, related-questions

CLARIFICATION: I have posted a question that hasn't been answered yet. My question is a variation of another question, that has already been answered. I wonder if it is OK if I use comments to inform the poster of the original question and the poster of the accepted answer, as I suspect them to be able to answer my question, too.

Consider the following situation:

- There is a question: How to solve the problem A, if B and C?
- There is also an accepted answer that solves the problem A.
- I have another question: How to solve the problem A, if B, C **and D?**

Now, in this case, if I highlight my problem in the comments to the accepted answer, it wouldn't contribute much to the original question. But, on the other hand, there is a good chance that OP or poster of the accepted answer would know the answer to my question (that is currently unanswered with a low number of views).

I consulted [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about correct use of the comments and it says:

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or
>   answer.

Would it be selfish to use comments with the purpose of getting an answer to a related question?

Comment: What do you want to ask?  "What would the answer be if `D` is added?" or "I have a similar question here(with link), can you answer it?".  Neither is acceptable, but how to suggest you handle the situation would vary depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: "I have a similar question here(with link), can you answer it?" sums it up very well. Since I didn't feel that it's alright, I decided to ask here.

Comment: Related: [OP is annoying me by asking more questions based on a single question which was answered already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-is-annoying-me-by-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was)

Comment: @psubsee2003 But in a different kind. This might be more like: "Random people annoy me by linking to different, remotely related questions under my answer"

Comment: @Vogel612 true, which is why I said related, instead of marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: My question is not remotely related, but strongly related. Furthermore, I think that it even might be of interest to the original poster and answerer. However, I get your point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already stated it yourself: Comments are for **requesting clarification / information**.

This means you **should not abuse comments to link to other questions, just because it's convenient.** Also I, as answerer of a question would probably be rather *annoyed* to be asked: "Hey you just solved that problem, could you look at mine next please?"

As answerer **I and only I decide** which questions I want to answer.

As you wish to draw attention to your question, you can follow the [documented steps:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

> To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on any question more than two days old.

---

I just leave this old version of my answer here:

There is a relatively simple solution to that. [Just Ask!](https://stackoverflow.com/ask)

In your question you then can make a reference to that specific question (*question A*) where A,B and C are explained. Then you explain, why no approach in the answers given to question A worked.

Yes it would be selfish to use comments for that purpose, but that is not the main problem. The main problem is, that comments is not the right place for that. There is a few restrictions on comments that make it **hard** to use them as a platform for problemsolving.

1. Character Limit - Questions and Answers allow 30k Characters, Comments 450 :(
2. Formatting -  Questions have codeformatting and linebreaks, comments do not.

for these reasons you should instead ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Use *questions* to get answers, not comments.

Comment: I have posted my question separately, too. I want to know if it would be by rules if I notify about my question someone, who in my opinion can answer it, by the means of a comment on a similar question.

Comment: I have clarified my post to emphasize that I have posted my question as a separate question and to clear up what I am trying to achieve with the comments.