# Add Ability to Ignore Users

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible/practical to provide a way for users to ignore other users?

It seems like this would help solve both sides of the "[so negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077)" debate:

- High-rep users who don't want to be bothered by low-quality questions can avoid encountering the same user again after they've asked a question deemed low-quality
- Trolls and other unhelpfuls can be safely ignored if a user feels insulted or offended by a derogatory comment

And some related logistics:

- A user can see how many other users are ignoring them, but this information is not displayed on the user's public profile
- Users could have the option of ignoring anyone already being ignored by a certain number of other users

This puts a twist on the idea to "[Allow users to optionally filter out low-quality questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252607/ability-to-ignore-questions-from-low-rep-users?rq=1)" because it's left up to the user's discretion.

Comment: Nope, that is what question bans are for. No pile-on ignoring please, we focus on *content* here, not individuals.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252607/ability-to-ignore-questions-from-low-rep-users

Comment: And the 'low quality' complaints are about drive-by question askers; the one-off accounts. How would ignoring those help anyway?

Comment: [This is actually (for the most part) implemented.](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/browser-extension-to-hide-all-the-activities-of-a-given-user-on-stack-exchange/3429#3429)

Comment: @hichris123 - thanks for the extension link, I'll try it out

Comment: I find it offensive that you think some people (judged by button pushing) shouldn't be heard.

Comment: Its pointless. New users come and ask a dumb first question.  You wont have the new user in your ignore list because this is their first question. Also, there are too many dumb users to ignore all of them

Comment: @MartijnPieters - For me the negative comments from trolls are what I'm most interested in blocking.

Comment: @cantera: Trolling you *flag*.

Comment: If a user is of actual low quality, the system would handle it.

Comment: Here's the comment that prompted my request: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24225481/723007. It's hard to consider it trolling if 3 people agreed with him, but I also don't think the question is invalid either. That's why leaving it up to the user to selectively ignore would be helpful IMO.

Comment: @cantera: that is flag-worthy; I flagged it as non-constructive.

Comment: If they are truly a troll, or causing you such distress that you want to ignore them, then you are doing us *all* a disservice by allowing the content to remain on the site. We have tools to handle users who cannot contribute constructively—flags. They clear the crap for everyone, not just you.

Comment: +1 for a good idea; just because the policies are bad doesn't mean your idea is bad.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The irony is that you have individuals harassing other individuals using that keyword you love, *content*. Is that what you want? Because if *content* is what you want, why do you delete so much *poor content*?

Comment: @Seb: I have *no idea* what you are on about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I come here to help students, not to get into pointless pedantic debates which I usually win anyway, but which certainly aren't helpful for anyone. What kind of content do you want? I think we want the same thing, but I've noticed, it can't be done without an ignore feature. You're neglecting to address the political aspect. There are users who might hold grudges or have "answer envy" and will thus push shitty content onto your system, and I want to be able to ignore them!

Comment: @Seb: we all have a responsibility to keep shitty content out; don't ignore, downvote!

Comment: @MartijnPieters You can't downvote a spiteful series of comments that's just jumping from one (invalid or pointless) point to another, over and over again. Sure, I could flag it to be deleted... and it would be... *and it has been*... but then when it happens *again* and *again*, you gotta start thinking, am I bothering the admin with *something an ignore could fix*? You won't ban him because he has a higher rep than I... so let me ignore him!

Comment: @Seb: I'm just going to point to Cody's comment: [Add Ability to Ignore Users](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/43165)

Comment: @Seb: and reputation is **never** a reason not to ban someone. Everyone is held to the same standards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... and I'm going to point to [my flag stats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1989425), face-palm and say "duh"!

Comment: @Seb: excellent, I see that you have a great flagging record. Auto-flags are raised for users whose comments get repeatedly flagged, so moderators will look at accounts that attract a lot of controversy. Feel free to use custom flags if you see patterns we should know about. Ignoring users means we don't get to hear about these issues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just had a similar but different question about blocking moderators and how to handle abuse. What I am seeing is there is a lot of moderator gaslighting: they show up to some question, have no idea about it, want the question to be something easy to answer (different from question) and then hurl abuse and delete question. How to block them? How to make moderators understand that *questions* are search queries not "work specs".

Comment: @hichris123 I think the stackignore is just ignore, not block right? i.e. you can not block abusers from commenting or deleting your post or question. You basically have no recourse from people gaslighting and purposefully misreading or misinterpreting. None except "flag comment". I don't see this as sustainable in current form. It is getting worse and worse and I have been on here a while.

Comment: @mathtick: first of all: you are probably talking about *community members*, not moderators. Moderators, like me, have a diamond next to their name. You can't block community members from commenting. If there is [actual abuse in those comments](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), you can [flag them for moderator attention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging). However, also take into account that our site has a very narrow, specific focus on what kinds of questions work well here.

Comment: It's funny that this was closed as an alleged dup, where the supposed dup was about ignoring low rep users. The vast majority of users I want to ignore are HIGH REP users. People who bully their way through the site berating people asking good faith questions and flooding the site with their personal opinions as though it's dogma. They're not breaking any rules, but they are unpleasant people that I wish I could summarily ignore. This is a much needed feature.

Comment: [How can I block a user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277425/how-can-i-block-a-user) is a better duplicate target for this IMO.

Answer (score 18):

> High-rep users who don't want to be bothered by low-quality questions can avoid encountering the same user again after they've asked a question deemed low-quality

I shudder at the thought of the CPU cycles wasted comparing user IDs against thousands of lists stretching thousands of IDs long, on the off-chance that the author of a question about to be displayed lurks there...

This is a bad idea for two reasons:

1. while some people are certainly more sensitive to question quality than others, at a certain point nearly everyone will agree that a given question *detracts from the ability of this site to help others* - and a few people ignoring it doesn't change the fact that we're still subjecting that question to hundreds, possibly thousands of readers coming in from search engines who have no say in the matter. When the rubber on that old "making the internet better" slogan hits the road, lofty ideals give way to hard practicality: dumping acres of crap onto the 'net *does not* make it a better place, even if a privileged few can ignore it.

   Oh, and everything I just wrote in #1 about poor-quality questions? That goes double for questions asked *in bad faith* - trollish posts don't need to be ignored, they need to be *removed*.
2. I shouldn't *have* to ignore someone to get them out of my face. If the system is failing to block or filter out crap, then it's a broken system - giving me a button to click doesn't change that.

This *might* be useful if "ignoring" someone had some *teeth* to it: perhaps raising a flag, or otherwise feeding into a system that, with sufficient input from multiple sources, would block or banish a given user's posts *entirely*... I can't find it now, but at one point I suggested that flagging a post or comment hide it from the view of the flagger, regardless of whether or not it was actually *removed from the system* - thus providing feedback to the flagger AND ensuring that signal was provided to the system. But failing that... This is not a social forum, a newsgroup where a tight-knit group can decide who is "part of the clique" and ignore everyone else.

Go join Facebook if that's what you're looking for. I hear it's... great...

Comment: The begs the question: "I shouldn't have to ignore someone in chat to get them out of my face." So are you admitting that the chat moderation system is broken?

Comment: Some food for thought, @Mysticial: how would chat be different if normal chat flags were only shown to moderators... (and there were enough moderators using chat to actually handle them promptly).

Comment: Sounds like that would be a case for either more moderators or more ability for "trusted users" (however you might define that) to moderate. That said, chat.SE has enough mods, but I don't hang out in the "troublesome" rooms enough to know how they're usually dealt with.

Comment: Greetings. I come here primarily to help people... I think I've done my share, eh? Well, I'm about to be driven away by a "privileged few", as you'd put it, because they want to argue about irrelevant topics after I've proven that they're wrong about other irrelevant topics, time and time again, which is a form of harassment. **If you don't want to deal with political casualties, give us the ability to ignore our political adversaries** or we'll most likely flock elsewhere when we're harassed by your *clique*.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about here, @Seb.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had an [encounter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349199/replacing-quotes-inside-a-pandas-df-to-count-unique-terms) with a user who felt he had the privilege of having every single step done for him, and **literally** outsource thinking onto me. And when solutions wouldn't work immediately (because his data had a different shape), then he would straight away down vote answers (despite them working on data, as shown by output).

Me trying to help this guy was the most frustrating experience I had so far on SO and it somewhat changed my mind on this issue.

I don't agree with the way the question is posted, as in *low rep should be ignorable*, or *I dont like bad questions*. This is fixable. But I'd like to ignore someone because of **his attitude**. Attitudes are not question specific and they can ruin your SO experience.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254816/839601

Comment: @gnat I flagged that, but it got disapproved: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1082349

Comment: interesting. In my experience, moderators tend to cleanup chatty / help-vampiric / annoying comments with ease. Given decline, I'd say there is a fat chance that you overreacted or flag message was unclear (the latter is most likely the case, I find it _very_ difficult to write compelling messages)

Answer (score 4):

#### This is a terrible idea

SO is based on the idea that the collective community is responsible for the overall quality of the site.  One of the most important aspects of community moderation is making sure that everyone's contributions are available for voting, editing, and other moderation.  Being able to large-scale ignore users creates unnecessary divisions within the community.  It's a bad idea for the same reasons that serial voting is a bad idea.  You need to just the content, not the user.

This is something that I think goes against the very nature of community driven content.  Stack Overflow co-founder Jeff Atwood writes about some of the [problems of an ignore/block feature to an online community](https://blog.codinghorror.com/your-community-door/) in his blog:

> - **It allows you to ignore bad behavior.** If someone is hateful or harassing, why complain? Just mute. No more problem. Except everyone
>     else still gets to see a person being hateful or harassing to another
>     human being in public. Which means you are now sending a message to
>     all other readers that this is behavior that is OK and accepted in
>     your house.
> - **It puts the burden on the user.** A kind of victim blaming — if someone is rude to you, then "why didn't you just mute / block them?"
>     The solution is right there in front of you, why didn't you learn to
>     use the software right? Why don't you take some responsibility and
>     take action to stop the person abusing you? Every single time it
>     happens, over and over again?
> - **It does not address the problematic behavior.** A mute is invisible to everyone. So the person who is getting muted by 10 other
>     users is getting zero feedback that their behavior is causing
>     problems. It's also giving zero feedback to moderators that this
>     person should probably get an intervention at the very least, if not
>     outright suspended. It's so bad that people are building their own
>     crowdsourced block lists for Twitter.
> - **It causes discussions to break down.** Fine, you mute someone, so you "never" see that person's posts. But then another user you like
>     quotes the muted user in their post, or references their @name, or
>     replies to their post. Do you then suppress just the quoted section?
>     Suppress the @name? Suppress all replies to their posts, too? This
>     leaves big holes in the conversation and presents many hairy technical
>     challenges. Given enough personal mutes and blocks and ignores, all
>     conversation becomes a weird patchwork of partially visible
>     statements.

---

Addressing your points directly:

> High-rep users who don't want to be bothered by low-quality questions can avoid encountering the same user again after they've asked a question deemed low-quality

This is already in place in the form of post bans and other manual suspensions for repeatedly posting bad content.

> Trolls and other unhelpfuls can be safely ignored if a user feels insulted or offended by a derogatory comment

Like [Becuzz points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315963/4320665), our existing community moderation tools already take care of this problem.  In fact, it does a superb job and lets everyone else benefit as moderators suspend or even delete problematic accounts.

> Users could have the option of ignoring anyone already being ignored by a certain number of other users

If implemented, this would lead to truly elitist behaviors.  And depending on the interconnectedness of the ignore lists, it could end up causing a bunch of voting rings.  After all, everyone else in that tag is collectively ignored.

Answer (score 2):

What if were a mock button -- like a "Close Elevator Door" button -- that didn't really do anything but could be pressed repeatedly in moments of extreme frustration?

I know it would help relieve some of the aggravation I feel sometimes when I answer a question from someone who is not only clueless, but also tactless and ungrateful.

(If any part of this answer make you feel that way, go ahead and test it now:)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SO already has this built in, sorta.  When you find bad content flag, vote to close, downvote, etc.  And eventually, the worst offenders will get banned all on their own.  Question bans, answer bans, mod bans for rude, abusive or spam comments, etc. all exist now.  No need for another system.

We should be judging posts on their content, not on the user posting it.  I know it seems like some people never change (especially when you keep seeing the same low quality garbage flooding in).  But occasionally I get proven wrong.  Just because a user makes one bad post should not relegate them to exile, never to be allowed to ask again.  People can change.  And those who don't get banned by the system until they can.

Also, if someone is harassing you via comments or something else, raise a custom mod flag and explain what is happening.  They can investigate and deal with problem users.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using http://weboverride.com/ to ignore comments from specific users for certain reasons...