# How can I block a user?

Tags: support, feature-request, etiquette, users, harassment

I want to block a very irritating user on Stack Exchange from answering, commenting, or voting on any of my posts on any site in the Stack Exchange network. Is there a way to do it?

If not, then can I expect Stack Exchange to introduce blocking in the near future? I know I can flag posts or comments, but I don't even want that user to answer or comment, or interact with me in the first place.

Comment: To hide answers from the user with the numerical user ID of `USERID`, might I suggest `$('.answer:has(div.user-details:has(a[href^="/users/USERID"))').hide()`? You'll have to put it in a userscript or similar to make it run on every page, though. (Similarly, for comments: `$('.comment:has(a.comment-user[href^="/users/USERID")').hide()`)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi He started being rude and irritating to me first, not the other way around.

Comment: Also, one last thing: my code might mess up your [review queue](/review) interface (I think it will hide posts by the blocked user if they ever come up in review), and it will look like you're being asked to review an empty page.

Comment: Presumably, such a plonk would also remove access to answers from the user?

Comment: @MartinJames As I wrote already a scoring system, which would allow you to hide "all comments and all answers of a user as long as the answer did not get 3 upvotes from users not being ignored" would be great, but I do not want to be greedy.

Comment: @ceving: Wouldn't high rep users most likely use this tool on **every** user below i.e. 2000 rep, effectivly stopping high rep users from answering low rep users questions and with that drying out SO from upcoming new users with low rep?

Comment: @hamena314 well, I would not mind a 'member for today' killer myself.

Comment: @MartinJames: English is not my first language, I am unfamiliar with the term "member for today"-killer ... care to explain?

Comment: @hamena314 new users, ('member for today' on profile), are hugely more likely to be trolls, puppets, homework-vampires, rep-PersonalServicesWorker seeders and other such annoyances.

Comment: @hamena314 He means people who have been members for less then a day

Comment: This is a good excuse to learn a little javascript.  Wouldn't be hard to knock out a userscript that does this.

Comment: I've found that there are several users who post comments that are rude, but not necessarily rude enough to require moderator attention. It would make a lot of sense to have the ability to block users that I personally find offensive, but that might not be offensive to the majority

Comment: A personal black list to hide (only to your own eye) comment and post from specific user seems great.

Comment: @ChoudhurySaadmaanMahmid I'd love if this websites network had a feature to block users, specially those who think are God and when you ask something you just don't know or have no knowledge but you're trying to learn and they, those "kings of universe", answer with zero politeness, are senior rudes and add to your answer that comment like "search on google" or "go study before asking" or "your question is duplicate". Internet, as everything, is awesome, but unfortunately, there are satan's followers everywhere.

Comment: @joaogdesigner Oh and there are users who think they are God and when THEY asks questions they are doing you a favor. You own them the answer and if your answer is not 120% perfect they judge you with such condescending attitude. That's why I'm here, looking for a way to block them, and disappointed. =.=

Comment: I think just a personal block list should be more than enough.  It would be good if StackOverflow  has that capability.  It's not like I want them censored blocked from using the platform, I just don't care about the opinions of some users and I don't want them to flood my feed.

Comment: Why don't you give an example of what has happened which led you to ask this question?

Comment: I think this still need address to often the victim is made to feel like the victim when its not, for example, THE very first comment on this thread is making the victim out to be the bad guy when i no for a fact their not, to often peoples mental health can suffer cause of adverse comments made, and in 2021 its my legal right to be able to block someone on a site I subscribe to !

Comment: if you think someone is rude you can always open a report flag

Comment: Still no answer for how to do this eight years later.  When is the ETA for the fix?

Comment: @sgfit I believe the customary answer is "6-8 weeks", but in all seriousness, there's no sign that Stack Exchange has any plans to implement this.

Comment: The main meta Stack Exchange site [has the same open issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users). Curiously, the idea is a lot more popular there than here. There has been a pretty good conversation going there on this for over 10 years, albeit with no apparent movement.

Comment: @EmperorEto Seems quite clear that it's not generally desired, given that nothing happened in 10 years. Honestly, if you want to ignore someone, just don't pay attention to them. Don't really need to modify the software for that to happen.

Comment: @DanMašek that doesn't seem clear at all; if anything opinion is highly divided. Me I'm not too keen on ignoring Q&A's, but if I could ignore *comments* of specified users - or even opt out of comments entirely - I would. It's not about whether a person is mentally capable of not paying attention to someone. It's about improving subjective user experience. Many people clearly think it would improve their experience, and it's unclear how it would *harm* anyone else's. If it's not a dev priority, that's one thing, but I can't understand why so many *oppose* the idea in principle.

Answer (score 26):

No, Stack Overflow is not going to let users ignore other users, because such a feature will do more harm than good.

When someone is being hostile to you, flag their comment or post for being abusive, and it'll disappear within minutes when you're right.

Related:

- [Can I block annoying or hostile users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82574/can-i-block-annoying-or-hostile-users)
- [Create a blacklist to keep from seeing certain users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/create-a-blacklist-to-keep-from-seeing-certain-users)
- [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)
- [Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)
- [Add Ability to Ignore Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260581/add-ability-to-ignore-users)
- [How to ignore/block someone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171249/how-to-ignore-block-someone)

Answer (score 20):

You can't. You can flag the comments for moderator attention.

If your flags have merit, moderators will act accordingly - this may end up with the other user being suspended.

> can I expect SE to introduce blocking in the near future?

No.

Comment: Well said. It's good to know that.

Comment: Probably disagreement with the feature request. This is meta, [votes are different here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: You guys do realize this poor Capt Jack user probably got banned for having 17 down votes? I think blocking's an excellent suggestion! It would definitely improve the experience, according to Stanford research on positive and negative reinforcement. You'd get better quality posts if you stopped down voting so much.

Comment: Dear @UXGuy - you do realize this is meta.stackoverlfow where you can't get banned, however many downvotes your question gets? The blocking suggested (one user blocking another - so they don't see anything by that user) won't be implemented. We do have other ways to block users (thus, providing negative reinforcement) - but those are more "global" - and I'd say offer a better reinforcement that just being essentially "ignored" by one user.

Comment: "You'd get better quality posts if you stopped down voting so much." - no. We would get lots of more low quality posts since people will have no incentive in writing high quality posts.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Oded. You have good ideas but based on 1000s of people's actual behavior online, researchers found users whose posts get downvoted produce worse posts in the future. If you want to discourage someone, the best way to do it is give no votes (up or down). Up votes do lead to a moderate increase in quality.

Comment: They also found people who get down voted are more likely to down vote other people.

Comment: @Oded Why not? There are some very obsessive and irritating characters on SO. If they won't be banned for harassing people, at least let their victims pretend they don't exist.

Comment: @kuhaku - if you flag any post (or comment) by a harassing user, a moderator will certainly look into it (you'd have to give enough information about the situation for a moderator to be able and act). If there is merit to the claim, a user can certainly be banned (and users have been banned for such behaviour). We do have a "be nice" policy on the site.

Comment: @Oded There is recourse against users who are clearly breaking rules, but it's still possible to be disruptive w/out breaking rules. Allowing personal blocks would fix this.

Comment: @Opux A possible (but very risky) approach is to literally flag everything that bothers you. It will certainly force a moderator to take a look at the situation. And if the moderator thinks you're abusing flags, you'll likely be contacted at which point you can explain your case against the "disruptive, but law-biding" user.

Comment: @Mysticial Risky, but also pointless, even more disruptive and not even feasible. Not everything users do can be flagged. And if what they are doing isn't even against TOS, what's a mod going to do?

Comment: @Opux I don't think you necessarily have to be in violation of the TOS fine-print to get "moderated". If the moderator sees a pattern of small things that are harmless individually, but harmful in aggregate, the mod can act on it. Many users are smart enough to walk that fine line of not violating the rules until a mod decides that's enough and bans them anyway. (IOW, the unwritten rule of not being a jerk.)

Comment: Man I would love this feature. I have one irritating user who constantly poops on all my questions telling me to read a book and trying to get me to say something to get banned. It's ridiculous. Stack overflow gives these guys way to much power with user having no ability to block. If I ask a question why shouldn't I be able to hide it from users who know how to rig the system ?

Comment: The "be nice" policy has either an epic fail or SO defines "nice" way differently, I have never received a nice feedback from +1k users, but new contributors and people who don't care about rep are mostly nice

Comment: I mean, at least there should be a way to stop their activities to show up in my inbox. A user has left at least 6 comments to my answer. I can't ignore them because a red number appears on my inbox icon every time!

Comment: The problem with "just flag the user" is that moderators will only see that one comment that you flagged, and in isolation it might be a totally reasonable comment.

Comment: It would be usefull to be able to block some users. So we'll be able to not see their comments and not accepted answers unless we click on a "see" link, as well as they will not see our comments and our unaccepted answers. As well as questions and profiles. They must of course be able to see accepted answers. To avoid abuse, perhaps this block list may be limited, to ten for example, but this mays help to block some very offensive and regularly annoying and harrassing users. This blocking may have a timeout, like one month, that requires another blocking in case of no behavior improvement.

Comment: PS: I'm sure if one see that she/him had been temporary blocked by several users at the same time, she/he will perhaps change of behavior... most will change. And this may help to improve the community "feeling".

Comment: For me I don't want people to agree with me that a user is flag worthy. I just want to hide his annoying existence for myself, and also hid me from that being.

Comment: Is the flagging system effective against sealions?

Answer (score 15):

> How to define a personal kill file for Stackexchange to plonk annoying users in order to be able to ignore their comments?

Currently no way to do such a thing exists, and to respond to your feature request, I don't think there should be any. Stack Exchange is not a social media platform and it shouldn't move closer to becoming one. We like to focus on content here, not personality. So treat each piece of content on its own merits, irrespective of who it comes from:

If you find a comment non-constructive or abusive, flag it as such.

If you find an answer non-constructive or abusive, flag it as such.

Failing this, just don't read the comments and move on.

Comment: To plonk a user is a personal decision. To flag a comment is not a personal decision. I would like to remove a comment from my eyes without taking the comment away from others.

Comment: @ceving This is not a social media site. We don't focus on users here, we focus on content.

Comment: It is a social media site, because you are Magisch and not User0123456. You have an avatar and you tell the people that you like C.

Comment: @ceving You wanna suggest replacing user names with ids and removing avatars then? Because thats more likely to happen then your suggestion.

Comment: No I want to give you evidences, why your statement "This is not a social media site" is wrong.

Comment: So...  is Facebook a software Q&A site?  I'm so confused now...

Comment: How can I Like C++, C, sockets and multithreading?

Comment: @ceving http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65261/248731

Comment: LOL: First answering the question to pull some rep and after that closing the question, because it is off-topic. This is so ridiculous.

Comment: @ceving What makes you think meta posts give rep? (hint: they dont)

Comment: It may or may not be a social media site, but it sure as hell ain't Usenet... Unless there's an NNTP endpoint for SO I don't know about? :P

Comment: "just don't read the comments" could be said about social media too. Maybe consider why it's a terrible answer there and then ask yourself is StackOverflow is really that different.

Comment: "We like to focus on content here, not personality" - yes, which is exactly why I would like the option to not see *comments*, which are too often far more about "personality" than "content". Blocking low value comments from people I know a priori are likely to make them and add no value to my day will help me focus on content. Forcing me to see those comments in my mailbox or on my posts only causes distraction and frustration with this site.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own personal Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script to that kind of job.

Comment: Where to host the list?

Comment: @ceving In your browser cache maybe?

Comment: @Magisch "To host something" means to access it from every browser.

Comment: @ceving No idea, upload it to some free file hosting service or your own server, if you have one?

Comment: This wouldn't stop users from editing, commenting or voting on your questions and answers.

Comment: True, but it save your sanity from seeing their comments.

Comment: @ceving s3 bucket