# How do I plonk users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How do I define a personal [kill file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_file) for Stack Exchange to [plonk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plonk_%28Usenet%29) annoying users in order to be able to ignore their comments?

A [Gnus scoring](http://www.gnus.org/manual/big-gnus.html#Scoring) system would be even better, but I do not want to be greedy.

Comment: @Will Yes. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277425/how-can-i-block-a-user?rq=1#comment119923_277425) is already a query. The problem is just where to host the data.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (2009, declined): *[Add the ability to ignore users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353)*