# Hiding specific questions from my list

Tags: support

**Is there a way for me to manually mark individual questions as "hide from my view" so they don't show up on my question list on https://stackoverflow.com/?**

I haven't seen any UI buttons to hide a specific question.  I've read some existing questions and I am getting the impression it is *not possible* to hide specific questions from my view.

- [How can I block a user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277425/how-can-i-block-a-user)
- [Hide Hot Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166652/hide-hot-questions)
- [Allow users to hide individual job listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312509/allow-users-to-hide-individual-job-listings)
- [Allow users to mark jobs "not interested", "applied", et cetera](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315991/allow-users-to-mark-jobs-not-interested-applied-et-cetera)

**Why would I want to hide a specific question?**

I do utilize the `Ignore Tags` to help hide categories of questions, but sometimes I want to hide a specific question.  I often find myself seeing a question belonging to my `Watched Tags` list, but I have to mentally keep track that I should avoid that question because I am unable or not interested in contributing to that specific question.

**What if I built my own third-party tool to hide specific question...**

Can I assume that each SO question is assigned a unique HTML `id`?  Below is a picture of the `id` I'm referring to.  If the `id` is unique to the question, I could just hide those `id`.

[image: <div id= for a specific question]

Comment: I didn't check this [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4166/hide-unwanted-questions-greasemonkey-script) but it describes the feature you're looking for

Comment: @rene thank you for the script