# Is there a way to hide all comments by a user?

Tags: discussion, comments

There is a user on the main site who leaves meaningless or useless comments in one particular tag that I am active in. Those comments do not warrant anything other than NLN flag, and that user is very active, at least in recent months, so I don't see any reason for them to suddenly stop doing it.

But these comments are very irritating, and making me to consider leaving that tag.

I thought maybe there is a way to simply hide all their comments under any posts for me? It could be a nice middle ground: they keep posting their stuff, and I keep my nerves intact.

I imagine something like userscript, that allows to specify a user whose comments to hide on which site.

Comment: Related: [How can I block a user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277425/208273)

Comment: if you weren't agitated, I would have suggested that you just keep flagging them instead of turning a blind eye.

Comment: @starball, once strike is over, I'll reconsider my position. But for now, this is the only viable solution I can see.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't exactly a healthy place to be if trivial things like comments get to you. What will be the next thing that other people do that you will choose to let yourself be emotionally influenced by? IMO this is training, don't hide the training material. Use it to become a more resilient person.

Comment: @Gimby, let me use an analogy: one can train to tolerate barbed wire, but I don't think this is of any use for me, especially considering the cost. Outside of SO I successfully avoid especially irritating people and their unsolicited opinions, and would like to do it here too. I don't want any residency training, I want to help people where I can, preferably with as low of a cost for me in terms of irritation.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You would need to write a custom userscript or user style to target comment elements in the DOM that match only content where that user is the author.

The markup for a comment's container contains this attribute that you can key off of (for a CSS selector): `data-comment-owner-id=""` whose value matches the SO user ID of the author.

So this would hide all comments written by you, markalex (userid `21363224`):

```css
ul.comments-list li.comment[data-comment-owner-id="21363224"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With help of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/319322/1779795) and your CSS I've successfully hidden those irritating comments. And it's nice that no additional plugins required for this.

Comment: If you change the selector to `.comment[data-comment-owner-id="21363224"] div`, you can avoid `!important`.

Comment: @NickODell That would still leave each comment's `li` parent as an empty stub, which feels a bit less clean to me. I will update the answer with a more specific selector that removes the entire `li` and doesn't require `!important`.

Comment: OMG THAT WAS SO SATISFYING. The one drawback for Chrome seems to be I have to override the entire CSS file and if the version hash changes I have to do it again.