# Further questions on the answered question in the comments area

Tags: support

A user asks a question regarding a problem and we answer that. The answer is marked as answer by the user. The marked answer solves the problem which asked initially. But after implementing the solution he gets further problems, which again he asks as a question in the comments area. This question could be a totally different problem, but from the user point of view, it is the continuation of his overall project. But the answer to this question may need some explanation and if we write answer in the same answer area as the original answer, it may lead to confusion for the future viewers in the context of the original question asked. In this case should we ask the user to  create a new question or should we ask him to update the original question which clearly expects for both the answers?

Comment: I would ask them to ask a new question if their follow up comment isn't directly related. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/217863

Comment: possible duplicate of [OP is annoying me by asking more questions based on a single question which was answered already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254814/op-is-annoying-me-by-asking-more-questions-based-on-a-single-question-which-was) See also: [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer)