# What to do when an answer is drawn out to a discussion inside the comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I started out helping somebody on a question that I first misunderstood. After getting further by asking questions using comments, I have the feeling that this question has kinda run out of control into an endless comment discussion.

The user themselves doesn't have enough reputation to join the chat room, and I do not have enough experience in that kind of discussion, to really know how to handle the prolonged discussion. The user has already acknowledged that the code I provided does what they want, although now the discussion has changed to how they should implement the provided code...

How should I handle any further comment in this discussion?

The discussion in question, is the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217257/encrypt-a-file-decrypt-its-content-and-use-it-in-a-variable

Comment: One of the comments from your questioner: *Your example does seem to do what i want, but why did u choose the hardest example in the world??? It will take me hundread of hours to understand how this works and how i can customize it to my needs :-( Did u write this yourself or find it in a link somewhere? Any chance u can make this simpler?* You should have stopped replying right there and then.

Comment: From the viewpoint of the asker: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: yes, i had that feeling at that time as well, but as i said, i am to inexperienced to know how to handle it

Comment: See [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: see also: [Further questions on the answered question in the comments area](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262709/further-questions-on-the-answered-question-in-the-comments-area)

Comment: *so i guess no problem for u guys to give me a lead on some code that i can work with. Just the simplest Encryption method will do.* - you should have never answered this to begin with, it is a 
*send me teh codez* demand disguised as a question, mark those with a **close - recommendations for external links etc is off topic** reason and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions (and for editing my miscased 'I''s :D). I learned a lot from the supplied links.

Answer (score -4):

Follow-up discussions need to be strongly attached to the original question or answer.  It is **wrong** to move lengthy follow-up discussions into chat.

Yes, that means I think the system's automatic invitation to do so is a bug (or rather, a misfeature).

Comment: I would agree that one should do as much to help as possible in(on)-topic, however for how long should such discussions continue was the question, and i found that the answers given in the comments above provided me with answers i needed. I do find that lengthy follow-up discussions mess up the topic in question, especially if the focus changes from help me with the code to help me to implement your answer (which are 2 very different questions in my opinion). Don't get why you got so downvoted for your opinion, though...