# How should I deal with lazy follow up question-comments on answers?

Tags: discussion

I'm sure this happens to a lot of users.
You have a clear and useful answer to a question.
Someone comes along and makes adds a question-comment that makes it obvious they didn't even bother reading your answer.

I feel like the options are:

- "Please ask another question." response.
- "Please read my answer above." response.
- Quote my own answer with the relevant text.
- Try to reformat answer to try to improve clarity.
- Sigh, say nothing, move on with life. ← Increasingly becoming my preference

What should be the correct response?

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478)

Comment: See also: [OP is annoying me by asking more questions based on a single question which was answered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254814)

Comment: Personally, when has gotten too much, I have simply deleted answers and downvoted the question. It may seem harsh, but a question that can not be answered by an answer isn't a good question.

Comment: Although this question seems to be about third-parties, unlike the above links which relate to the question author.

Comment: How about telling the OP: "Your follow-on question|comment is a bit off-topic to your original question. You should ask a new question".

Comment: Ignoring them is a valid tactic.

Answer (score 29):

You're more than welcome to do any of those things.  It's a decision that you'll need to make personally based on a case by case basis, along with the consideration of how much time you want to invest.  There is no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 17):

Obviously it's up to you. Answers are a charitable gesture, and there's no etiquette violation if you just walk away from the discussion entirely.

But on behalf of those of us on here who get easily overwhelmed and, frankly, just aren't that smart, I'd offer that it may not be that we didn't read, just that it's entirely beyond our capability to comprehend. That certainly isn't your problem--no one expects every answer to be crafted for third graders--but know that it may not actually be laziness. It might be stupidity.

Comment: In the event that it really *is* stupidity then you're *far* better off walking away.  If someone just didn't take the time to read the whole thing you only need to (hopefully politely) tell them to re-read it.  If they simply aren't capable of understanding it you're only ever going to waste a *ton* of time trying to teach them core concepts that comments and even answers aren't really designed to be able to teach, due to their scope.

Comment: Self-degradation is *stupid(ity)*; not knowing all things known to others is *not*!

Answer (score 2):

don't do anything special

there are other users/readers who can appreciate the answer but might not be able technically (number of points) to upvote your answer

Certainly not remove your answer as has been suggested in some comments

Answer (score -3):

The situation really depends on the question-comment. If the question-comment is trying to ascertain more information or trying to understand the concept of the answer. I would say that is a well written question-comment. I have done many of these myself and learned many new concepts that I would have not otherwise known. Also these question-comments tend to get others in the community into the conversation.

For question-comments that are completely off-topic or redundant. yeah, those should probably be ignored as they really don't add any value.

There is also a "grey zone". These are question-comments that could possibly be their own question but may fit under the current question. In this case you might want to just tell the person to move their comment to a new question so as not to cause confusion.

Anyway, I wouldn't get angry about question-comments. There is a huge range of years experience and educational backgrounds on this website. By the way, my background is engineering.