# What should I do to get more answers to my question whose answer I already accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I accepted the answer given to my question. This answer solves by problem with different method but I want to debug the posted present code. What should I do to get more answers to my question? I can't put bounty also as I don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer in the first place?

Comment: because it solves the problem. But it solves with different method

Comment: As far as I can see, you have enough reputation for the minimal bounty.  And bounty is the exact thing you are looking for

Comment: what you describe sounds rather like a new question. Did you [consider asking it separately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/839601)?

Answer (score 7):

By accepting an answer you've indicated that the problem you post is solved to your satisfaction. If the problem isn't solved to your satisfaction - which appears to be the case here - **then don't accept an answer**. You shouldn't accept the first answer that "comes close".

If you really think you made a mistake accepting the answer you can unaccept it by clicking the acceptance tick again. This will indicate that the problem isn't solved. However, if you make a habit of this then people will notice and will be less likely to answer your questions.