# Valuable question morphing into less valuable ones

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, rollbacks

A question was asked about the [HTML::PrettyPrinter](http://search.cpan.org/~clms/HTML-PrettyPrinter-0.03/PrettyPrinter.pm) Perl module. Essentially, the asker had copied the example from the synopsis and hit a runtime error.

Once this problem was solved, the asker hit another problem, completely edited the question (rolled back my rollback), got lots of down votes and eventually deleted it.

I think the original question had some value to it as anyone else referring to the documentation for that module is likely to encounter the same problem.

In summary: How do you handle the situation where someone asks a good, valid question then morphs it into a heavily downvoted one?

Comment: Do you have a link? 10k+-ers can view and see what can be done. Usually, if the initial question had value, we can re-instate it so that it'll help future visitors.

Comment: As for chameleon questions, see [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478)

Comment: This was it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954259/pretty-printer-printing-in-single-line-instead-of-indenting/23954384 . Even if it is reinstated and rolled back, isn't it likely to be deleted again?

Comment: Not if your answer got upvoted it wouldn't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters we've got an MSO-local "mirror" for that MSE _chameleon_ reference now: [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer)

Comment: @RobEarl: Ah, I see you got downvoted on your answer too; possibly the OP removing the obstacle to deletion.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. I now realise I have posted a few "chameleon questions". I didn't know how this was perceived by the community.

Comment: The question was undeleted, rolled back and closed as off-topic by five users :) And then OP deleted it again. According to his comment it seems that he just doesn't like to have a question with down-votes. Since @RobEarl states the question has a value for other users as well, I propose to undelete and lock it. (Flagged it for moderators attention).

Comment: Since people voted to close it, perhaps this particular question isn't worth saving after all.

Comment: Ah, I see one was me and suspect some of the other votes were also after the edit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Roll back the OP's edit that changes the question into a new question.  If they complain, explain that the rule is "one question per question."

Comment: ""one question per question."" I saw what you did there.