# Can a vote for an answer be removed after the OP clarifies question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What can be done when I voted for an answer awhile ago (so it is now "locked in" unless the answerer edits) but the OP has since clarified their question such that the answer is not as helpful and does not deserve the upvote? Note that the OP made a clarification in the comment rather than editing the question.

Comment: Unless the answer is edited, no.  Got a link to the question?  I'm leery of an update to the question that invalidated answers.

Comment: @Makoto If an answer misunderstands the question then clarifying the question is absolutely warranted, and that absolutely makes the answer unhelpful.

Comment: @Servy:  I don't disagree at all.  I was more concerned about a chameleon question as opposed to a legitimate misunderstanding.

Comment: I suspect that perhaps your original vote was generous. anyway , let it go

Comment: if edit to a question invalidates a reasonable answer, this often (not always mind you but still) means that [rollback is in order](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256782/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll only be able to change your vote if the answer is edited after your vote was cast.

You could also comment on the answer explaining the clarification to the question, and why that makes the answer inappropriate.  Ideally they'll fix the answer based on the clarification, or if not that, they they'll remove the answer themselves.