# What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?

Tags: discussion

A lot of time after I ask a question I still have further questions about the problem or I come up with new questions that are closely related. It is always a pain to ask follow-up questions or related questions in the comment section and I do not want to keep updating my original question to accommodate the new questions. Is it best to just create another question all together at that point?

Answer (score 47):

The correct way to ask a follow-up question is to ask a new question. Link back to the original so people can see the context.

Asking follow-up questions in comments is bad practice and won't get you the answers you want.

And editing the initial question to turn it into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) is possibly even worse.

Comment: ... and editing the initial question to turn it into a chameleon question is possibly even worse than asking for further details in comments.

Comment: @Bruno - I'll just steal that and edit it into the answer ;)

Comment: A particularly heinous practice is to unaccept the already accepted answer (-15) to goad the answerer into helping with your followup or chameleon question. Don't ever do that - it's super rude.

Comment: I have made a follow up question by asking a new question and linking the original one but it got closed