# Edit the answer in response to OPs comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

I ran into an *interesting* comment to one of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106067/is-it-bad-practice-to-equal-class-instances-by-just-their-unique-instanceid/29106121?noredirect=1#comment46482095_29106121) yesterday.

The OP asked a question, I answered it (some say *partially*). Now, the OP asked a couple of questions as comments to my answer. I answered the OP in my comments.
I got a down-vote (*no complaints here*) from someone because my answer was *incomplete*). When I asked him to go through the comments, he said that the comments to complete the answer and asked me to *edit my answer as people usually don't read comments*.

In my defense, I usually clarify the OP's doubts (unless it includes some code) in comments because :

> 1. It helps the OP to follow up easily. (OP)Comment-1 --> My response --> (OP)comment -2 --> My response.
> 2. Even if I edit my answer, I will have to *explicitly* notify the OP that the answer has been edited (which does not reduce the book
>      keeping on this site :P).

So, I am a little confused here, should I always edit my answers or should I leave comments? OR should I do both based on the question?

Comment: I'd do both then flag to cleanup comments.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Lol. Flag OPs comments? as what? *obselete*? :P

Comment: Yeah. Once the answer has been clarified, there's no reason to keep the comments around.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Ok.. Makes sense :) .. But that makes me actually do all the clean-up.

Comment: @TheLostMind, No, actually, if you flag a comment for mod attention, and ask for the entire comment thread to be deleted, they will usually do it, especially since once the answer has been clarified, there's no reason to keep the comments around.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it depends on the nature of the follow-up question, and what I have to say in response:

- If I feel like the comment is a legitimate request for clarification, and still on the topic of the original question, I will often edit the answer to add information. In this case, if the original answer was not clear to the OP, chances are that it might also not be clear/complete enough for other readers. If I can make it better by adding more detail, or explaining something more clearly, I mostly will.
- If the comment is a follow up question that goes beyond the scope of the original question, there's a chance that it could be a "help vampire" case. Which is a topic that has been discussed widely. For me, if I can answer it quickly, I might give a quick response in a comment. Otherwise, particularly if it continues, I will either point out that it's out of scope, or ignore it silently. But in any case, I will **not** add information to the answer that is not suitable as part of answering the original question.

In the first case, since the OP is not automatically notified when the answer is edited, I will typically leave a short comment saying something like:

> I added more detail to the answer, please see the latest version for an explanation of [whatever they asked].

Comment: I am not sure about the *leaving the comment* part.. I'd rather add the OPs comment as well as my response as part of the answer and just hope that the OP comes back

Comment: second bullet point seems to describe a kind of help vampire (or sometimes simply newcomer who doesn't understand SE Q&A model) known as ["chameleon"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/839601)