# What to do if my question is answered and I need to completely change my question?

Tags: support

Recently I asked a question:

[How to count student number on different conditions in an attendance sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008747/how-to-count-students-number-on-different-conditions-in-a-attendance-sheet/)

I did not get any good reply (in terms of my understanding). Now that I tried to worked around and completely changed the scenario and stuck again at one place. 
I need to ask the question which was related to my previous post, but things are now completely change.
Now what should I do?

1. Edit the previous question completely including the "Title" or
2. Should I ask another question leaving the previous one unchanged?

EDIT:

I am getting this warning-

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

Comment: If you are getting that warning it means you should make sure your question is a good one and that it follows our [quality guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Changing an existing question is not the right thing to do here. The system is telling you to take a deeper look - why not do that?

Comment: see also: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Answer (score 17):

> Should I ask another question leaving the previous one unchanged?

Yes.

Given that you now have a completely different question, you should ask it as a completely different question.

Regardless - since your original question was answered, changing it means all the given answers are no longer correct and relevant and the effort of those who answered would be in vain. Don't do that.

Comment: Yes! I have now a completely different question. When I attempted to ask a different question, a warning was flagged stating about chances that I may be blocked from asking any question as my previous question is still on hold or something like that

Comment: Well, from your 10 questions, 3 have a negative score, 6 have a score of zero and only one has any upvotes. This suggests that you are not asking questions that are received well by the community and is the reason you got the warning. Perhaps take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure your next question follows those guidelines?

Comment: Yeah! Those were my early days. Now I have read the guidelines.
So I am still in danger even if I follow the guidlines?

Comment: @user3405976 "In danger" is up to you. Make sure you write a good question that is not a dupe. Well written, understandable, and answerable. You may have read the Help Center in your "early days" but it seems you are not following the advice given there. A re-read might refresh your mind as to what is required - "How to ask a good question" etc.