# 600 character limit on comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

## 1. It diagnoses most problems incorrectly

Here are a few situations that I thought of where a comment exceeding 600 characters is likely:

1. A user is answering a question in a comment
2. A user is asking a question in a comment
3. A user is explaining why they think a question or answer is incorrect or could use clarification, i.e., and edit.

Consider the first two items on that list. The solution to the first one is to post an answer instead of a comment. Similarly, the solution to the second one is to post a question. But that's not what the message "Too long by X characters" indicates. It indicates that the solution to both of those problems is to make the comment shorter.

But surely it diagnoses the third item correctly, right? Wrong. And that brings me to the second section:

## 2. It doesn't accomplish its intended purpose

To the best of my belief, the purpose of the character limit is to reduce clutter and improve the readability of comments.

So maybe the solution for a legitimate comment that is too long is to make it shorter. But that's not what most people will do when they see the message "Too long by X characters". Most people will just split the comment into two or even more comments. So rather than contributing to the solution and the end goal of less clutter, the character limit actually contributes to the problem by unintentionally encouraging users to post two comments instead of one!

## Possible solutions

There are a few things that could be done to solve this problem. One would be to extend the limit, but that wouldn't really help anything. It would just decrease the frequency of the problem, rather than solving it. Another solution would be to automatically hide the text that exceeds 600 characters in a comment and have a "Show more" link for the comments, similar to the "Show X more comments" link. Another, possibly more drastic solution would be to remove the limit altogether.

Personally I think that the best option would be to collapse long comments, but I am interested in your opinions.

Comment: Because it'd be hard to read comments longer than that. If you have that much content, post an answer. I am all for a feature-request to make it easier to separate the comments or adding show more for each comment, but I'd still put a limit. Maybe 1000 Characters.

Comment: @M-- The situation I was describing was one in which I was replying to an answer to my own question, so posting an answer wasn't an option. However, raising the limit may well solve the vast majority of the situations in which the problem is present.

Comment: If you're posting a long comment on your question, clarifying/answering other comments. then edit your question and add that information there. If a post needs extensive clarification in the comments, it means it is, in some level, incomplete or unclear.

Comment: I think you somehow misunderstood me. It wasn't a comment on my question, it was a comment on someone else's answer to my question. And it wasn't information that would have been helpful in the question itself.

Comment: Clarifying on my first comment: I think that feature would serve Meta but would not be suitable on the main site. Is it a priority though? NO.

Comment: (I'd say OP of that answer then should edit and clarify their answer). Care to share a link? I really don't see a general use for increasing length of comments, specially on the main site. There may be a use (that I am not aware of) for the specific case that you have in mind, but certainly not everywhere.

Comment: "I'd say that OP of that answer then should edit and clarify their answer". That's exactly what I was asking him to do in the comment :). Sometimes suggesting an edit the official way just doesn't cut it, because the edit summary would have to be _way_ too long. So in that case, comments are the only fallback. And depending on the complexity of the edit, 600 characters isn't enough either. Here's a link to the comment I was talking about https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26642/how-to-make-gf-behave-like-drop#comment47395_26643. It's on Vi and VIm, but the same principals should apply.

Comment: @M-- I have edited my question, and I believe that it better explains the logic I used to arrive at my conclusion that the "feature" of limited-length comments does not contribute to the goal of less clutter and greater readability.

Comment: @Dharman the first paragraph doesn't really have much to do with the subject of the question, only with the fact that I had edited the question. In the original post, I had more or less just said that I didn't believe that the limit on characters in comments worked as intended, but didn't explain how I came to that conclusion. In this edit, I went into much more depth.

Comment: @Dharman it also uses the imperative vs declarative language paradigms as a metaphor. If you don't know what imperative and declarative languages are, that could be the source of the confusion.

Comment: @Dharman I edited the post again. Does it look better now?

Comment: @Dharman it's not that it's not part of my question, it's just that it's more of an _introduction_, rather than part of the main body of the question.

Comment: As @Dharman mentioned, we can move the conversation, if constructive, to the chat. Otherwise it should be cleaned up after arriving at a conclusion. That conclusion **may** be reflected as an edit to the post.

Answer (score 6):

No, no, no.

We have way too many comments as it is and the comment maximum length is just right. It lets you write a few short sentences either asking for clarifications or posting a piece of helpful advice on how to improve code/question.

Comments are not designed for discussions, "thank you"s, follow-up questions or answers. Comments are temporary in nature and they should be removed as soon as they are no longer needed.

Extending the comment limit or abolishing it would only contribute to more mess. What's the point in doing that? We need to make the site cleaner.

It's true that if someone wants to post a longer comment they can split it into multiple parts, but that is by design. If there are too many comments added under a post then moderator flag will be raised by the system. Moderator will then come and move the conversation to chat or delete it permanently.

Comment: If comments aren't for discussions, thank you's, or follow-up questions or answers, what are they for? Literally every comment on an answer I've seen falls into one of those three categories.

Comment: They are for asking for clarifications or posting positive criticism.

Comment: Asking for clarification is a follow-up question, and the answer is a follow-up answer...

Comment: And positive criticism is a form of discussion.

Comment: And if comments are not the place for discussions, what is? AFAIK, the only way to start a chat is to add the number of comments that it takes for it to suggest that you move it to the chat.

Comment: I don't want to have a conversation with you in comments. Please see the explanation of comments here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment Stack Overflow is not a place for discussions/conversations.

Comment: Nowhere on that site does it say not to ask follow-up questions in the comments. Which, btw, was what I was doing in the example I gave of a message that had to be revised in order not to be too long.

Comment: And by those standards, the first comment on the question be @--M shouldn't have been in the comments, it should have been an answer instead.

Comment: See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions

Comment: Wouldn't asking a new question with a minor change just get it marked as a duplicate and closed? That's what actually happened to a commenter on the accepted answer to that question you linked to.

Comment: Yes, M--'s comments should be an answer, but I assume they didn't think it was a good enough answer to be placed in the comment. When people do this, you can reply to them to ask them to post it in the answer space instead.

Comment: You are now asking a follow up question in the comments under my answer. If you have a new question, then please start a new Meta question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218848/discussion-between-thaddaeus-markle-and-dharman).