# Appropriate to Re-ask questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This is a follow up to an earlier question of mine - I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141983/embedding-subview-in-main-view-swift) recently. However, due to the fact that I am very inexperienced in swift, I explained my question really badly and with (what I know know) are incorrect terms. I got a great answer (this person managed to mostly understand me), but I have some questions. The comment chain, already unwieldy from all the clarification I had to do, is quite long, and I have followup questions that seem like questions of their own (code troubleshooting, to be exact) that barely fit in a comment, and don't seem right to append onto the long collection of comments.

So, my question: Now that I know what I tried, and what I need help with, what code I don't understand, and the proper terminology, is it OK to re-ask the question with all these things fixed?

This new question will be explained a lot better and more clearly, and will have the code that I tried to get working from the previous answer, and will make it easier for people to answer it and help me and anyone that finds it in the future. Just checking, is this cool?

Comment: No, edit everything into the present question. There is no problem clarifying a question as long as you don't invalidate the current answers. As you correctly noted, it should be helpful for future users. So go edit, it's cool.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Is that better than starting a new question, even if the current answers would be semi - invalidated?

Comment: If it semi-invalidates current answer, than new question is better. Edits shouldn't semi-invalidate any current answer.

Comment: whatever edits you think of doing to your question, better make sure to avoid invalidating existing answers (if these are of good quality) and turning it into ["chameleon"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer "'poor or ever-growing questions'")