# Answered a question; question changed via follow-up answer - unsure of relevance anymore

Tags: discussion, questions

Yesterday I answered a question wherein someone was struggling with submitting a score from Flash to PHP. The answer was a quick and simple one (although perhaps alarm bells should have gone off at him not understanding 'his own' code), so I posted a response.

The questioner then answered his own post - poorly formatted, with text inside code blocks - essentially stating that my suggestion worked (but no Accepted Answer for me). However, he then posed another question. It was *related* to his original question, so I asked him to delete the 'answer', modify his original question to expand on the issue, and I would update my answer. I did so, and although he deleted his answer, he never updated his question.

We're now at a point where I've updated my answer twice, adding more solutions as he hits more walls; but because he's deleted/never updated questions, my answer just looks like I'm adding random additions to it. There's also pretty length comment thread where he's struggling with further problems, all related to the original post.

My gut feeling (which I have mentioned in the thread) is that he simply doesn't understand the basics of what he's trying to achieve. However, I'm not sure I can objectively vote to close on a question where I've only got a 'feeling' he has no idea what he's talking about.

TL;DR I'm concerned that my answer looks completely out of whack with the original, unmodified question being asked. Should I just delete and move on?

Comment: I would roll back to the answer that makes sense with the question (or edit the question) and move on. Flag for comment cleanup and get the heck out of there, he's never going to stop asking for more help if he hasn't bothered to learn the very basics.

Comment: Thats called a chameleon question.  you need to resist the urge to chase it as it changes. when it happens, tell the user that you've already answered the original question and he/she should ask a new one.  when they edit to CHANGE the question (rather than append) roll it back. Then perhaps some bold text on your Answer noting what exactly you are answering.  Also though, your own POV is askew.  `I have mentioned in the thread` SO is not a msg board or forum - they are supposed to be succint Questions with Answers. not threads or debug/tutoring *sessions*

Comment: @Plutonix I, in fact, said the exact same thing to him (with regards to SO not being a forum) - I simply used the word 'thread' because of how the comments started to roll out.

Comment: see [Link for poor or ever-growing questions to better explain why people stop answering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) and questions linked to it

Comment: @gnat 'Just One More Thing...' seems like it should be a flag in its own right!

Comment: one "trick" or rule of thumb you can use is to pretend that the **"Avoid extended discussions...chat"** message is a hard and fast rule.  Extract yourself from the mess with, "well, looks like we are out of room here..."

Comment: @Plutonix That's a good suggestion. I actually tried to start a chat about 3 comments ago, but his rep is too low to allow it. Would he see the chat prompt in that instance?

Comment: yes, the next time they go to add a comment.  I think if they cant clarify the issue in that amount of room, they never will or it is a sign of an XY problem.  Language barriers often complicate it, but still that should be enough room.  If you do take it to chat - you are encouraging them to treat it as a tutoring session though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh. I've faced an almost similar issue several times. The OP asks a question which some of us answer (very fast, if the question is simple). I then go look at another question, suddenly my rep starts falling, when I see *from where*, BAM!. The OP would have changed the question completely, making my answer look like a joke.

What do I do?.

1. Place a comment asking the OP NOT to repeat this.
2. Try editing the answer. If I can't add anything new to an existing correct answer (assuming the updated question has been answered correctly by someone), *delete* my answer. If nobody has answered it,  then edit my answer.

Comment: Following has latest 'one more thing', I have suggested the OP start a new question, as it's now a completely different one. I think my Answer edits are clear enough to illustrate what he *had* asked. It's a slightly weird one because, after he deleted his other questions (rather than chameleon the original), it looks like I've answered his original post and then added some bonus answers on there just for yucks.

Comment: If the OP changes the question so drastically it's asking something entirely different—rollback!

Comment: "...making my answer look like a joke." :D... laughed hard. :D :D

Answer (score 6):

I have also had this happen to me on multiple occasions... I usually get away by:

- Rolling back the question to the original state and
- politely notify the user that if he has a new question to ask a new question and provide a link to the current one and explain the relation (*if any*)

Believe me, this method works most of the time: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20223105/2140173),[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19089281/2140173),[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18978839/2140173),[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19634142/2140173),[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19977563/2140173),[[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20330199/2140173),[[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25661659/2140173)

Also, worth mentioning that radical editing of the original question invalidates current answers.