# Can I ask the author to clarify/explain their answer?

Tags: discussion

Let's say I get an answer to a question which solves my problem, but I do not understand why the author chose to do it this way or I don't understand how it works in general. Should I:

1. Figure it out by myself via documentation, etc.?
2. Ask for clarification from the author?

Comment: Most answerers are fine with explaining a point or two in comments, but like with full questions, doing your own research helps us help you.

Comment: Sometimes, it's better to ask a full question, linking that answer and detailling what exactly you didn't understand about it. Naturally, standard rules for asking questions apply.

Comment: Its your wish. The comments section exists for clarifing doubts. The docs can also be refered, but it will be hard to find and understand what you need using the docs as they contain lots of extra information. Personally, I would have posted a comment.

Comment: Please, please, please always read the docs first, or google something in particular.

Comment: Please make sure you don't try to turn you post into [Chameleon Question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer)... Otherwise asking for *clarifications* is fine as long as you demonstrate at least remote understanding of language/concept used in the question.

Comment: Comment to ask for clarification is fine. Just like you would comment to suggest improvements to questions, you can suggest improvements to answers.  New questions should be new questions.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[Why not both?](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/why-not-both-why-dont-we-have-both)

Within reason, an answer should contain at least some explanation, if it doesn't feel free to ask for *some*.

I say "within reason" in the sense that an answer should be somewhat self contained. If the question is "How do I foo the bar?" It is reasonable to expect some explanation of what "foo-ing" is and how it is done. So a follow up comment like "That seems to work, can you explain why it works?" is completely reasonable.

On the other hand if you need extended help, you should probably do the research. If the question is "How do I foo the bar?" and your follow up comment is "What is a foo? What is a bar? and how do I print Hello World?", you're pushing it.

**TL;DR**

It is reasonable to ask someone to explain their answer. It isn't reasonable to ask someone to take the time to teach you the language from scratch.

Comment: On a side note, this is a big part of the reason why I'm not a fan of code only answers.

Comment: Indeed. Code only answers only really work for the most trivial of questions. Otherwise some description around what's going on and how makes for a better answer. If it's unclear, then a comment indicating that is appropriate.

Comment: @apaul34208 code only answers can have the specific answer in comments because it's easier to explain it in that way.

Comment: Your example sounds a bit strange because if somebody wants to foo a bar I would expect that they know what "foo-ing" is and that it doesn't need to be explained to them. Why would they ask how to do it if they don't even know what it is. But probably I'm just misinterpreting in the metasyntactical variables.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Very true, I'm more referring to cases where there is just a code dump. I honestly prefer well commented code in some cases.

Comment: @sth Often difficulties and questions arise because someone wants to do something they don't fully grok yet. They may have a rough idea of what foo-ing is, but they're struggling because they don't have a firm grasp on it yet.

Comment: `"How do I foo the bar?"` i like the question.ROFL :)

Answer (score 10):

On "I don't understand how it works in general" part - it is really a good reason to ask a *new question* - make sure to refer to the original question in a new one and consider if a link to the new one should be added (as a comment) to the original answer.

At that point, assuming you are planning to write a good question, you'd read some documentation, look for duplicates and possibly solve the problem yourself.

If you feel that you are missing something small to understand the approach - add a comment, but *please* demonstrate that you at least understand the language and are going to do your own research and not use the answerer as a consultant (and *actually do that* :)). Something like:

> "It works, but I can't understand why - it looks like Foo to me, but the syntax should be different; what feature should I read about to understand that?".

A follow-up comment of

> "if you need more details, the Bar feature used in this answer is described in XXXXX"

would be very nice and may even score some bonus points from the answerer (in sense of "this person actually cares - next time our paths cross I *know* to expect a good question/participation").

Answer (score -3):

Yes... but carefully!

If you're not satisfied/convinced with the approach/answer - you can/should go back and ask on your doubt ... BUT ...(now the careful part starts) ...

Yes:

1. You can ask to clarify any particular point
2. You can question on any alternative approach
3. You can ask for any supporting link / doc

No:

1. Once someone answered, you shouldn't expect that they will drop everything again and explain things (Time is valuable).
2. Someone can help others - not spoon-feed.
3. On forums - everyone can clear doubts; no-one can teach details.

KISS - Keep it Short & Simple.

Comment: I thought KISS was "keep it simple, stupid"

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously by anyone over the age of 30, spell out the word "you" and "your", use the formatting features of Markdown for lists, and don't use that many dots.