# How to handle questions that require remedial and advanced help?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know how others handle a question that asks about something too advanced for the questioner's apparent skill level.  An answer to the explicitly-asked part of the question might help future readers, but the answer that will most help the questioner is probably more remedial, suggesting that they learn first how to confidently solve several antecedent problems.

The more questioner-oriented, instructive answer often leads to longer comment threads, coaching about debug techniques, answer edits, the need often to retitle the and rephrase the question, and so on.

I don't mind engaging in that sort of thing when I have the time -- in fact, I really like when it culminates with a light bulb switching on at the other end.  But what's considered the normative line on too much pedagogy?  ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987380/organized-combined-array-from-parse-by-date?noredirect=1#comment55736219_33987380) as an imperfect but recent example.  In this case we finally got to a correct, accepted answer, but it took a lot of conversation to get the OP there).

Comment: Stack Overflow is about answering questions in such a way that they are useful to other users, not just the question asker. You should answer the question asked to the best of your ability without large amounts of noise. If a user needs to read an introductory tutorial for that language, then point them to one in the comments.

Comment: Tangentially related, from the asker's point of view: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285579/1947286

Comment: Side note: if you are willing to spend a lot of time on the question why not to edit it into something reasonably looking - good title (maybe "Organized Combined Array" means something special if you think different, but for me from old Windows world it looks strange), clean up code sample a bit (unless every line need to be surrounded by new line in that language)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dangerous and counter-productive to make an assumption about one's skill level, primarily because they're not the only benefactor of the answer.  It gets worse if we think about it in inverse: wouldn't the case be that the question they're asking is over their understanding level?

But that's *just* the OP. Someone else may come along and immediately understand the answer.  I know I've been burned once or twice on some really simple answers, whereas I could just understand a more straightforward solution, even if it wasn't catered to an entry-level or pre-entry-level developer.

I've been in some scenarios in which I can describe:

- The user has had a question, to which they have some rough understanding of what needs to be done next, but need an extra push.
- The user has a question to which they have *no* idea what's going wrong, but they can take a hint.
- The user has a question to which they have *no* idea what's going wrong *and* they assume that we're going to be here to help them through it.

In *none* of those cases have I ever altered my answer to hand-hold the OP through it.  By and large, the answers I've given have been either to the tune of:

- Provide a rough solution, **explaining what the thought process is in plain English**, before providing code.
- Providing tips on how to proceed next; why one style of code or one approach in code may be less favorable than another.
- Clarifying points which may have been muddled by my own explanations.
- Provide citations and references to other articles to back up and reinforce the answer that I've made (most often done with questions about Java concerning the JLS).

I'd say the big thing is to **be clear** about what the solution is, and explain it in plain terms.  Code can come after that if it's needed for emphasis, but don't make it a point to *only* provide code if you can help it.  Don't anticipate that someone is going to ask you to hold their hand (as it were), and don't make it out like you wish to offer that kind of service.