# Should edits to questions by the OP require approval once there is at least one upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

As a protection against [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer), would it help to require approval for edits to questions by the OP, once their question has already been answered and at least one answer has up-votes?

It might seem harsh to impose restrictions on people editing their own content, but there are already restrictions that prevent answerers from deleting their own answers once they are accepted, and question askers are also prevented from deleting their own questions once there is at least one answer.

Besides being frustrating to whoever answered the question, questions that are edited to include follow up questions, new "fix this for me" bugs etc are a less useful resource for third parties: I've seen quite a few questions that started off well enough: a straightforward question about a reproducible bug gets answered in a couple of paragraphs with a few lines of code, a helpful reference and an explanation, then the OP decides to turn everything into a mess by making their question a stratch pad for whatever is wrong with their project at that point in time, which in turn leads to the answers becoming a mess of edits too.

If such edits required approval then reviewers could watch for this kind of behaviour by rejecting the edits. If the question has already attracted a quality answer (as determined by the community) then arguably it doesn't really need to be edited, and if so then it still can, but with approval.

The editing-your-own-question restriction could be removed for high rep users.

Comment: What if you get into a bind in which a user asks one question, but actually intended to ask a related yet slightly different one?  What about clarifications or additions to the question that the user wants to make, as in the case of bounties?

Comment: What about user asks unclear question, comments ask for clarification, but some... person... jumps in an posts an answer anyway? OK, items don't stay in the review queue long, but the dumb answer is then dumb and in the way. Also, it's a lot to expect that edit reviewers in search of a gold badge will pause and thoughtfully say to themselves "is this one of those lizard things?"

Comment: In those cases, the edits can be approved. The requirement for at least one upvote is intended to prevent dumb answers getting in the way, sure they might get upvoted anyway but it's less likely. Also, if the user intended to ask one thing but asked another, they should have thought harder before asking the question and getting other people to expend effort answering it. At that stage, what's wrong with just saying it's too late to change horses in the middle of a race? Even the answers to the unintended question could be useful to others

Comment: In the current situation it takes one responsible user to "police" the question, and users are often more flexible than programmatic action. Do you have some evidence that this breaks down sufficiently that a change should be made to attempt to rely on the unreliable Edit Review Queue?

Comment: @BillWoodger by the same token it only takes one responsible user to police a question for bad edits, so why not just get rid of the Edit Review Queue altogether? The fact is it's better than nothing. My thinking behind this proposal is that - in general - suggested edits are very rarely damaging. I reject plenty for contributing nothing but very few are actively harmful. By contrast plenty of edits by OPs to their own questions are actively harmful for the reasons I outlined. So they make a more worthy target for edit reviewers attention (as imperfect as that attention may be)

Comment: It takes three responsible users to reject an edit. To get three users responsible enough to reject because the question is changed it a way it shouldn't be I think is less likely than someone who has looked at the question and requested more information (I can be wrong). Do you have evidence of substantial failure to identify questions as they are revealed as lizards? To put it another way, is it an actual problem. It isn't in the tags that I look at, but those are very low-volume. It may be different in high-volume tags, for instance.

Comment: @BillWoodger how would I go about collecting statistics about the frequency of something like "chameleon questions"? Seems impossible.

Comment: From your experience do you have a number of example where you came late to a question and found oner or more answers undermined by the changed nature of the question? If not, I'd wonder if there is a problem, or in other words that people are already dealing with the problem effectively.

Comment: @BillWoodger yes I have had that experience multiple times, but I wasn't saving links to them as I went. But even if I had 10 or even 20 such links, would that even prove anything given that there are almost 10 million questions on SO?