# Are questions by default permitted to evolve, and if so, to what extent?

Tags: discussion, edits

It is a usual case that the initial question which is posted
may undergo a series of changes during the troubleshooting/debugging 
process and the final version of the question might not have 
anything to do with the first version of it.

I would call such a thing 'evolution', though I am not sure that is the
right term. Is such 'evolution' by default allowed per Stack Overflow's 
principles?

Adding new issues as **edits** seems to be a good idea but in some cases
the user might be asking a new question through their edits.
Should this be encouraged? If no, is it OK to ask a user to consider 
posting a new question, in the larger interest, that it might be useful
for a broader category of people who search for this evolved question?

Comment: Sounds like **[chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)**

Comment: @lad2025 : That looks like a cracker !! Yes ! This one looks a bit like it with the difference that I am not looking for an exit strategy.

Comment: I'd like to personally thank you for posing the question about whether or not questions *could* evolve.  You wouldn't believe me if I told you how many times I've just *seen* them evolve, often without any warning.

Comment: Wait, what?  Why would this be considered a duplicate of [*that*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253762/1079354) question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** the usual case.  In fact, it's explicitly discouraged and even has its own name for it - [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Opinions on the minutiae vary, but the main point is this:

**If you wish to modify your existing question with respect to knowledge gained from answers or comments, you should capture it in a new question**, with the main proviso there being that one should at least **attempt to solve the problem further** before asking a completely new question.

Asking two or more questions in the span of an hour concerning similar-looking pieces of code indicates that one is not doing their due diligence in attempting to solve the problem.  At that point, they're offloading the problem solving portion to Stack Overflow, which isn't why we're here.

Ultimately, if you've got one part of your question answered, consider the question "resolved"; but if you've got another question to ask, first **do your work to see how far you can get**, then ask a *new* question about where you're stuck.

Comment: I liked the terminology `offloading`. Though this is explicitly dicouraged, is it still the `usual case`?

Comment: No; if weaker, I certainly hope not.  We as a community should be moving to nip that in the bud so that it doesn't become a point of frustration for answerers.

Comment: Got the point. Cheers !