# How do we handle original questions with "new requirements," after a correct "answer"

Tags: discussion

I was helping someone with [their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358034/how-do-i-export-just-one-worksheet-in-excel-to-a-single-htm-file), and after much back-and-forth within the comments, determined what they *actually needed* wasn't what was *originally requested.*

Furthermore, the original poster then returned to the comments, agreeing that the solution worked as they had requested, but they didn't like how it behaved when their code continues when doing a completely separate routine, and resulting in (what I consider to be) a completely separate question/problem.

While I've tried to recommend they post a separate question in the comments, it seems to me that the **original question** should possibly be either:

1. Closed, and opened anew 
   (With a clearer indication of the full scope of the problem and their requirements) or...
2. Edited (again), wherein I would also need to edit my answer in order to support this.
   (This approach is frustrating to both parties, and could get messy given the length of the comments discussion.)

Seems like this could get way out of hand, if it continued.  What do we do in these situations, typically?  While I recognize there are [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253829/2486496) [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130630) discussions on here, my specific question around this is more to the point of...

**What do we do with the original question now?**
*(as opposed to, "What do we do when requirements change after a proper answer?")*

Comment: MSE related post: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/178816)