# Why was technical C++ question deleted, apparently by non-C++ users?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a technical but precise post about how C++ handles certain regular expressions, [What is the position of an unmatched group in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017185/what-is-the-position-of-an-unmatched-group-in-c) . The post was answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik . It turned out the most common reference that C++ users use, http://cppreference.com , was missing the information I needed, but Galik found the answer in the standard, so this answer can be used to improve that cppreference.

So the post and answer were both useful, so useful it will might help improve a major reference. There seems no reason to delete the post.

Two of the three users who voted to delete the post seem to have no particular interest in C++, at least it is not in their profiles and I could not find any C++ questions they ever answered.

Why is a precise, useful, on-topic post that elicited a lacuna in a major C++ reference by a top C++ contributor deleted?

Comment: I mean, it's not for the op to decide what is or isn't useful, so forgive me for not taking your word for it. The voting seems to be... contested (+3, then -4 over a 9 day period leading up to deletion)

Comment: "I could not find any C++ questions they ever answered." [Really? One of them has answered 194 C++ questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3832970+[c%2b%2b])

Comment: @KevinB That’s true. But you can just read Galik’s answer, quoting the standard. You know it’s useful because it’s in the standard. And from the comments to the answer, you know it’s not in cppreference.com, which a bit of googling will confirm is the main information source for C++ coders. So taken together, these facts shows] the post and answer are useful.

Comment: I agree that it's not obvious why this question was deleted, but can you please tone down the speech against non-C++-people? This person not very familiar with C++ can assure you that "But my question wouldn’t make sense to anyone who is not already very familiar with C++." is blatantly false.

Comment: from my pov this doesn't appear to be any kind of targeted closure/deletion, it all happened over time, just people using the tools they've been given. It's certainly possible they got it wrong

Comment: All of that said...I agree this post should not have been deleted. It seems to be clear and have a useful answer. I would vote to undelete unless a reason that it's bad is given.

Comment: eh, i don't think the answer quoting the standard is directly enough to indicate that it's useful. It's useful if people find it when they need it. this was closed over a 9 day period, overwhich it also received several downvotes and no upvotes. I can agree with it being undeleted... but past that i don't think it should be held to any higher standard just because of the answer. undelete it and let it run it's course

Comment: Focus less on the users and more on the post. It's more likely you'll get a productive experience that way.

Comment: @RyanM ok but 2/3 of the people who voted to delete have never answered a C++ question and show no indication I could find of having any interest in the language. What is causing this piling on of people who would not have a natural reason to read my question to vote to delete it? Doesn’t this seem odd to you?

Comment: c++ isn't the only tag on the question, and tags aren't the only way questions are found

Comment: @KevinB my point is not that the answer quoted the standard, it was that the answer was not in the standard C++ reference outside the standard. That’s what makes it useful.

Comment: Look, can anyone give a single reasonable reason why anyone, C++ or non-C++ user, could possibly have voted to delete the question? You combine that with the fact that 2/3 of the voters probably have no interest in C++ - this all seems like possibly an indication of a more fundamental problem, at least if it is happening to others. Are other users going around deleting posts in areas they do not have expertise in for no reason (if that is what is happening here, and nobody has provided any evidence it is not).

Comment: @RyanM I understand that you think the question should be undeleted. But can you think of any reason at all that multiple people would have found anything remotely objectionable or that could cause a deletion? What could possibly be motivating them?

Comment: Worth noting that as of several minutes ago, the question has in fact been undeleted.

Comment: My guess would be that they disliked that an answer could potentially be obtained by simply running the code. But this doesn't answer what the spec requires, so I would disagree with that logic, if it is in fact the logic behind it.

Comment: It's a good question, and the closure as "unclear" seems strange; I found it clear enough myself. I certainly don't think it deserved to be deleted. I have *guesses* as to why the question was closed and deleted, but I'm frustrated that I have to guess at all. It would have been really nice if at least one of the close/delete voters had left a comment explaining their rationale, but they don't appear to have done so (at least from the visible comments).

Comment: I mean... the close reasons were changed specifically so that wouldn't be required.

Comment: @RyanM But that’s unreasonable. The question could not possibly be answered by running code. Running code would just show what m.position() is for one possible pattern, for one regex, for one architecture, for one compiler version. It would have no applicability to other strings, or regexes, or compilers, or compiler versions, or platforms. It is implausible that anyone would believe running the code would be relevant (except to that one specific regex, compiler, and platform).

Comment: @KevinB Oh, I'm not saying it's *required* to explain a close/delete vote; it definitely isn't. I'm just saying it would have been nice, so as to avoid having to guess, *especially* since the closure and deletion are both extremely borderline at best. Hopefully one of those users will see this Meta and leave an explanation here.

Comment: So your question was undeleted now, but it sounds like you aren't satisfied with that. What do you actually want to happen here?

Comment: I can only speculate, as I did not vote to close/delete and I think the question is fine (I voted to reopen, in fact).  Based on my experience and the fact that there is a comment asking "What do you get when you run that code?", I am entirely willing to believe that because you could obtain the answer for that particular string (or others) by running the code, someone thought it was a bad question.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I don't follow. The OP is asking quite clearly *why* the question was deleted, and their comments are just reiterating that question. I presume they would like an answer to that. The OP hasn't even asked for their Main question to be undeleted (though I'm sure that's implicit), so I'm not sure why you think the undeletion alone would be satisfactory to the OP.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I would like to understand the root cause of why multiple people, most with likely no possible interest in or understanding of the question, all went out of their way to delete the question for no apparent reason. I want to know this both for my own future questions and for other questions on the site. Most people do not have time to engage in long meta-discussions: if we do not know why this is happening we do not know how often it is happening and how to prevent it in the future and for others - maybe other good tech questions are being deleted? There must be some reason.

Comment: @cigien Do they expect us to read the minds of the delete voters? I know what they *want*, but I don't know what they want *to happen*.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery These Meta questions get asked fairly frequently, and there are a number of possible outcomes, e.g. answers could be provided that make an educated guess as to the delete voters' reasons based on those voters track record for similar questions, or an answer could talk about how Main questions of this nature get deleted, or ideally (and this happens often) one of the delete voters will notice this Meta discussion and pitch in with an answer explaining their rationale.

Comment: @kdog if you don't want people outside of C++ to know about the question please do not tag with additional tags. Regex is a tag with couple followers too and when you *demand* those people to look at the question by adding the tag then don't complain their looked at/acted on the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't understand your logic. Aren't tags meant to indicate to SMEs that it's a question they might want to look at? The [regex] tag is eminently suitable for that question, and in fact, I would add that tag in since the question is *very* related to regexes.

Comment: @cigien this is exactly what OP complains about - one of the top SME of the regex tag acted on the OP's post tagged with "regex"...

Comment: @kdog you may or may not be aware of the existence of "Review Queues". You can access it in the top navigation by clicking the icon of the box with the checkmark on top. The site relies on review queues to help moderate the vast amount of posts. Users who volunteer can go there and are presented with posts meeting different criteria (first time posters, suggested edits, etc.). They can vote to take an action such as deletion, closing, reopening, etc. So they probably didn't "go out of their way to delete the question". They merely saw it pop up in their review and voted to delete.

Comment: @cigien OP is complaining that non-C++ experts acted on the question. The question that wasn't brought to the attention of C++ experts only. Moreover, if the question is indeed so tightly related with C++ itself as to *only* rely on the specs of it, then it doesn't sound like regex knowledge helps there. It seems that OP believes it's a C++ question, related to C++ specifications and implementations and it *happens* to mention regex. But the last part seems irrelevant to understanding or answering the question. You could have the same situation with arithmetic or other implementations.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I’m confused as to why someone who didn’t know C++ would bother to vote to remove the question. Can you give a plausible reason that a person who didn’t know C++ or care about it would decide that a question about the behavior of std::smatch::position() for an unmatched capturing group would vote to delete?

Comment: @kdog Aside from getting the individuals who cast said votes to respond, it's impossible to know why (other than giving them the benefit of the doubt and accepting the reason they chose to close with as the reason they chose to close... whether you agree or not.)

Comment: I don't see why that question uses regex related tags. Yes, there's a regex on the question, but it isn't about the regex but how the language itself returns from tokenization operations. Regex by itself doesn't do anything that the question is asking about.

Comment: @VLAZ This is quite fascinating. I notice that nobody is really defending the closure or the deletion. Yet, instead of admitting those users are at fault in anyway, it's somehow the *OP's fault* for inviting those users to view the question by using an incorrect tag? If the only thing the OP is at fault for is using the incorrect tags (and like I said, I don't even think the tag is inappropriate), shouldn't the SMEs simply have removed the incorrect tag, and perhaps downvoted the question for wasting their time? I don't understand how an incorrect tag justifies a closure or a deletion.

Comment: @Braiam I am not entirely sure what you mean by “how the language itself returns from tokenization”. smatch and smatch::position(i) are used exclusively for general regexes in C++. This is how C++ handles regex. The question applies to most C++ regex usages where the regex uses grouping, not just tokenization. The question has nothing to do with tokenization per se. Most  regex questions are about specific language for regex anyway. Some might be about how Python handles a regex, or JavaScript, Perl; this is about how C++ handles it. regex seems the best tag for a question about C++ regex API.

Comment: @KevinB it might be impossible to know why it was deleted, it might not. Surely the admins have tools to analyze deletion patterns - perhaps those tools would be helpful absent an explanation.

Comment: @cigien it's less pointing fault, and more... avoiding such. Whether or not the users were wrong doesn't really seem to be important. People voted, as they are allowed to do, and the community is free to overturn those votes. that's simply how it works, we don't need to chase down these users and get an answer. There doesn't need to be an at fault at all.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, you're right. I suppose I'm focusing too much on whether specific users are responsible for any individual incorrect closure/deletion, which is not particularly productive. I guess when I see what I think is a very odd result, I assume *someone* is responsible, but it can often just be a result of systemic issues instead. I agree that focusing on that would definitely be better.

Comment: @kdog Because the regex tag is used for the pattern itself, not the surrounding paraphernalia that languages include. I could ask the same question with a different pattern, as long as the pattern has at least more than one group (since otherwise it would make the question moot). If you read questions that include the regex tag, you will be hard pressed to find questions that aren't about the pattern.

Comment: @Braiam The regex tag documentation does not support your claim that "the regex tag is used for the pattern itself", see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info . Therefore, question about the regex API of a particular language are within scope of that tag. Recent examples indicate numerous regex API questions in C++ tagged with regex, e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253526/properly-compiling-c-code-that-uses-the-tre-regex-library or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855728/constructing-stdregex-from-a-char-slice-without-copy .

Comment: @RyanM By the way the original question specifically asked for what was "guaranteed" to happen which rules out trying various compilers and regexes (which as I pointed out earlier would not have answered the question anyway).

Comment: I don't know what are you reading kdog, but every item there is about the patterns and the specific implementations of the patterns (aka dialects). The "how to ask" explicitly asks you "sample input, expected output" of the pattern. If that's not a hint that you should only use the tag for questions about the patterns... I don't know how clearer would it be.

Comment: @Braiam It is not the case that "the 'how to ask' explicitly asks you 'sample input, expected output' of the pattern. " It says for "most questions" such a sample input is required, showing that for other questions it is not.  You added the "of the pattern" requirement yourself - that is not what the text of the tag description states. Obviously, if you implicitly add an "of the pattern" requirement to all the examples in the tag description, you will impute an "of the pattern" requirement. But such a requirement or expectation is just not in the language of the tag description itself.

Answer (score 24):

I'm going to dodge the main thrust of the question; it doesn't matter if someone doesn't have experience in the technology to moderate and close questions.  If they can't understand the premise of the question *in general* (that is, assuming that they're technically competent but can't understand the nature of the ask), then it's fair game for anyone to close a question.

That said I do want to call out this pattern that's been pretty popular as of late on Stack Overflow.  Question closure exists as a way for the OP to come back to fix problems or deficiencies with the question.  Question deletion exists to remove content which is irredeemable and unsalvageable from public view.  Closing and deleting the question within mere minutes of each other is an anti-pattern that means that OPs don't have a chance to reach for the alleged olive branch that we're giving them in the first place with question closure.

To be blunt I saw no reason for the question to be closed.  I don't understand C++ all that well, but I didn't see anything in the question to immediately raise a red flag, either.  You ask a tight, specifically referenceable, "Hey I can't find an answer ***here***; does anyone else have an idea??"-style question which shows that you've done your homework enough that any C++ expert should feel comfortable with filling in the gaps.

Comment: "Closing and deleting the question within mere minutes of each other" how? Are we seeing the same question? It was deleted several days after, so there was plenty of time for the OP to fix it. Also, even then, OP has by default 2 days unless it has a score of -2 or less, so in any case that statement has no basis on reality.

Comment: @Makoto If a question tagged C++ and <regex> should be understandable by people who do not know C++, should it also be understandable by people who do not know regex? Should I have included an introduction explaining what regexes, what capturing groups are, and how C++ handles them? Such a policy would make questions much longer and more difficult to read, and would cut against the utility of the site.

Comment: @Braiam what do you mean “fix”? There was nothing to fix in the question. That’s the gravamen of the whole discussion here.

Comment: @kdog When I read the posted question, I see several issues that should be corrected and a bit of rewrite to make the question better beginning with the title.

Comment: @kdog Your question *is* understandable by people with only passing knowledge of C++ and regex. Please don't focus on that so much. It only distracts from the issue that even someone who is *not* an expert should not have closed and deleted the question.

Comment: @kdog Makoto's argument is that the author of the question weren't give enough time to "come back to fix problems or deficiencies with the question". I'm saying that the author did have such time.

Comment: The edit history shows post created Feb 2, post closed Feb 3, post deleted Feb 12 with no changes within more than a week from post closed to post deleted.

Comment: Let's not focus on *time* too much. The point is, the close and delete happened without the OP having a chance to fix the question – because it was entirely unclear what to fix about it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi they had plenty of time, as did anyone who wanted to keep the question around. the answerer could have edited it, or cast a reopen vote, any 3 random people who passed by could have reopened it in that 9 day period, it could have been opened in the review queue during that 9 day period, but none of that happened. That's not a very good look for a question that is "useful", you'd think something that was useful would get some attention

Comment: @KevinB I cannot comment on the C++ tag, but if it is anything even *remotely* close to the Python tag then "useful" and "attention" are almost entirely uncorrelated. Either some experienced person adopts the questions (e.g. follows) quickly, or it just drowns in the noise. There is way too much crap to accurately find, let alone properly handle, the pearls in it.

Comment: and...  a question asking for an answer that's in the standard is a pearl? it's a curiosity at best

Comment: @KevinB It was a well-posed question, concise but complete, understandable to non-experts, and citing obvious references. Sneering aside, that's a pretty good question in my book.

Comment: None of that makes it useful, ;)

Comment: @KevinB I would like to point out that this discussion is about whether the question should have been closed/deleted. If you find the question to not be *useful* (and you're certainly welcome to that opinion) then you should downvote the question. For example, I have never found a JavaScript question to be useful (because I don't write code in that language). While I'm welcome to downvote every JS question I see, I think you'd agree that this doesn't give me the right to close/delete them on that basis.

Comment: @cigien yeah, that's not at all what I'm arguing, but thanks!

Comment: I understand C++ quite well, and I endorse this answer. It appears to be one of those cases where people tried in vain to find a "general reference" close reason, couldn't find one, so applied one of the reasons that obviously *doesn't* apply. Not that the question is even "general reference", even if that *were* a valid reason to close questions on Stack Overflow. Time aside, deletion of that Q&A was contraindicated due to the high quality answer.

Comment: @CodyGray I do not understand your comment that "It appears to be one of those cases where people tried in vain to find a 'general reference' close reason". What is a 'general reference close reason' and why would people try in vain to find one?

Comment: @RichardChambers what issues in the question "should be corrected"?

Comment: @kdog https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258851/what-guidance-should-we-give-people-asking-unclear-questions-on-stack-overflow it's hard to provides specifics in a comment. too little room.