# What should we do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, regex

There's a subject I'm pretty good with. I like to share my knowledge with others through answers. Unfortunately, there's another user active in the tag who makes participation extremely frustrating. This user:

- Aggressively closes questions as duplicates - which is good, usually! Linking related questions together helps readers and helps consolidate knowledge about a particular problem.

  - Even when the target question doesn't have much to do with the original question - which isn't so good ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65977165), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130271), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66193269), and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968823))
  - Even when the target question doesn't have anything at all to do with the original question - which isn't good ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053206), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548719), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66143042/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067745), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016993), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65861554), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753629), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680827), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680208), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66150167), and so many more)
- **Votes to delete most questions with answers that he has closed**

  - Even when the answers are unquestionably valuable and not covered by any answers on the target ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66017185/timeline) - this was [discussed on Meta earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405252). [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966956), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65982381), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65977165), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66034925) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998127) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65548719) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66018195), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64013256), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66032829), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123660), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66215433), and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66195982))
  - And even when the target question has very few votes/linked questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65949774), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196591), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65267099/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65967286), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65963625), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976199), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024829), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56043575), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65992638), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989383), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66013555/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66103594), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66140679), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65958971/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65423905/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66122885), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66010404/timeline), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66231322), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66120065), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66214373), and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66117578) - these last two both had two delete votes before being reopened)

Moderators can probably find a great number of similar examples [by searching through deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D%20score%3A3%20deleted%3Ayes%20is%3Aa).

From what I understand, duplicate questions are **signposts**. They help point the poster, answerers, and future readers to a centralized target. If the duplicate question contains answers, those answers often contain useful information or another way of looking at things not covered in the target. I have been under the impression that this provides value to readers which should not be destroyed without good reason.

Of course, if a question has been asked [many times already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285), the existence of the question and any possible answers very likely does not provide value, and deletion is well warranted. But the questions I have seen get deleted are very often *not* in this category - the linked targets (when they have something to do with the question at all) frequently only have a small number of votes/views/other linked questions.

Some of these closed questions are requests for solutions without showing what the user has tried so far. These questions are usually not high quality - that's what we have downvotes for. But using one's gold badge to close them (sometimes for an unrelated duplicate) just so one has the ability to delete the post later seems like an abuse of the system to me, for a non-♦.

The [official help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says:

> ### When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted.
>
> Before voting to delete, please check whether there are **any good answers;** if so, then the question should be flagged for moderator attention as a potential merge candidate. We don't like to lose great answers!
>
> Also, be cautious when deleting questions closed as **duplicates;** [they can serve as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.

Now, it takes three users to vote to delete. One user cannot delete everything themselves. *But*, a vote to delete [pushes the post into the 10k tools list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today), and if a post gets onto the list, in my observation, there's a halfway decent chance of the post getting deleted, *regardless of the quality of the post or the quality of the answers*. There are a number of users who visit that page most days and spend most of their delete votes there. With all due respect, I think many of them do not really take time to consider:

> Is this post *really* of such low quality that it and all its answers should be removed from the site?

In contrast, I think some see it as a sink to use up their delete votes. In their defense, a significant majority of posts that appear there really are objectively terrible and don't deserve to remain, at least in my opinion - but there are no audits, it's not a review queue, and there is no real oversight on what gets deleted. If you frequent that page, most days, you will usually see quite a few posts on the list that originate from this user's initial delete vote. (I also have quite a few reasons to believe that some sockpuppetry is going on to make deletion easier - but that's a separate issue)

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV7rq.png) for an example. Do you see the pattern? [The same thing on another day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDKTM.png). And [another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDaBT.png). Many days, a long string of delete votes in that tag is common, without distinction between posts with value and posts without.

Lots of users with the privilege vote to delete every now and then and everyone makes mistakes occasionally. But these aren't just mistakes. This is a systematic attempted deletion of what seems to be most questions in a tag that one user doesn't agree with. (I'm not saying that *all* of the questions I've linked deserve to remain on the site, but in my opinion, a good chunk of them do. And I'm not asking for action on any of them in particular, it's only the *persistent pattern* that worries me.)

**Is this sort of deletion behavior an acceptable use of one's privileges?** It's been going on for many years, and has surely resulted in multiple thousands of questions getting deleted.

Personally, I see it as senselessly destroying value, and I think it serves as a serious chilling effect for any other would-be regular participant in the tag. A well-received, accepted, good-faith answer on an on-topic question has a decent chance of being deleted regardless, if the question happens to rub one particular user the wrong way. But there aren't any *official* rules against it, and some here may see deletion as justified if the one who posted the question has not included an attempt, or has a fundamental misunderstanding of how pattern matching works, or due to some other reason. What does Meta think?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this post. I will just say that just by reading the title, I guessed the relevant tag... and I was right.

Comment: My stomach sank when I saw the title, but reading through the post I have to say I'm impressed with how you've presented the question; it can be hard to discuss the actions of a specific user while also keeping the tone civil, and open to feedback. Well done.

Comment: Are you asking in general or about this specific case? Because the title and the ending of the question is general and the rest is about a specific case. I'd prefer to discuss a specific case, mention that it's about [tag:regex], mention the user, mention how the "tag-community" is maybe special in the behaviour, mention how the technology should be potentially handled differently and so on. I feel like after reading that there is much diffuse information, finished by the question "Is this sort of deletion behavior an acceptable use of one's privileges?": In general, obviously not.

Comment: I highly recommend readders to, [please read this meta post once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/10844#10844). **Should duplicates be deleted?** In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort Wiktor puts into curating the regex tag. Majority of the questions with that tag are too localized, and thus can not be helpful to anyone but the question authors. I don't think closing and deleting them cause any loss of value at all.

Comment: *too localized, and thus can not be helpful to anyone* is a slippery rope with every reader having a different opinion on that. We can never guess how a question may help a future visitor dealing with similar (if not same) problem, not to forget it's added SEO value. Keeping a dupe is fine if question has been answered already but deletion is unwarranted.

Comment: @oguzismail I do appreciate the effort he puts into curating the tag as well as his useful content. There's no question that his answers are of great value. That being said, I also can't help but notice the pattern of deleting valuable content as demonstrated in this post.

Comment: While I can agree with the sentiment, to a certain extent, this is so focused in one single user (or maybe two, if one looks at the patterns), that it feels like it could be better material for a mod flag than a meta post. Like this looks a bit like like a veiled call for pitchforks and torches.

Comment: And what's up with the trend of minting socks to post in meta?

Comment: @yivi I got a bit tired of the backslash from last time I posted a question on Meta ...

Comment: @rene I find it distasteful, particularly when it looks like a disguised call to arms. Also seems to have some similarities with questions posted by other users (both regular and socks) in the last weeks. I find it distracting. But in any case, I still think this is flag material, not meta material.

Comment: Because the OP has used a sockpuppet, it renders their statement *"I like to share my knowledge with others through answers."* pretty moot, and ends up feeling like the OP lacks the "credentials" (for lack of a better word) on the site to be able to make some of these claims. Especially when many new users don't understand the close and delete processes, and why they happen. *This* user has **never** contributed an answer.

Comment: @yivi yeah, from these examples a pattern emerges that makes it mod material. Not because I think the user being targeted is wrong, just for the fact that I doubt we get all the data, all the insight, all the raised flags, all the history that is needed to make the right call here. We (us mortals) are not the right audience, unless there is some "hidden" agenda.

Comment: Don't remove the signposts! Thanks for posting this.

Comment: @rene I can't speak for the OP's motives, but I can think of some reasons why a Meta post is useful in addition to raising a flag. The user in question, and possibly other users who engage in such behavior, may not know that what they're doing is controversial. Discussing this on Meta gives the community an opportunity to discuss whether such behavior is problematic, and a consensus might emerge either way. The users who do this might realize the issues, and change their behavior according to the consensus. Only raising a flag means the other users never even realize there might be an issue.

Comment: @cigien I actually find questioning OP motives, considering that meta reactionary is pretty much _fait accompli_ when framed in such a way: this user is doing evil by deleting many questions (despite the fact that less than 2% of all deletions on the site, so there's too much slack).

Comment: @cigien agreed, if it is dealt with only behind the scenes then nobody really gets the opportunity to see this and realise they're part of a problem.

Comment: I don't think anything of value was lost here.

Comment: @Larnu The post's credibility should not be affected by who the author is. I think this question, like any question, can stand (or not) on its own merits.

Comment: I would agree, if the OP didn't make claims they contribute when they clearly don't, @TylerH . Each user is meant to be independent, which means that they can't be claiming on this account to be having problems with someone they likely, on this account, have had no interactions with. I know who the author isx they are broccoli, no one else; and they have made no answers on [so].

Comment: Not knowing the author eliminates our ability to establish bias by looking through their previous interactions with said users or their usage of the tags in question. It turns it into a very one sided attack

Comment: @KevinB Which, I'd argue, is *exactly* why OP structured this post as they did; this entire post appears, to me, to be clearly phrased and structured as to *not* be an attack. Why go to this trouble of being so civil and in-depth if their purpose was just to attack a one-off user? [They've already admitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-to-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment826587_405478) that their motive was to avoid retaliation in a tag that they're active in, which seems very justified to me.

Comment: @zcoop98 haven't you seen the UK parliament? They have a rule about civility, yet they can also say that "[t]he intellectual power of the president is protozoan". Respect on the other hand, wouldn't allow anyone to say that, if it wasn't true. That's why some people reject courtesy and civility, because they perceive those that use them as fake and dishonest.

Comment: Just a note on the all sign posts are good thing. Sign posts are good, until you have 1000s of the linked by dubious titles pointing every which way, then they become noise and worse than useless. Just saying

Comment: @00110001 Absolutely. See *Of course, if a question has been asked many times already...* Some of the questions that get deleted are in this category, and cleaning up the site by removing such redundant questions is just fine and should happen more.

Comment: @cs95 every time I see people using [reductio ad toxicum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Hitlerum) I have a feeling that it covers an attack with some utterior hidden motive - typically when they have no ground to engage in productive discussion

Comment: @gnat my motive is openly out, and detailed in the OP - it isn't like Broccoli here is the only one who's noticed this pattern of destructive behavior or had their answers deleted because of it.

Comment: sure they're not the only one. Thorough cleanup of a tag like regex would naturally be noticed (and apparently perceived as painful) by many of those losing rep gained by [answering obvious duplicate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/839601). Although I wouldn't fall in same "toxicum" trap and blame them - because main reason for such a friction is apparent inability of the company to invest effort in this long known issue despite multiple complaints and proposals to improve things

Comment: I think it was pretty clearly laid out that not all closures here were open and shut - especially when language specific regex questions are closed as duplicates of generic regex question where the regex is not the only component of the answer. Sure there is a need for better tools but my point is overaggressive closure is not the answer to that problem, nor is our frustration to this knee jerk moderation unjustified. Thanks.

Comment: @zcoop98 The whole notion of "retaliation" is ridiculous, though. How does one "retaliate" against another Stack Overflow user? By downvoting their posts for no reason? By voting to undo their moderation actions? In such a case, the aggrieved party can do exactly what *should* have been done here - **raise a moderator flag to get it addressed**. This method is an egregious waste of everyone's time that has caused far more drama than necessary, and I have to wonder if that wasn't actually the point all along.

Comment: @IanKemp So.. meta users actively choosing to speculate on who the posting user is, is actually due to the poster causing drama? That sound a lot like "See what you made me do!" :D

Comment: @Scratte If you're going to argue that people aren't inherently going to speculate on the identity of someone choosing to explicitly conceal that identity, I'd going to argue that you need to take a course in the fundamentals of human psychology. This is a question about human behaviour, not about a block of code; knowing the "who" is important for understanding the "why", and that "why" is often as or more important than the topic presented.

Comment: @Scratte Then there's the fact that the "offender" wasn't explicitly named either, leading to people having to themselves figure out that person's identity. That's a waste of our time, full stop, and has potential negative ramifications if someone is wrongly identified (see: reddit and the Boston bomber for an extremely egregious example). Since the OP is already posting from a sockpuppet, there's zero need for them to avoid naming the "offender"; the only reasons I can think of for that obfuscation are negative ones.

Comment: @Scratte In short: the OP's intentions here may be pure as snow, but the fact that they've gone to such lengths to make something that should have been simple, incredibly convoluted, makes me (rightly or wrongly) suspect ulterior motives. It is, after all, far cleaner on the hands to incite a mob to be judge, jury and executioner than it is to do the dirty work yourself - especially if, as on the Internet, you can hide your identity so that there's no possibility of tracing the incitement back to you.

Comment: @IanKemp How about that the fact that no one was named, can make this post general enough to apply to any similar cases? Also, you're arguing that the poster should just name themselves *and* take the backlash *and* just live with it, because.. that would be easier on you. I'm going to guess they also carefully considered the pros and cons of doing it anonymous and I do not see why they should explain their reasons to you. If you think that "why" is more important than "what", then I don't agree at all. We should not judge a post on who posted it.

Comment: @Scratte How would naming names make a Meta question less general? The important thing is the **conclusion** that Meta arrives at through consensus, which sets a precedent for handling future incidents of the same type. And arriving at such a conclusion is made unnecessarily difficult by the lack of detail presented here.

Comment: @Scratte The OP doesn't have to do anything. But if they want this appeal to authority (because that's what it is) to succeed, they need to be credible. And choosing to obscure their identity **and** the identity of the person they believe is behaving badly, for no apparent reason, decreases their credibility in my eyes, at least.

Comment: Despite not liking the notion of blaming the OP for posting anonymously (this is a discussion on moderation patterns - I can't see how the poster's identity could help apart from inciting even more drama should they have a history of bad blood between them), I must admit that the anonymity of the poster and the "offending" user is not on the same level - despite not being named, it is *extremely* easy to figure out who the counterparty is from the abundance of examples provided.

Comment: Wiktor's behavior/reputation has actively dissuaded me from participating more in the regex tag, for fear of taking the time to research and write a good answer to a good question, only to have it closed/deleted out from under me. I mean, why bother?

Comment: "I highly recommend readders to, please read this meta post once. Should duplicates be deleted? In general, no: most duplicates stay around... " It seems the community is divided on that. Some try to delete duplicates, others not. It probably wouldn't hurt to try to reach a consensus which can then be controlled.

Comment: @Trilarion Exactly my thoughts. This seems to be the whole point of the post. Even Wiktor [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405495/8967612) that it would be "real added value" if the community reached a consensus on best practices for this matter. I'm not sure why some users see this post as an attack or as one with an agenda. I mean we've all seen "attacklike posts" before and they look nothing like this. I really appreciate the OP keeping a civil, non-aggressive tone throughout the post and I also appreciate Wiktor being open to feedback.

Comment: I admit that I (a fairly high rep user) am afraid to post questions in the `regex` tag.  My first question in that tag got attacked (and I deleted it).  I was a ~30K rep user at the time.  Since then I have felt that you needed to be really really sure you had an extra extra good and worthy question before posting one in the `regex` tag.  (Basically, if a tag could be considered "unfriendly", then that tag is.  If that level of caution and fear is what SO wants to foster on the `regex` tag (in the name of question quality) then it is all good.  If not, a bit more friendliness may be in order.

Comment: @Vaccano I don't think "friendliness" should factor into things at all. Remember, we're not a help forum. I'd prefer to measure whether a post is a net gain to have on the site or not - a test that many of the deleted posts pass, IMO. Extreme caution **[is good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/261593/1)** - albeit it should not be overpowering.

Comment: @Vaccano " If not, a bit more friendliness may be in order. " Friendliness is always a good idea, but in this case we simply should make up or mind if deleting duplicate targets is a good or bad idea and then act accordingly.

Comment: @Vaccano Your question did not get "attacked", it was analyzed and was found wanting. That is curation, not an attack, and the fact that you are apparently unable to distinguish between the two suggests to me that you don't understand question quality and/or the need to keep it high.

Comment: @Broccoli Same 3 persons deleted another one today as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66211686/grep-a-string-with-multiple-slash-keys/66211701#66211701)

Comment: Using the meta effect to try and get actions taken that you deem appropriate is no better than the three users allegedly coordinating to take actions they deem appropriate

Comment: @zcoop98 If done in an open-minded way, sure. We don't know the specifics of how these three users are interacting or if they're interacting at all. That's what we have mods for. We have a tag that questions can be tagged with for discussing specific questions.

Comment: @Kevin That's fair; the motives of the curators in question shouldn't be judged any more positively or negatively than OP's in this case... I guess my impression is that this post *is* open-minded, or at the very least civil.

Comment: like, i definitely understand the frustration here, but it's just not something that we the community have the tools to deal with fairly. The most productive thing we can do is bring up individual questions and discuss each specific case; if we think users are abusing their privileges', that's outside the realm of the tools we have (other than raising a flag)

Comment: I think if we took a few of these cases out and individually explored them, we could come to a more... agreeable outcome, understanding why someone felt it should be deleted, looking through all the existing sign posts to see whether or not the keywords in question were already covered, etc, and potentially learn something from it that we can then use as a reference... rather than just listing dozens of deleted questions and letting the cards fall where they do. I personally have no interest in the regex tag, so... not something I would lead

Comment: @KevinB Because the post isn't about a single post or several ones. It's about what to do when a user is deleting (and closing) a lot of post that maybe shouldn't have been deleted. Bringing up single posts will never address that. Nothing really ever changes from those meta posts, expect for that one post on main.

Comment: At least one of those users have shown interest in discussing the issue, it's not like we're dealing with people who aren't open to disucssion/change

Comment: I love SO and it has helped me so many times.  It is nearly always my first resource to go to.  But _not_ for regex.  Why?  Because there's about a jillion _good_ regex resources on the net with language-by-language comparisons, details of obscure features, and, best of all, online visualizations of regex behavior.  That's why I'm somewhat bemused at this particular meta question pointing out this particular behavior on this particular tag.  Of all possible subjects to help people with on SO, some which get very little attention: why put your effort into regex?

Comment: @davidbak Well... it's an easy way to farm reputation points for one. Regular expressions falls in the category of SQL, CSS and other related tags which are "code but not actually code" topics. The problems people have are so defined by context that they're hard to dupe close, so it's rather easy to answer the same questions over and over again by adjusting to the situational differences. If you're good at it and can answer fast, it's lucrative.

Comment: @Gimby Does that mean that gold hammers in those tags got their hammers by answering almost duplicates fast? And in such case isn't it a little strange they're closing the same type of posts that they've answered to get the hammer? Should some tags be exempt from the dupe hammer feature?

Comment: @Scratte I'm going to repeat myself: Assume the best when you can't prove the worst :) I don't endorse rep farming, just stating that those kind of tags don't exactly make it hard to do by their very nature.

Comment: @anubhava "Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege." Please, complete your quote.

Comment: @davidbak it's literally the lowest common denominator. You can answer nothing but regex questions and get easily +40k reputation.

Comment: @Trilarion that's because the commenter left out the other paragraph. See my comment above or follow the link and search for the title "Should duplicates be deleted?". If I were cynic I would say that it was deliberate.

Comment: @Broccoli If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66438257/change-the-position-of-string-within-a-larger-string-in-r) was answered by anybody else, it would have been deleted.  This was answered today.  I am very disappointed that SO doesn't take any action when the evidence is so big.

Comment: @Wiktor and Oguz and others . The deletion you are carrying out in the pretext(As it appears to be) of eliminating duplicates is a slap in the face to those who devote their time and energy for offering solutions. Be thankful to the generations of people who wrote/developed 'regex' and still contributing to it. I am sure we all have benefited from what Opensource tools have offered to us and all I can say is give respect to earn respect.

Comment: @ronythomas You do realize that blindly offering the solution to the same problem the n'th time is a slap in the face to those investing their time *curating* all these solutions? That at some point one must be greatful to the people *maintaining* what is there instead of steadily adding to the pile? I am sure we all have benefited from well curated content, and all I can say is don't paint such a black-and-white picture.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There's absolutely nothing wrong with deleting common duplicates. Those **should be** deleted. The problem is with deleting questions with good answers that aren't duplicates, or questions with good answers that are duplicates of *very rare* older questions without many votes or linked questions. Check out the links in the post again. I don't believe any of them fall under "common duplicate."

Comment: @Broccoli The problem is with this entire discussion being set up to be about persons, and not about actions.

Comment: @Broccoli Do I disagree that these examples are bad actions? Not at all. But I disagree that they should be used for finger pointing. I disagree that they should be used to allege dishonesty or acting with pretext. I disagree that we should be thankful for people keeping the regex tag a regex-writing-service.

Comment: @ronythomas He is doing the same deletion stuff again and again.

Comment: It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66532250/10819573) has been just saved narrowly from being deleted.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It does seem like a valid duplicate though. Doesn't the second most upvoted answer from that duplicate answer that question?

Comment: That example is particularly tricky, @ArvindKumarAvinash. The suggested duplicate _does_ mention in prose that the string may have delimiting forward slashes around the expression (quoting: _"If I say that they don't need to have //'s around the regex they enter, then they can't set flags, like g and i. So they have to have the //'s around the expression"_). However, and oddly enough, the accepted answer (and most voted!) does not address this, whereas the second most voted one does. Frankly, this would call for a problem more serious than that of deleting the Nth duplicate.

Comment: I wonder if it's occurred to people doing this, that if they **deleted fewer questions/dupes**, then there might actually be **fewer new questions** re-asking the same thing - since the existing one's one show up in search results, including the dupes they link to. So many of the examples aren't "basic" but will definitely get re-asked since they've been deleted. If everyone could understand everything in TFM then there'd be no need for StackOverflow :-/

Comment: @aneroid this argument hinges on all duplicates being both 1. unique 2. good. Whereas in my experience, a lot of regex questions are neither. I don't even want to count how many are "how do I match digits" or "how do I match the entire string". We probably get one a day on average of those. If you think they all provide value, then I point you again at the rate we're getting them. Unless maybe there is some critical mass we can achieve that will make new questions like that show up less.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Just to be clear: You say the duplicate does not solve the issue because one has to pad it with problem-specific, constant characters?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I assure you I have no interest in any "cause", be it with or against some anthropomorphic cabbage. I find it outright *absurd* what kind of content is being defended here. As far as I can tell, either this is a clear duplicate because the *problem* is being solved, or it clearly needs focus because it is about at least 4 problems at once, going by your list.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash *Every* "needs focus" question is about solving <N> problems with a single <code pattern>. The code pattern being written in regex does not change that.

Comment: I promise to vote to delete closed pages MUCH LESS if/when other users agree to close closable questions instead of answering them.

Comment: Wow... I thought it was "just me", then I find this (and similar) threads. Why are we dancing around the topic - **we know who are the two/three people responsible**. This doesn't happen in other tags I'm familiar with (I use many), just [regex]. Are there different rules for regex to the rest of SO? If yes, it should be spun off as a separate site; if no, there should the same "general" standard. The regex tag is no longer helpful, just frustrating because some guys use it as an advertising space for their consulting services, and to do so, they need to shape it according to their needs.

Comment: And, I think we all know who is @Broccoli. I feel very sorry for him because he does brilliant thankless work - he's one of the only ones keeping [regex] alive. Thank you Broccoli.

Answer (score 83):

I agree that questions that are duplicates should be closed.  But, I find a disturbing pattern when somebody closes a dupe with a more general dupe and even not the correct tag i.e. suppose a person asks a question primarily in `R` tag with a `regex` on it, an the person who closes the question on a `regex` only tag, it may not be that helpful.  I find multiple posts that I answered getting dupe tagged and then deleted with this way of closing.  More disturbing attitude is when I find a similar question answered by the same person (may be next day or couple of days later).  His prior actions suggest that he considers those questions not to be worthy for SO.  When I dupe tagged the question, immediately he reopened it.  It explains that the OP's concern is not really about cleaning the SO from those kind of questions.  I am sure that moderators would take notice of that.

NOTE: I could provide many links to that, but then the identity of the person who does this will be revealed and I don't want to do that.

#### Update

After 8 months (Oct 15 2021)

1. Is there any changes in the behavior?

   None
2. Is the group still involved in deleting questions when others answer and then reopen when they themselves answer?

   Very much. I was surprised to see a dupe question getting reopened by the same group.  They act as a group and there are [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69538963/revisions) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411495/i-want-to-get-rid-of-words-with-exact-pattern-in-character-vector-using-regular/69411506#69411506) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68785820/splitting-column-data-into-two-variables-using-regex-in-r/68786366#68786366)
3. Is it okay to answer in `regex` tag without their approval?

   No.  Because I find in many occasions even in the last couple of days, the same guys closing questions that are not remotely dupes as dupes while gleefully answering dupe questions.

Comment: The links in the question already identify a person pretty clearly. Don't see the point in beating around the bush.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You are right.  I didn't look at the links earlier.  Anyway, I would say that one of the person in the link did deleted at least 20 or more questions answered by me in the past few month or so.

Comment: I completely agree with these observations. So many of my answers have been removed recently by same 2-3 users. Really astonishing to see so much (mis)use of the privileges. I am starting to wonder if we are still a collaborative platform or a custodian society.

Comment: @anubhava I noticed that after a question (you also answered that) got reopened, we both got downvoted.  I was thinking that we need approval from him to answer any questions whatsoever

Comment: eh, that's likely just the meta effect. There's not much good to come from blindly applying blame.

Comment: @akrun, Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this one. Here is one more observation, if questions are reopened we may get or may not get downvote is one thing, but another part is many times specific tag removal will also happen(as a bonus) too, even tag is very much relevant for question, I am not sure OP has shared those examples or not but it wouldn't be difficult to find those examples too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, I have noticed that, [mentioned it here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-to-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate#comment826588_405478), but users are free to spend their *normal* votes as they like, even if it's for reasons others would consider questionable. More productive to focus just on the deletions and closures here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I modified tags only when somebody asks a question in python and have R tag unknowingly.

Comment: @Broccoli It would be great if he practise what he preaches.  But, unfortunately, I didn't see it that way

Comment: @KevinB Predictable downvotes on answers on reopened questions has been happening for ages before this question was posted; what they've experienced is not the meta effect. But it's a distraction, I believe normal votes are too subjective to be worth discussing here.

Comment: To your point about tags, it's interesting that the user in this case has a gold badge in *several* top-level language tags that they probably are not an expert in just because the [regex] tag was used and they are an expert in that one. JS, Python, C#, Java, PHP, and R... that's quite the feat if someone is a SME in each of those at the same time. Some have a lot of overlap, others... not so much. Answers not about regex in C#: 37. Same for JS: 23. PHP: 122. Python: 76. Java: 28. The user wouldn't have a gold badge in any of them without [regex], or even a silver in all but one of them.

Comment: @TylerH It is easier get gold badge in any of the top languages (without actually knowing the language) if one is proficient in `regex` because the `regex` code is almost similar except some escape characters

Comment: @akrun Yep, that is an unfortunate flaw in the current tag system. Especially considering one can ask a question only tagged as [tag:regex].

Comment: @TylerH One cannot ask a Question only in regex. The excerpt says " Because regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool." Not adding a language tag often gets the Question closed.

Comment: @TylerH which is why I am very conservative with using tags just because it's related, but not relevant.

Comment: @Scratte Guidance states they *should*, not they *must*. And the system allows it. You even said yourself just now that not adding a language tag "often" gets the question closed (as opposed to "always"). The highest-scoring question on the site (a target for many of the dupes mentioned here) in [tag:regex] has no other tags, for example.

Comment: @TylerH Sometimes curators miss a post. I said "often" because if I said "always" someone would find one that isn't closed. I've been told in SOCVR that not having a language tag is a reason to close a regex post. If you mean the RTFM canonical that includes all languages and their particulars, obviously there's not enough tags to cover that, so it only has the regex tag.

Comment: @Scratte So... you *do* agree it's OK to have questions with only the [regex] tag? Got it :-)

Comment: @TylerH I think you **deliberately misunderstood** what I was saying. But what do you suggest for posts that only has the regex tag? They mention all the things that are OK and all the things that are not OK for a solution? How is that any better than adding a language tag? Usually people don't even know what the engine they use can even do.

Comment: so... an accusation of... i dunno, potentially a double standard? or... maybe you not understanding the nuance of the difference between one case and the other, and an accusation of revenge voting? but no posts, so all we can do is take your word for it

Comment: @KevinB Just from yesterday and today, links are [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143042/how-to-remove-useless-characters-in-r/66143218#66143218), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214373/remove-duplicated-substrings-in-r/66214443#66214443), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163504/determine-repeating-numbers-in-a-string-in-r/66163531#66163531)   There are many, but since you requested, I showed some

Comment: @akrun Looks like the system worked

Comment: I mean... you're reopening questions you answered, there's nothing odd there.

Comment: @KevinB Because he tagged it to generic, non-specific dupe.  It may get deleted if I don't reopen it while he answers the same questions and reopen more specific dupe tag

Comment: If people would just use the tools made available to them more often and more consistently this whole issue could be avoided. If you find a users actions problematic, as you clearly do here, raise a flag. If you find a post that you think es sun correctly closed, open it. If you find an incorrect answer, downvote it. None of this is new, we have tools to deal with it

Comment: @Scratte No, it sounds like you're stuck in another situation of artificial/self-imposed constraints. The system lets you do something, and there are multiple examples of good questions that follow that practice. But yes, to answer your question, *every question* should mention enough information to answer it... that's not unique to [regex] questions.

Comment: @KevinB So first you doubt that retaliation downvoting happens. And after counter-evidence is provided you pivot to “yes but there’s nothing wrong with that”? It would be more convincing if you stuck to one argument. At any rate, none of the examples provided by akrun are actually incorrect (or low-quality) answers. It’s very hard to argue that they deserve downvoting.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/11682469)

Comment: @konradrudolph haha no, if anyone knows counter downvoting happens it would be me. I never said it doesn’t and wouldn’t say that. What I do know is that it wasn’t the user in question.

Comment: Your latest edit makes a suggestion that I think should be discussed separately, because there's not really a good way to respond to your latest suggestion when it's part of an answer. You can link to this discussion post if you want.

Comment: @cigien I rolled back to earlier version

Comment: @cigien I am trying to minimize the issue.  I think by posting a different topic linked to this could again flare up somebody's ego (if it is there).

Comment: I understand that, and it's up to you whether you want to post another Meta about this topic or not. I just think your latest edit is substantive, and shouldn't really be part of a response. Also, as to causing offense to any particular user, it's not as if they won't notice just because you edited a relatively old Meta answer. These changes show up on the active page, where observant users will notice it anyway.

Comment: [Here's a recent prime example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71822237/8967612) of a question that is _wrongfully_ closed with an irrelevant dup-target, _and_ it has accumulated two delete votes already. (Disclaimer: I answered that question)

Comment: Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547581/parse-text-into-table-with-r/) that was bugging me for the sake of the asker. It wasn't a bad question but immediately got jumped on by the regex community. The only mistake the OP made was tagging it as regex in the first place. The reality is that it was an R question and if people don't understand the question and language well enough, then they should stay away.

Comment: Here we go again. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73031006) of a question wrongfully closed, then deleted. The OP is asking how to _force_ (i.e., induce) a timeout and the dupe target is about the general use of timeout to prevent deadlocks. You don't need to know regex to see how those are two different questions. And even if it were a duplicate, why delete it without a good reason? Same behavior repeated over and over: downvotes > closure > deletion. This really needs to stop!!

Comment: @akrun IMO - questions with answers should be deleted by the mods only. But the community thinks that is a wrong idea. So we need to live with it.

Answer (score 51):

Not really an answer to this question, but something I think may be worth looking into:

What bothers me a *lot* more about these examples is that a *significant* portion of the deleted questions all have the *same* 2nd user casting a delete vote.
That can't be a coincidence, and has got to be coordinated delete-voting.

Frankly, I find that more concerning than a single user delete-voting duplicates he sees over and over again.

Comment: I raised a flag about coordinated **undelete**-voting recently, it was declined with this message: *Given the number of undeleted posts on this site you can find any number of combinations of users that “collaborate” like that.*, so I guess coordinated delete/undelete voting is not an issue.

Comment: It certainly seems like just picking *some* cases where people voted together is meaningless unless contrasted against *all* cases where the two people voted. There is likely to be coincidental voting-together merely because people frequent the same tags or vote-queue at the same time.

Comment: Sure, there's likely to be _some_ overlap, but this seems more than a coincidence.

Comment: I guess the pool of people with delete voting rights that actually do cast delete votes is small enough to make it more likely that the same people cast delete votes on the same questions, they likely find them through a linked interest in a tag. Not saying there is no coordination going on, but it is that much harder to prove that it is not coincidence.

Comment: Coordinated or not, this is a good heuristic to detect probable bad moderation.

Comment: I totally agree with your observation.  I also find a pattern in the persons who deletes it.

Comment: This is the "separate issue" I didn't want to elaborate on. I think this is something to leave to the mods, and the mods alone.

Comment: I'm not so sure. In any tag, even popular ones you will often find a lot of the same few users closing/deleting stuff. Those of us who use such moderation powers are, what, like 0.001% of users on the site?

Comment: Coordinated voting (of any kind - up, down, close or delete) is a very slippery slope. As a regular in the SOCVR chatroom (note that the actions in this question don't seem to have any connection to that), I am aware of some serious moderator and staff concerns about such activities. SOCVR, thus, has very strict rules.

Comment: @AdrianMole Once I got suspended for deleting my answer (even with 3 upvotes) and later answered as a new post.  The moderator explanation was that I should have known then SO guidelines.

Comment: Both users that are deleting posts have high scores in regex tag. If you are following some tag then it is not unusual that same people make same (similar) actions on multiple questions. I don't think that fact alone is cause for concern.

Comment: There are plenty of tags where only two or three >20K users are actively curating the tag. It's not unusual at all to have most tags be deleted (or undeleted) by the same two or three users. Even if one is always first, that might be because they are more actively following the tag than the other. I might look guilty of this too.

Comment: @akrun The disciplined badge seems risky to get...

Comment: @Cerbrus Coincidence? The closing and deletion by the same 2 users (and most of the times the same third) is still happening. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68241560/how-can-i-use-regex-to-match-an-unfinished-word 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191656/how-to-remove-file-folder-path-from-string-using-regex 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246350/javascript-matching-function-applied-only-at-the-end-of-strings 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234331/regex-negative-lookahead-will-not-be-matched-if-its-preceded-by

Comment: @akrun And more closed and deleted by the same 2 users
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660851/replacing-mysq-datetime-format-hours-min-sec-by-date-in-a-string 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506473/i-need-a-regex-for-thousand-separator-that-dont-separate-after-decimal 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894035/replace-a-string-containing-special-characters 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766433/regex-to-match-a-word-unless-its-a-full-string

Comment: @Thefourthbird what to do. Two days back, they did the same on one of the answers.  When it got reopened, the answer was downvoted and I see the delete vote again.  Also, I find that person even making a huge issue if somebody else answers on `regex` tag i.e. he at once removes the regex tag (even if it is written regex wanted) while I don't see him removing regex on questions answered by him.  Anyway, it seems that we need to get his approval for posting on regex questions.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I casted my undelete vote on those links. There will be some downvotes as a a reaction :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird here is the one I mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68776525/revisions

Comment: @akrun Ow yes I see, they are very determined to get you off the board. Thanks for doing so, we will see what happens with the votes. I just wanted to point out that in my opinion there seems to be more happening than just coincidence.

Comment: @Thefourthbird the fact is that I generally don't chase looking for regex questions.  It is just that one or two questions are asked in `R` that also includes regex and if I know a solution I answer.   This kind of aggressive behavior is the likely cause of many reopen/delete wars and subsequent hatred/toxicity towards each other.

Comment: @Thefourthbird you have cited 8 cases over a period of what appears to be three months. I am 100% sure that one could find equally many (actually more) cases of me voting "with" someone else over that period, even though I've never exchanged a single word with them. What exactly do you feel warrants calling out such behavior?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi These are deleted questions by the same users in the period after when this post was created, pointing out that this still happens.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That *what* still happens? Please don't beat around the bush, if you have something to say about behavior that I am sure would match many if not most curators, I would really like to read it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It is in the first comment, `The closing and deletion by the same 2 users (and most of the times the same third) is still happening.` and is related to this posted answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I do that too. Many others do that too. Why is it worth calling out? "Some 2 people active at the same time have similar vote opinion" seems hardly surprising. *What* about this are you calling out?

Answer (score 34):

I often cast close and delete votes on regex questions (and answers) to keep the regex SO tag part clean, avoid having to re-type the same solutions time and again (sometimes several times a day) and easy to search for the regex solutions online without the need to go through several dupes before coming across the original solution.

Personally, I believe **deleting every duplicated post is bad**, and I never do that. Let me try to clear up my "moderating system" that is based on a single principle: ***I am only doing what others have been doing***, certainly paying more attention to what others have been doing to my posts, since it is just more visible to me. I have been collecting the SO behavior patterns since 2015 when I started my active SO life (my profile says "Visited 2231 days, 2222 consecutive").

**What posts do I close?**

- Regex explanation requests and any post where OP is confused with truly *basic* regex patterns (for the majority of them, there are even specific signposts dealing with that exact issue)
- <s>All questions with no shown attempt, with no efforts shown, where the answer is "use *feature_name*" (and that are usually answered in a "here-you-are" style) with a generic duplicate close reason (these include word boundary usage of several kinds) that is enough to solve the issue, usually leaving a comment with tips on how to proceed with asking. I agree I do not give the exact solution here, but the linked threads are fair source of knowledge OPs need to answer their questions</s> March 13, 2021 update: as this behavior [can lead to suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate/405495#comment827339_405495), I have fallen back to the practice described in [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285739/3832970) and I vote to close an "Needs More Focus"
- Questions about some very common, extremely frequent regex topic, where OP might even share some basic efforts, but the real solution is in most cases already present or there are posts that can be easily adapted to OP needs (mostly questions about phone number, number, email validation and suchlike), though some are still valid on-topic questions
- Any post that has canonical dupe reasons (using variables in JavaScript, etc. regex, doubling backslashes inside string literals, using full string matching vs. partial string matching, etc.)
- Certainly, exact duplicates (that I can find within a single Web search and two result pages).

**What kind of closed duplicate posts are worth downvote?**

Not all of them deserve downvotes. I used to downvote posts I closed automatically some time ago, but I stopped because I realized users should have a chance to show they are eager learners. However, I do downvote when

- The duplicate is too frequent, and thus, "evident" (a basic search would have solved the issue and there would be no need to write an SO question)
- The duplicate was basically about a typo, or "bordering on" a typo (again, OP could have solved it with a tiny bit of extra attention)
- OP does not even try the solutions provided in comments (I often post the solutions), or/and behaves in an "emotional" way

**Deleting a post is necessary when**

- The post is misleading: when the answer is not actually the right solution even if it is accepted, almost all typo questions when there is no real problem, etc.
- The post is a duplicate of a very frequent and evident regex issue (some dupe reasons contain a hundred and more linked duplicates, and there is no risk losing value for SO when removing them), including number, phone, email, URL validation questions and the like
- The post owner did not put effort into solving the issue, or if that effort was truly insuffucient and was meant to disguise a pure code request.

**When not to delete and even upvote duplicates?**

- I *never* delete highly upvoted duplicates with long history, and even cast reopen votes in case I come across them
- When the question is related to a non-evident issue and the question is asked in a nice way, with code examples, test cases and explanation of OP efforts
- When the question is actually a duplicate of two SO threads (usually, they are still about very frequent issues, but the fact two links are required makes the current question a nice-have)

Note I use the terms "evident" to describe a simple and frequent issue with broad SO coverage, and do not mean that something should have been clear to OP prior to asking a question.

Now, it must be easy to understand the reason behind those closures/deletes listed in the question. This is not done to make anyone feel frustrated. If you think the duplicate question is unrelated, I assure you there was a reason. If you disagree, let me (or a person who closed the question) know via a comment, and if you have a point, the post will be reopened. If an answer is unique and is valuable, it is great, but what would you say to the identical XX valuable answers? Removing one or two (no, not all the threads I close and cast delete vote to get actually removed) does not harm anyone and SO either. *In my opinion*, this is in line with the official help page you quoted.

By the way, it is not true that a close reason with few votes is not a good close reason: some answers with just one upvote are worth 100 votes, they are simply not visible to others due to various reasons (poor title, or vice versa, too good title that people usually do not even think of to search for).

I disagree that "power" users should not use gold badge to moderate the corresponding tags: that is the purpose of gold badges. More, there is *no problem* with hammer-closing: any three users with reopen votes will reopen the question. Believe me, if the question was closed by mistake, it happens within minutes.

Our colleagues who frequent the 10K tools page do a great job keeping this place clean. Again, they are just human beings who can make mistakes. We all do. So, there is an undelete tool there, too. Don't you think it can also be perceived as another "sink to use up their undelete votes"? In my opinion, this system works in the end. If there are any disputes, I rely on moderators' final say.

I agree "it is not a good thing there is no real oversight on what gets deleted". Still, there is a list of recently deleted and undeleted posts at least.

I am not sure what "deletion behavior" that's been "going on for many years" you mention, my deletion behavior has been the same all the time I obtained the privilege. It is also easy to "copy" my close/deletion pattern if you

1. want to keep my preferred tag as clean as possible
2. try to keep an eye on as many posts in this tag as possible (sometimes, just browsing a question after question).

I want to also note that I also care to delete the questions I answered that turn out evident duplicates, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396742/3832970), or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000605), for example.

Now, after I wrote all this, I come to think I am overthinking it a bit, and probably mislead others with my decisions. I admit I have been obsessed with "aggressive cleaning" approach, but that was done in good faith. If this thread clears up best practices that would be real added value to the community.

Comment: Stack Overflow has always been a free coding service. Most posts contain code and it's free. Also, only curators care for Question author effort. No one else does. Not people trying to find a solution to a similar problem. Not people actually answering the posts.

Comment: I really appreciate your willingness to discuss things. Discussion and consensus is good. You say *it is not true that a close reason with few votes is not a good close reason... they are simply not visible to others due to various reasons* This is exactly what having a few visible linked questions will help with; deleting otherwise reasonable duplicates will result in the good target being *harder* to find. Dupe closing such questions is great, to link them together. But attempting to delete them afterwards, as is done, sounds like it defeats the purpose..?

Comment: It's only useful to keep them... if it's a unique sign post.

Comment: I suppose that the "free coding service" comment above is satirical, but surely the whole point of the curators is that answerers will leave the site if the question quality keeps decreasing. (it's not always but usually true that effort ~== quality) And the user-in-question if I recalled correctly answers a lot of regex questions too.

Comment: Your system sounds very much like my system. We don't need to keep everything, because sheer amount of similar questions and answers makes it almost impossible to find good answers on your own without asking new question.

Comment: Awesome write up and great moderation in a popular tag. There is one thing I ask you to reconsider or clarify and that is this reason in the when to downvote paragraph: *OP does not even try the solutions provided in comments (I often post the solutions), or/and behaves in an "emotional" way*. That reads to me that you vote based on the user, specially to send them a signal. I honestly believe downvotes are not meant for that. Can you elaborate a bit how the OP influences your moderation decisions? My stance is that it shouldn't influence your moderation.

Comment: Given the questions in the regex tag, it seems hard *not* to moderate (most of) them based on the OP. "solve my niche problem" *is* inherently about the OP, and very many regex questions are asked in such a way that there is 0 potential to match a more general problem.

Comment: @Scratte: People considering whether to spend their time writing an answer often do care about question-author effort when the question is relatively simple / basic / boring.  If it's an interesting question that's worth having an answer to, I *might* write up an answer even if the author hasn't shown much effort, if I know it's not trivially answered.  But for homework copy/pastes and similar garbage, most people skip answering or only give a hint in comments.  (At least in lower-traffic tags like [assembly]). If we answered every no-effort question, the floodgates would be open even wider.

Comment: @Wiktor: Can you clarify which parts of *Deleting a post is necessary when* applies to answers?  Are you recommending downvoting / deleting correct answers to questions that should have been (and later are) closed as duplicates, or only ever to deleting the whole question?

Comment: @Wiktor: you argue that deletion can be undone with undelete votes.  That's true, but it's *much* rarer because deleted questions don't turn up in searches as easily.  IDK how long they stick around for Google (which is what I usually use to find duplicates), but I rarely hit deleted questions when looking for dupes.  (Of course, in tags I frequent, deletion of questions with any answers is pretty rare.)  I don't think "someone will undelete" is a strong enough argument in favour of deleting unless you're pretty sure.  True you don't have to be totally certain, it is reversible, though.

Comment: "*OP does not even try the solutions provided in comments (I often post the solutions), or/and behaves in an "emotional" way*" **Do not vote based on OP's actions!** Voting is about the content not the person who authored the post. OP's actions are irrelevant in judging the usefulness of the post!

Comment: @Dharman OPs actions are relevant in the context of comments. If several comments are made (which request clarification), but they're not answered and met with hostility, a post that otherwise could be improved can't be clarified and that's a reason I tend to downvote posts too. Comments on main are meant to improve or clarify the post, you could argue that if comments were needed you should've downvoted immediately, but I tend to wait a bit for a response and don't downvote if the response is satisfactory.

Comment: @Dharman You have taken Wiktor's statement out of the context. "Not all of them deserve downvotes. I used to downvote posts I closed automatically some time ago, but I stopped because I realized users should have a chance to show they are eager learners. However, I do downvote when..." This paragraph clearly implies that downvoted posts are actually worthy of the downvote. That is not downvoting based solely on user's actions.

Comment: @rene [Reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) is a rough measure of: *"community trusts you; communication skills; quality and relevancy of your questions and answers"*. An extremely rude and offensive OP at best fulfills 1 in 3 reputation criteria. The votes equate to reputation not content alone.

Comment: @rene I would like to add to that I see (and have experienced personally) answers to such questions being downvoted without fail. Almost every answer to these questions is given a downvote before the question is deleted. Regardless of whether the answer is right or wrong. This indicates the user is in the habit of "punishing" users for answering questions they deem to be duplicates and not necessary for the site. Obviously we cannot tell people how to vote, but do you think voting on answers based on the merits of the *question* makes sense to you?

Comment: Wiktor, you have my support. The real problem are not those who close/delete questions, but those who don't do research before posting. But I feel that any attempt to keep one tag clean is a uphill if not loosing battle. It is one person against everyone else: against OP, against all those who come from other tags (e.g. from c# or javascript) and genuinely think the question is new, against those who know the question isn't new, but want to make easy points, against those who want to make noise on meta, even against general policy of quantity and not quality

Comment: @ASh Did you *look* at the many examples of invalid close votes that the OP provided? I appreciate Wiktor’s work at cleaning up. It’s thankless work, and it’s a lot of work (like you say, it’s an uphill battle). But that does not excuse lack of care, and many of the close votes really *are* completely inappropriate. This isn’t a rare occurrence, it’s unfortunately frequent.

Comment: @cs95 if you consider the question not having value I can imagine that the answers have no value and as such warrant a down vote. A downvote on an answer might make a question eligible for the roomba.

Comment: @cs95 "This indicates the user is in the habit of "punishing" users for answering questions they deem to be duplicates and not necessary for the site." Voting is anonymous and you're not a moderator, hence you have no idea **who** is downvoting those answers, so your accusation is based on an assumption that you cannot prove. Be very careful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You disagreeing with a vote doesn't make the vote invalid

Comment: @KevinB *My* disagreement is neither here nor there. There are *rules* for close votes, and the examples listed in the question blatantly violate these rules, even under a generous interpretation. This isn’t even remotely subjective.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In what way exactly? How can you prove, behind a reasonable doubt, that no one could possibly ever under any circumstance consider the given questions/answers duplicates, or unclear or not useful and worthy of downvotes? (we already have evidence of the contrary)

Comment: @KevinB I can’t prove it “behind a reasonable doubt”, but I absolutely don’t need to, because that would be a ludicrously and lopsided standard of evidence. In reality, there is clearly a very broad agreement amongst the commenters and voters here, and that’s really all that matters.

Comment: Calling this meta discussion "community consensus" seems to be stretching things a bit. There are lots of red flags about this discussion; that it seems to attract rather one-sided opinions hardly means the bulk of the community shares these opinions – nor that it does not, mind.

Comment: Using your gold-tag dupe-hammer on *"All questions with no shown attempt, with no efforts shown, ..."* is a *very dangerous* occupation (if, indeed, that's what you meant). This is paramount to abuse and could result in either: (a) your suspension; or (b) removal of the dupe-hammer privilege from the system completely. This has been discussed (in a different context) in SOCVR, and a moderator there suggested the (a) option would be one of their possible responses.

Comment: Using a "RTFM" target as a duplicate is both lazy (cast the *correct* close vote and allow two others to support your call) and just plain wrong.

Comment: It's funny that people say that there are rules for voting other than user targeting, when the creator of the site basically said that you are able to close questions if they are boring/uninteresting.

Comment: @Braiam The issue with that is that what you find uninteresting, I find interesting. It's a bad measure and a poor reason to close a post.

Comment: @Scratte well, use your votes however you like, leave others to do the same. Why is that concept so alien here?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I will provide feedback via updating the post when I finally "process" the reactions. It is clear to me I should have shared this "system" some year ago, it would have reduced the amount of negative emotions throughout the regex tag.

Comment: I have read two full tutorials. I've read the RTFM canonical. I'm going through the "Advanced Regex-Fu". I also found a joke-regex that finds the string "42". I understand it all except a small detail. But as you've written, any post that asks for an explanation is closed using the RTFM, which I already read. And there's no way to show effort on my own brain-activity on the matter. So now.. I'm asking people in chat instead. Do you honestly think this is good for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I never said it, but I just wanna thank you for reopening my question. If you didn't, I wouldn't be in SO years later. Just encouraging you to keep an eye also on reopen queue to find questions worth reopening or incorrectly closed by others. Cheers.

Comment: @TheMaster I do reopen posts I closed once the person who posts the question makes it either clear or unique/on-topic. There are few users who really care that is why this does not happen often.

Answer (score 24):

You know what, I have bigger problems with the other part, saying that two questions are duplicates when they aren't or are just related questions. For the deletion of duplicates... I really don't find most deletions as irremediably harmful, for a simple reason: even if this user tries to do that, it will be fighting against every asker of Stack Overflow, which is a tall order even with some coordination.

I'm not against deletion of most duplicates, as there's a practical limit of ways to ask useful signpost questions without running into irrelevant keywords due to humans failing to accurately describe what they are asking about. I prefer people finding relevant information due to using the correct set of keywords than a crapshoot where you find questions where someone described something that happened to use the same keywords, but in a different context.

For me, the first issue is far more important and preponderant than the latter, as in the latter would be a lost battle of attrition against the internet, which would sort itself out (aka without intervention of anyone). The other doesn't have this characteristic and as it's very difficult to convince others that two questions are actually not duplicates of one another.

Comment: Totally agree. Closing all questions that ask for a regex as RTFM doesn't sound great. Even worse when the question doesn't even ask for a regex but one of the possible solutions is "use a regex".

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen a "close as duplicate" that was actually a duplicate. I think the false cases greatly outweigh the true ones.

Comment: Why is it difficult to convince others that two questions are actually not duplicates of one another? I've found that some users are just hasty with their duplicate flags and they're not taking the time to read and understand the questions. It seems like it should be easy to have them actually read the questions they had just skimmed over previously, and then discover that they're not duplicates

Comment: @KyleDelaney because we fallen in the false premise that two questions are duplicate merely because one of the answers _potentially_ answers the other question. Which leads us to absurd situations where if the answer didn't exist then they are suddenly not duplicates (!?).

Comment: It's often hard to realize that your view on a particular matter might not be correct

Comment: @KevinB which view?

Comment: Any view, not any one particular one expressed here. Mostly a reply to Kyle. Simply telling a user who dupe closed a question that it isn't a dupe, isn't a very strong case for it being not a dupe. for example, your assertion that two questions aren't duplicates just because one's answer completely answers the other, isn't one that is held by everyone who participates here

Comment: @KevinB well, I'm not saying that mine is right, but at least doesn't lead to a ridiculous situations that I described. I reject that PoV, not just because of that, but allows other more ridiculous affirmations.

Comment: BTW @KyleDelaney , you might want to read the reply above mine.

Comment: I find (not in the regex tag, which I don't look at, but elsewhere) that questions are closed as dupes if the _answer_ is a dupe.  But I feel that's wrong and misleading, especially when you consider how people are _brought_ to SO via search engines:  They're typing in _questions_, not _answers_.  If they could have typed in an _answer_ they'd have no problem, would they?  So the _question_ needs to bring up a hit on SO.  I would go so far as to say that _many_ (much more than a few) "closed as dupe" that I've seen are like this.

Comment: @davidbak eh, i'm not so sure on that... but i'll admit my experience *looking* for answers isn't necessarily high. from my experience, the answers often have the keywords I'm searching for rather than the questions.

Comment: @KevinB - yes but I frequently see questions from people who don't know the proper search terms.  I usually just comment with the correct search terms in that case.  E.g. - you want to know how to take a generated file and modify it further before you compile it?  The proper search is "makefile chain rule" - not obvious to the person asking about how to "fix" generated code!  And thus, a question/answer about "makefile chain rule" is not likely to be found by him or someone with a similar problem. (I just answered - with a comment - that one yesterday.)

Comment: @davidbak If people fail to search their problems with the proper terms, dupe-closing their question to serve as a signpost to the proper answers seems to *exactly* match the purpose of duplicates.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I thought the issue we were talking about is going the extra step and _deleting_ duplicates?  At least, that's the original question.  This particular answer is a little different.  Still, this answerer says he prefers people to "use the correct set of keywords".  But my point is that this business of programming is so full of specific technical terms that frequently there's no way to know a priori the "correct set of keywords".

Comment: I should also add - I can nearly always find the correct set of keywords within five minutes of posing questions to a search engine and looking at snippets and refining.  A search process with a search engine.  But it is sadly totally obvious that the fast majority of SO questioners - initial questioners - never bother with a search engine and don't do that kind of research before asking their question here.  And that's apparently fine with the site, so I'm okay with it, but it means that they don't know and won't find out for themselves the "correct set of keywords".

Comment: @davidbak "use the correct set of keywords" is not to be taken as a standalone sentence. How many times have you found that someone that uses the phrase "know how to take a generated file and modify it further before you compile it" in any other context that makefiles? If you do, then those are not the proper keywords and need a qualifier, like "make" or "c" or something. The best target questions have one duplicate that uses these.

Answer (score 20):

<sub>**Disclaimer**: I'd rather not discuss the specific user, or their deletions. This answer's focus is on the rationale behind why a user may vote to delete questions after marking as a duplicate and what actions another user could do if they notice this behaviour.</sub>

---

I have to admit that I often also vote to delete a question after marking it as a duplicate.

My reason is that I never spend longer than 5 minutes searching for a duplicate and if I can find a duplicate within those 5 minutes then it *really* doesn't need another signpost. Instead, what often happens is users find a way to still post an answer to the already closed question and thus posting either rehashed information or posting an answer that should be added to the duplicate target.

> What to do when one person tries to delete every duplicate?

If you really want to, flag a post for moderator attention, leave a note explaining why it's flagged and then leave it at that so the moderator(s) can decide if anything further needs to be done.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your answer: While I don't disagree that a target being easy to find is a good indicator that the duplicate might be unnecessary, SMEs can often spot what the question is *actually* asking, and if they are familiar with the existing content, they might find a target very fast. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980954) is a very good example where the target was found in 2 minutes, but where the dupe is nonetheless an excellent signpost and should definitely not be deleted (see the comments). I'm sure you're aware of similar cases in tags you frequent.

Comment: @cigien - Absolutely, I definitely don't vote to delete every question closed as a duplicate, that is mainly reserved to those "My debug/log/terminal told me exactly what the error is, how do I solve it?" questions and other questions with a blaringly obvious duplicate

Comment: Yes, there's no doubt that many (most) duplicate closures should be deleted. However, you've answered a question which contains a long list of duplicate closures that arguably don't fall into this category (many of the closures are with targets that are not obvious, or are RTFM targets). Given that context, your answer seems a bit misplaced.

Comment: @cigien - Yes admittedly I was unsure if this should just be a comment and I didn't look into many of those examples because a singular users actions don't interest me and chose to focus on the OP's question whilst adding possible rationale why a user may seem to be deleting more than the average person

Comment: Ah, I see. That's fine, it's a reasonable answer; it just seems like you're directly addressing the OP's question. Perhaps you could begin the answer with something like, "I'd rather not discuss the specific user, or their deletions, but in general ...". That would convey what you're trying to say without it being confusing I think.

Comment: That a subject matter expert can find a duplicate in 5 minutes is not even close to being the reality for lots of users. I can find a solution in 5 minutes for lots of Questions. That doesn't mean they're simple or that it is easy. It's just easy for me.

Comment: @Scratte - Its a relative amount, 5 minutes in a subject where im a "subject expert" generally seems to equate to an hour or two of research at most where I'm not well versed . Yes there are lots of times when I can instantly find the solution by "cheating" and googling the exact duplicate the op is asking about but other than that for the most part I try to stick to only searching using words found in the OP's post and I *still* find a lot of duplicates. You'd be amazed at how many you can find by just using the question's title to search with

Answer (score -32):

You raise a custom flag, explaining the behaviour and the pattern.

If that flag gets declined, and you believe that doing so was incorrect, *then* you post a question on Meta.

---

To address the manner in which this question was posed:

You apparently felt strongly enough about this topic to make a Meta post about the behaviour of a particular Stack Overflow user, yet you aren't willing to put your name against that post or name that user. Why not? What benefit do you, or they, receive by having identities obscured? What benefit do Meta users obtain by being forced to follow breadcrumbs and draw inferences? What if people get lost and draw the wrong inferences? I'd expect a level of identity obfuscation if you were reporting on something truly egregious, but this isn't it.

The only way that a truly collaborative community like SO's curators can survive and thrive is by being as transparent as possible. That means you have to be willing to call people out for what you see as bad behaviour, and you yourself have to accept there's a possibility of being called out.

Yes, cultural norms or your personality or past reception on Meta might discourage you from calling someone out directly, but **as long as you are doing it from a place of honesty**, there is no reason to be afraid of directness. It would certainly have saved everyone involved a lot of time and effort in this case.

I personally have rubbed quite a few people on Meta up the wrong way, some of whom are moderators, and while I regret that - I do try to be civil with them, and certainly would have no issue being called out by them. Because I know that regardless of how I would feel, I am part of a community, and I trust that community to do right by its members - because as far as it's able, it always has.

Ultimately there's nothing wrong with what you've done, it just hinders our ability to determine what the issue is, which hinders our ability to discuss and form consensus on what, if anything, should be done. Time is a precious resource on Meta as much as SO itself.

Comment: Does the identity of the reporter have anything to do with the reported behavior? How would your answer differ if I, a moderator or some random newby on the site would have written the same post? In addition, you don't even try to answer the question in place. Flagging only makes sense when you *know* that the behavior is wrong, when you aren't sure if it is correct, you post on meta.

Comment: @BDL Of course it does, because the very first thing you need to do is review that user's actions to determine if they have indeed been performing the action that the post is asking about! If that hasn't been going on (and many times in Meta questions about specific users it actually hasn't), you can immediately discard the question.

Comment: The user you have to check is the **reported** user, not the **reporting** user. The reported behavior is baked by a ton of links to questions. Why would you need the real name of the meta post author for that? We could discuss if naming the reported user in the meta post is a good idea (imho, it's not), but why do we argue about the identity of the reporter?

Comment: @BDL Flagging is **always** the first step to take because the mods are responsible for enforcing the rules. If you flag and that flag is declined, it's highly likely (but not guaranteed) that your understanding/interpretation of the rules is incorrect, and as such a Meta question isn't required. But you are always able to raise the topic on Meta if indeed you believe the moderators were wrong or made a mistake.

Comment: @BDL My mistake - why does the identity of the reporter matter? Nominally it doesn't. But the fact that the reporter is in this case, obviously a high-rep user with high activity in the listed tags, who is purposefully obscuring their identity, makes one consider their motivation for raising this issue.

Comment: Given the latest problems with backlashes on the main site after posting meta questions, I also wouldn't post a potentially controversial question with my usual account. The author of this post certainly had enough of that. And then again, even if the author of the meta post would have a long going war against the reported user, would it make a difference as long as the meta post is written in an civil way?

Comment: I admit that the reason is selfish, I wish I didn't feel it necessary to avoid retaliation.

Comment: I am a regular contributor in the tag. Closure timestamps for questionable or uncommon duplicates are very frequently correlated with downvote timestamps on useful, correct answers. Yes, one shouldn't assume to know who is voting - but when you can see it happening not once, nor 10 times, but hundreds of times (not just for me, but for most top users in the tag), a picture starts to form. I do not want someone who visits every question who I believe downvotes answers at the drop of a hat to acquire an intrinsic bias against my posts when I post in the tag in the future.

Comment: It doesn't matter who is voting or why if there is no fraud involved. Every vote to delete can be later countered with an undelete. Every vote to close can later be countered with a reopen.

Comment: If they truly believe all these questions aren't useful, that's their opinion to have.

Comment: @KevinB That's not exactly right, unless you literally only mean *opinions*, which everyone is welcome to. If you're referring to the act of casting delete votes, then one's reasons *are* relevant, and users shouldn't really be casting those votes just because they feel like it. Especially when there is consistent pattern to the votes being cast, as outlined in this question, the reasons behind the votes matter a lot, and users should be willing to explain them. Perhaps they are casting those votes based on a misguided sense of which questions are actually useful, or not.

Comment: @cigien Are you saying they're casting these votes for reasons other than the reasons they chose to cast them with? How could you know? If they are misguided, that's certainly not malicious.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure what you mean. When delete votes are cast, there's no specific reason associated with them (as there are for close votes). Posts are deleted because they are not useful, and I'm suggesting that there might be a misunderstanding/disagreement over which posts are useful, or not. And I didn't say there was anything malicious going on. Frankly, I don't particularly care if there *was* malice or not; if there are issues with the voting pattern of a user, that should be addressed, regardless of how pure, or otherwise, their motives might be.

Comment: Oh, there's certainly disagreement over what posts are useful, that much is absolutely clear. Whose job is it to determine what is and isn't useful?

Comment: @KevinB It's *our* job, as a community, to figure out what is useful, and discussions are the only way to achieve that. Your comment "*If they truly believe all these questions aren't useful, that's their opinion to have.*" seems to me like you're suggesting that there's not much point in debating opinions if they are sincerely held. If I misunderstood that comment, I apologize. If I have understood the comment, then I don't think that's a productive way of addressing the problem (which is that there's disagreement).

Comment: Right, and that gets to my point. We, the community, have the tools to act here. we don't need to call these users out to use them. just use them. Where's the problem? We have moderators for dealing with problematic users, we don't need to debate on their opinions or actions. They earned the privilege to use the tools they are using just as we have.

Comment: @KevinB That's an interesting POV. So you think it's preferable for users to duke it out among themselves, instead of even *trying* to address the issue via a discussion? I'm not sure that's the ideal way for multiple curators to be spending their time or votes, i.e. basically undoing each other's work. Some of that is bound to happen, but it seems worthwhile to reduce that when possible. Regarding moderator action: there's nothing for a moderator to do unless there's a clear violation, which doesn't seem to be the case here; it's more a systematic pattern of voting that could be a problem.

Comment: I think it's more productive to discuss what is and isn't useful for a particular tag than examining the voting history of 1-2 users so that we can bring more awareness to curation as a whole, rather than singling out a few users who we disagree with.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, there may be multiple (and even more) productive ways of having the discussion. I'm only pointing out that is a perfectly reasonable way to do it. Note also that this question is very much about a particular tag. Also, while it is singling out a couple of users, it's worth mentioning that those few users are responsible for a vast majority of the deletions (and other forms of curation) in that tag, and it would be odd to not even consider that very relevant information.

Comment: That's precisely why we need to get more people involved.

Comment: There have been quite a few delete-undelete wars in the tag. Couple examples https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65949774/timeline https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65267099/timeline If you vote to undelete, others may simply vote to delete again later. Given the very large quantities of deleted questions that are involved, I don't think just continuing to leave the interactions as they are now is the right thing to do.

Comment: Which is why you modflag, @Broccoli, and leave it up to the moderators to figure it out and deal with.