# My question, which I was able to reopen myself after it was closed as a duplicate, is closed as a duplicate again, without context

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I've posted a question which was was closed as a duplicate.

Believing it not to be a duplicate, I voted to reopen, which *instantly reopened* the question, because I do have a gold [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag badge (I've answered enough questions and have a decent enough understanding of regular expressions, but I don't consider myself an expert).

Now, weeks later, the question ended up getting closed as a duplicate *again*, but without *providing additional information about who closed the question*:

> [image]

This makes me wonder:

- What prompted the *repeat* closure? What are the rules around re-closing a reopened question? What if two gold badge holders disagree?
- Why don't I see any information about *how that repeat closure came about*?

Comment: Question poster doesn't get to see who closed their question as protection against retribution. A gold badge holder in regex tag closed it

Comment: The question has been closed by two different user. Not that it matters, but regex is since some time a moderation Wild-West. No other tag produces that many meta questions and that many problems.

Comment: If you go to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66446285/timeline) you can see who closed/reopened any post. The question was hammered by different users each time, as must have been the case, since users are limited to one of each type of vote per post (not counting delete/undelete votes). It appears that 2 other users disagreed with your assessment; there's nothing special with regards to whether the users who disagree have gold tag badges or not.

Comment: Relevant answer that might give some insights to the why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405495/424903 . The regex tag is not just any other tag, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What prompted the repeat closure?

Other user or users believed the question was still a duplicate, despite your explanations. Disagreements happen, and sometimes users get it wrong.

> What are the rules around re-closing a reopened question?

The rules are that users should vote according to their individual judgement, and their good faith interpretation of the rules. If voting to close a reopened question was against the rules, the system wouldn't allow it. Same thing for reopening a question that was previously closed.

The fact that some users thought "a" doesn't mean you cannot think "b". Disagreements are resolved by votes.

> What if two gold badge holders disagree?

With the sad exception of [delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361933/348149), all other kinds of votes are limited to one vote per type per user per post which successfully changes the state of the post.<sup>1</sup> So if two gold badges disagree, each one gets a vote in each direction (closure, reopening), and then they need to wait for the rest of the community to sort it out (gold badgers or not).

> Why don't I see any information about *how that repeat closure came about*?

This is the result of changes to the post notices that [were published a couple of years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/348149). Since then, the list of the close voters is hidden from the question poster to make it less likely users will retaliate against close voters. In any case, the list of close voters can be accessed fairly easily, although I'd argue knowing *who* voted for what is not a particularly necessary feature in most cases.

---

<sub>1.⠀⠀A "successful" vote is one which causes a change in state for the post. Specifically, if you vote to close or reopen and the question is not closed or reopened as a result of that vote (i.e. your vote ages away), then you will be able to cast the same vote again 14 days after your vote aged away.</sub>