# MCVE vs SSCCE battle

Tags: discussion, help-center

Until some point in the past, most possibly connected with the implementation of a new help center and renewed close voting system, I had seen many examples of useful comments that asked OP to provide for a short, self contained and compilable example, usually followed by a link to [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/). After that point SSCCE usage seemed to vanish in favour of a minimal, complete and verifiable example, usually linking to [Stack Overflow help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The close reasons seemed to follow that trend. The initial reason

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

was changed to

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Though essentially the same things, but maybe with a slightly different flavours, SSCCE acronym is rarely used nowadays, but MCVE is endorsed and used from within the system. It might have appeared as a customized version of the original.

It would be interesting to hear your thoughts on the issue as to why has this shift happened. Was it a bad acronym? Or did [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) put a ™ sign on his SSCCE :) ? Or probably the stars were (mis)aligned for that change?

What do you think?

Comment: I'm disappointed. From the title of the question I assumed this would be something juicy and worthy of FOX News.

Comment: @J.Steen Sorry to disappoint you. Just tried to fill a gap in my understanding. In the meanwhile I think FOX news have something else to offer you ;)

Comment: I also don't agree with the current close-vote of "primarily opinion-based" - there are plenty of representatives of SO/SE on hand here to answer this question. Eventually.

Comment: @bluet However, the first part of the SSCCE acronym is "*Short (Small) - Minimise bandwidth for the example, do not bore the audience*". The new description text is better, I agree, but that doesn't specifically answer why the change of SSCCE to MCVE. =)

Comment: @bluet Probably, yes. More integrated and rather obviously officially endorsed.

Comment: @bluet Everybody who's active here has worked with questions that contain so much irrelevant noise (i.e. the whole CSS file applied to a JS-related question) that's plain copypasted. They are typically posted by newer users who don't bother about quality but do bother about getting their code corrected with minimal efforts from thier side. Still, Minimal ≈ Short, Complete ≈ Self contained and Verifiable ≈ Compilable. True, information contained in help center is more readable that the off-site resource, but was it the sole reason for a rewrite?

Comment: @skuntsel: I'd wager that's the sole reason, yes.

Comment: MVCE is a [special edition written by author of SSCCE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258849/839601) for Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat But where in the linked duplicate Q&A can you find an explanation for a shift from one acronym to another?

Comment: @skuntsel: because there are several possible acronyms here? Another that is used often is MWE. In any case, Andrew Thompson is the *original author of SSCCE.org*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've read Andrew Thompson's page before posting so I knew that. It's a good thing that he's collaborated in writing our version which is more perceivable to the audience. As to the acronym, I really wondered why the community suddenly dropped the original one and switched to a newer version. It could turn out to be good to have one here at SO. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Short, self contained, compilable ... well, what about technologies that don't actually "compile" at all?  : )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting the [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow)

> ### A note on SSCCE
>
> One of the reoccurring complaints with the old off-topic reasons was the reference to http://sscce.org/. While a very nicely-written and information-rich resource, **it wasn't specific to Stack Overflow and the wording of the close reason subtly implied that including such code was a requirement for asking a question, which was never the intent of the page's author**. As a result, both of the new off-topic reasons reference [a Stack Overflow-specific help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and attempt to cast it as a useful resource for helping others reproduce your problem and not a laundry-list of additional hard requirements.

(*bold emphasis mine*)

So the original page wasn't specific enough, and a custom version was written for Stack Overflow. The [original author of SSCCE .org, Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) wrote a much more concise draft for the help center and came up with the new acronym. See [Can we create a Help Center topic that outlines what a SSCCE / MWE means for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta), the help center version has a few more tweaks.

Comment: @gnat: ah, it says so on his profile; couldn't find that on SSCCE.org

Comment: yeah, "Author of the SSCCE and wrote the initial draft of the (much shorter) MCVE document here at SO..."

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much sums it up.  :)