# How to choose from many good answers added at the same time?

Tags: discussion, answers

I asked a question that turned out to be very simple to answer and I got 5 good answers almost instantaneously. Which one should I accept if all of them solve my problem?

[Positioning of an arrow in an HTML select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788848/positioning-of-an-arrow-in-an-html-select/38788990#38788990)

Comment: Please be patient - you can't even accept the answer yet, and people might edit their answers, for example to provide a more generic answer.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers).

Comment: A three-sided die?

Comment: I personally go by (in order of preference): 1. The answer which had the full solution, which I copy-pasted; 2. The answer which had the full solution, which I used; 3. The answer which had almost the entire solution, and is best-formatted; and finally 4. The answer which was closest to the actual solution. In your situation, I would accept whichever of the answers you actually copy-pasted from, since it looks like a copy-paste situation.

Comment: If the answers are equally good, and if you're sure no answer is a copy of another, I would choose the answer of the user with the lowest rep.

Comment: If worst comes to worst you can look at the timestamp.

Comment: Keep in mind the answer is not just for you, and not just for solving your problem. I think the best answer is the one that does the best job of explaining _why_ it works, so that future viewers can truly learn from it. Other people who see it later may have similar problems, but not exactly the same one.

Comment: In any case: *wait*. There's no rush to accept an answer. Just way a day or two to see if the answers receive some edits or new (and possibly better) answers come along.

Comment: I'm sort of hoping that you'll get many good answers here as well. Then you can ask on meta-meta StackOverflow what to do when you get several good answers on meta StackOverflow, and so on, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two criteria are quite good:

### 1. Fitness to Question

How well does the answer actually fit the question? If I ask a question like, "Did you go to the bakery and buy some cookies? If not, what did you buy?" The okay answer would be something like, "Yes. Malasadas." The great and correct answer would be, "I went to Liliha Bakery in Hawaii and bought not cookies, but malasadas for $4.49, with tax."

The answer should fully answer the question; otherwise, it's a half-answer, not a full-answer, even if the actual technical issue cannot be solved.

### 2. Fitness of Answer

Is the answer of a high quality? Does it fit Stack Overflow's guidelines?

Is it...

- clear?
- concise?
- relevant?
- completed with examples (specifically, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))?
- written with proper grammar?
- once again, specifically helpful to you?

Comment: If you're going to be specifc, you should be aware that StackExchange advocates the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) over the SSCCE. More info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283437/330057).

Comment: Answers do not require examples, neither an MCVE nor a SSCCE. That's something we expect for questions that are about specific pieces of code, such as debugging requests.

Comment: Proper grammar isn't that important. Anyone can edit the answer and fix it in a matter of seconds.