# Close reason when purposefully provided incorrect information?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is the desired close reason when a question is purposefully provided with incorrect information?

According to the January changes outlined in [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow), I think it could be one of two reasons:

- **"a simple typographical error"**
- **"it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem"**

I think **"it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem"** is the most appropriate reason.

I don't think **"a simple typographical error"** is appropriate because its *not* a simple or unintentional typo.

Is another reason more appropriate? Or is there a more appropriate action?

---

In my case, the context is usually web server configuration because I troll the [openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openssl), [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl), [pki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pki) and friends. In the web server configuration context, the question is often similar to the following.

> ```
> My site worked when it was HTTP, but it does not work when I added
> HTTPS. Here's my configure file:
> <Config>
>     server = somesite.com
>     ...
> </Config>
> ```

My first step in trouble shooting is test the site or server with OpenSSL's `s_client`. `s_client` will tell me if SSL/TLS is available, what the server's certificate looks like, and what the certificate chain looks like.

After running `s_client`, I often discover the information was bogus. Rather than using `example.com`, which is reserved by ICANN for the purpose (and alerts me and others), the person will hijack someone else's domain to ask a question (which is often not configured for SSL/TLS in the first palce).

And it sometimes leads to a debate like at [SSLError on requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707625/sslerror-on-requests-module). For questions like that, I'd prefer to disengage and point back to a Meta discussion on the subject.

Before saying "just add a comment", please consider: this problem happens multiple times a day - its not a one-off issue that happens on occasion. And comments sometimes engage the person to argue their case (which I'm not interested in being a part of).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be
>   reproduced or a simple typographical error.** While similar questions
>   may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to
>   help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and
>   closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the
>   problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

For the specific question you cited, the "Questions seeking debugging help must include..." close reason works also.

Comment: Why does **"it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem"** not the most appropriate? Its not a simple typo, and it *does* lack the required information (which implies it lacks sufficient information).