# How to mark a fixed problem?

Tags: feature-request

I asked a question about a problem whose root cause was primarily a bug.

I got answers about workarounds which I accepted.

Now in the meantime this bug has been fixed, and I think we can close the question.

The problem is, if I start for voting to close the question their is no option for this.

There is only:

- duplicate: make no sense
- off-topic: not applicable, it was a problem of programming
- unclear: no, I got an answer
- to broad: no, I got a very specific solution
- primary opinion based: no, it was a very specific technical problem

So I would suggest a further option like in most other issue tracking tools on the marked:
"fixed" or "root cause fixed" with a additional comment on it.

I don't think it is a good idea to add a further answer link "fixed now in this version" and e.g. switch the accepted answer. At that time the question was answered, it was a good solution and saved me time. Therefore I would like to honour this.

Why do you think?

UPDATE:

First here some comments:

1. Close means NOT delete, all information of a closed question are still available.
2. To close a question you have to vote for it, it is not a decision of a single person.

From my perspecive if the root cause of a problem is bug I think it is a common approach to mark this problem as fixed, all issue tracking tools have this option. Maybe the inital question was wrong and the focus only on close was to specific.

Again this is a feature request, therefore

- I suggest to mark a problem as fixed and this should not "disappear" in a list of several answers, It should be clearly added on top. If i have this information I like to provide it to all to a efficient way. I could just write it in the text, but I think haveing this information an a structual from it can be analysed and help may for the business case of this site.
- I suggest to have the possibility to close a problem if it is fixed (and i am pretty sure no one will have it again.) Remember this is a voting topic and is REALLY dependent on the situation.

To make it more clear, the case I am talking about is a problem in beta4 of xcode6 and in beta5 it was fixed. As far as the final version is publish, no one care anymore about all those versions. This is just one example I am pretty sure there several similar of this.

Comment: SO is not a forum. On forums questions usually 
get closed when solved. On SO someone can always find a new way to phrase an answer or suggest an alternative solution. Though in some specific cases you may indeed be able to say _"This is the definitive answer, nobody can ever answer this again"_, I don't think that's necessary. Can you explain what _problem_ your suggestion will solve? @Others: closing doesn't mean deleting, it just means no more answers can be added.

Comment: That the bug is fixed doesn't mean the information how to work around it should be removed. There may be people who still have to use an affected version for whatever reason and thus need the workarounds - as an anecdotical example, you'd think any issues with the ancient jython 2.1 would be obsolete by now; but apparently the latest IBM websphere still ships with that exact version. Thus I'd recommend including the information that the issue is fixed in version X into the question, or commenting on the accepted answer and asking the answerer to include this information in his post.

Comment: Ok maybe it helps with a specific case [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669403/macos-swift-framework-testing-fail). In this case it was a problem in XCode6 beta3 & 4 and it is fixed in Beta5. I think no one will use any beta in productive situation. Therefore this problem is just OBE now. But the answer for beta4 worked fine and therefore the solution is ok. Now just the root cause is gone.

Comment: Again, can you explain what problem your suggestion (closing a question after someone thinks the problem is solved) solves? What happens currently that you don't want to, that can be prevented by closing "solved" questions?

Comment: Regarding your edit, `Close means NOT delete` - closing means "this question should not have been asked on SO". Closed questions are also automatically deleted after a few days unless they have upvoted/accepted answers, as the system assumes that these could be valuable (unlike the now-closed question). So closing is definitely wrong here. And `to mark a problem as fixed`, you _accept an answer that fixes the problem_. You're right that your case (beta software) is a bit special. In that specific case you could unaccept the answer and then delete the question, but why bother? Just leave it be.

Comment: @l4mpi ok according the documentation a closed questions get NOT deleted automatically, a further voting is required.

Comment: Related to a fixed marking: I still think we have to distinglish between fixes and workaround. A problem by be fix in 2.x but many user may still use a 1.x version therefore is would like to marke an problem as fixin "2.0" but keep the problem open for 1.x and collect posible solutions related to it. I think this is a logical improvement of this platform. From the prio I would suggest first to have the fix feature. The closing feature is the logical next step.

Comment: @Stephan Whatever you read is wrong or incomplete, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/226398 - the parameters for question deletion get tuned every once in a while, AFAIK they have recently been changed to delete more questions. Regarding your second comment: "fix" and "workaround" are a completely meaningless distinction for most of the questions on SO; it only makes sense for issues caused by bugs. And in cases where the distincion is meaningful, of course we need to distinguish between them, which should be done _by prominently including that information directly into the answer_.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this question should be closed. Instead it is relevant to answer it with the information about the newer version that fixed the problem.

I suggest to even accept that answer so people can see the 'best' option is to upgrade. Optionally, if available, you can add a version specific tag to the question to make it stand out more.

I don't think there is a need for another close reason. There can be new workarounds for this problem.

Comment: This is IMHO related from the question. It make sense in some cases and it make not sense in other situations. Therefore closing is a voting and it is not done just by one person. If (i think) 50 people think the situation is ok to close, what is the problem or the risk?

Comment: It has no need to. What if the workaround *is* necessary for a large group (since they are stuck on a specific version) and someone finds a better workaround, why should we prevent posting it?

Comment: Yes in this case it maybe make no sense to close. If a product is still in use for many people this make no sense to close. But each product have a life-cycle, and in some cases they are very fast (e.g. in my case it was just a issue of beta4).   All what I want is the possibility for the commuity can vote for it to close an issue. At the moment i wrote this just in a comment. I like to have a way to communicate this issue is fixed. All bug tracker have a fix state.

Answer (score -8):

I think the 3rd closing reason in off-topic works best (removed emphasis of typo):

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Since this has been resolved in newer version, it is unlikely that *new* workarounds are needed. The answers (old workarounds) don't go anywhere.

Though, it would be better to put the necessary version information into your question so that users with the newer version are not confused.

Comment: Nope, that's totally not what this close reason is for - the problem _can_ still be reproduced by anyone using an affected version. "Can no longer be reproduced" describes a problem which could not be reproduced by anybody else except for OP, and which OP himself now can't even reproduce either; e.g. a random build error in eclipse which goes away after cleaning the project, or similar problems that solve themselves and nobody even knows why they occurred in the first place. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252585/1110381, shog calls them `"the problem went away" questions` here.

Comment: That depends if all the necessary version information is present in the post. If somebody with a newer version tries to reproduce the behavior, but the version is not clear from the question, this close reason is perfectly valid. I guess that emphasis should be on *no longer* because from this version onwards it is no longer reproducible.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: If you know that it only affects software till version X, then comment so / edit the question.

Comment: No too, i can reproduce it with the right version and I even created a bugreport for it.