# How to handle question about application bug that is fixed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked [a question about a limitation in IBM Blueworks Live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768949/is-there-any-way-to-import-visio-2013-vsdx-diagrams-into-ibm-blueworks-live) that has been fixed in a recent release.

Based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268242/how-to-mark-a-fixed-problem) it sounds like the general protocol is that the question should be closed but not deleted in case other users are working with older versions and can still use any workarounds that have been suggested.

For this question there isn't very much useful discussion and I believe the update that fixed the bug was automatically pushed to Blueworks environments (it was in our case), so I don't think this question is worth keeping around.

I have several questions:
  1) Is it appropriate to mark this question obsolete (or remove it completely)?
  2) If not, is it more appropriate to put this bug fix update as an answer, a comment on the question, or an edit on the question?
  3) As a user that doesn't have the reputation to vote to close the question or mark it obsolete, is there a way for me to request for it to be closed or marked obsolete?

Comment: You can flag for closure. I wouldn't delete in case there was someone using an old version. Definitely leave a comment/edit though.