# I don't understand why the following flags got declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

As you guys could see I was flagging these four things which are weren't helpful for future visitor, but got rejected and declined for further flagging.

[image]

1. *[Plunker is defective useless app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565947/plunker-is-defective-useless-app)*
2. *[What do I do to create an option file after I download and extracted MySQL server on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314105/what-do-i-do-to-create-an-option-file-after-i-download-and-extracted-mysql-serve)*
3. *[Any tips on how to integrate the code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314203/any-tips-on-how-to-integrate-the-code-block)*
4. [An answer to *Any tips on how to integrate the code block*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314203/any-tips-on-how-to-integrate-the-code-block/53314606#53314606)

For the 1st and 2nd, I wish to ask you guys whether it would be helpful or not for specific based and not a problem which is reproducible.

For the 3rd and 4th, it was a simple beginner mistake with a comment sufficient to be an answer. Which I felt unnecessary to be existing any longer. Yet there is someone who answers those question with two upvotes(!?). What's going on, Stack Overflow?

Comment: Flags are likely an inappropriate measure to take for these questions.  Hang tight, I'll put an answer together...

Comment: "Should be closed because it's been answered" -- That's not what closure is for. Questions aren't closed because they've been answered, they're closed because they don't meet the quality guidelines for this site. Further reference on the topic: [How to mark a fixed problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268242/7795130)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By convention, reserve flagging questions and answers for things that the community cannot deal with itself.

What this translates to is pretty simple; if an action taken by someone in the community cannot remedy a problem with a post, then flagging the content should be done.

This manifests itself in several ways:

- The post is overly and wantonly offensive - makes sense to flag for moderator intervention to be sure that they get the time out they deserve.
- The post is advertising a product without any attempt to answer the question - makes sense to flag it as spam.

Also note that these are "standard" flags.  Elect to use the custom moderator flags for a situation that *requires* significant detail and requires elaboration; for example, an edit war (multiple edits and rollbacks).

Typically, though, the community can handle the vast majority of actions needed to keep the site in functioning order.

- Bad answer?  Downvote it!
- Poor question?  Downvote it!
- Question seems to be a typo?  Close it as a typo!
- Question seems to be too broad?  Close it as too broad!
- Poorly formatted question?  Edit it (but be careful to not break the code by accident)!

Moderators don't need to be involved in anything like the above and flagging for their attention is counterproductive.

For your examples...

- The first question *could* probably be closed for a couple of reasons:  we don't support Plunker, and the problem likely couldn't be reproduced again.
- The second question is pretty vague so it's tough to figure out what the OP is asking.  You could elect to close that as "too broad" and leave a comment asking the OP to be explicit about how they're installing MySQL.  It's something that developers use so I don't *necessarily* see this question as being off-topic, although there are differing schools of thought on this.
- The question-and-answer combination looks fine to me and isn't worth downvoting or close-voting.  Someone asked a question.  They got an answer.  It doesn't seem like it's a typo.  **We have no close reason for "beginner" questions**, and shoehorning a reason into this space does more harm than good.

Comment: With the 1st question as the problem as you stated earlier and the 3rd as the question being too low of a quality, for once I doubt a matter of misplaced statement with no else would be improvable?

Comment: @mukyuu Close flag != moderator flag.

Comment: I would say the first question *could* be closed.  I'm hesitant to say it *should* be since I don't really want that question to get a whole bunch of attention so it could be cleaned up by the Roomba.  The third one - I'm just not seeing an issue with it.  Know that I know nothing of VB.net but even still, it reads like a question and answer which seems *fine*.

Comment: @Makoto For "Elect to use the custom moderator flags for a situation that requires significant detail and requires elaboration; for example, an edit war (multiple edits and rollbacks)." How could we know whether it was a situation like that? Is it counted whether your edit being overrided by higher rep user and not counted?

Comment: @Mukyuu:  There's an edit history on every post...if anyone is actively rolling back changes you've made to the post which are actually improvements to the post, then it's safe to flag and explain what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

> For the 1st and 2nd, I wish to ask you guys whether it would be helpful or not for specific based and not a problem which is reproducible.

I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking here, but have you considered following the advice that's been given to you to familiarize yourself with the existing close reasons instead of flagging for moderator attention?

> For the 3rd and 4th, it was a simple beginner mistake with a comment sufficient to be an answer. Which I felt unnecessary to be existing any longer. Yet there is someone who answers those question with 2 upvotes??? What's going on SO?

Doesn't matter. An answer to a question can be posted as one. If you consider yourself above answering a trivial question for rep, nobody is forcing you to. But that doesn't mean you can, or should, prevent others from or punish them for doing so.

Comment: You could've worded it better, but the problem is the 1st and 3rd is obviously a closable question. With the delay, it attracts such low-quality answer.

Comment: About "punish" - it's ok to downvote answers you think is *not useful*, answers on a trivial/typo question can be considered so.

Comment: @user202729: This is about flagging for speedy deletion, not downvoting.

Comment: @Mukyuu, if each are "obviously a closable question," what about the existing close reasons prevents you from using a normal flag instead of flagging for moderator attention? That's my understanding of why BoltClock is suggesting you review the reasons.

Comment: @Mukyuu: As the decline messages state, "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster." There are more serious problems that we need to prioritize over off-topic questions. An off-topic question getting a low-effort answer is not nearly as serious as 1) a user getting harassed 2) a user using multiple accounts to cheat the system or 3) a user vandalizing the site, to name a few.

Comment: Problem is the low quality reason which are given on [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer/167641#167641) is unsalvageable. Or whether it's should be closed "This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing." That's not the accurate description which I wanted it to be.

Comment: @BoltClock Do you have any other alternative then for the case which I mentioned earlier?

Comment: @Mukyuu: If it's a trivial question, but not otherwise off-topic, it's not grounds for closing no matter how bad you think it is. If it's missing required code or some other reason that fits the existing close reasons, then "should be closed..." followed by one of those reasons. Not a moderator-attention flag.