# Another closing reason

Tags: discussion

Do we need another closing reason for questions such as
"Asking for solutions without attempting a hands-on on it" ? so that it is more clear?

How do we close such questions now?

Comment: From what I've been told, there used to be a close reason for "lack of research" but they got rid of it. Most questions like this usually have at least one other problem that fits an existing close reason though.

Comment: It was ["lacks minimal _understanding_"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason), @BSMP; in other words "you are in over your head beyond our ability to write a helpful but finite answer". (See especially jmac's answer at that link, and for further reading also see: [What happened to the "you're just lazy" close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491)) This is now [supposed to be covered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) by "Too Broad" and "Unclear".