# Can we care a little more about quality instead of quantity, please?

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow [is about answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/):

> answers -- truly brilliant, amazing, correct answers -- are as rare as pearls. Thus, questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl.

The most brilliant answers [don't necessarily help the asker, but will at least teach OP and later visitors something](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315041):

> I attempt to answer questions in a way that helps other people who are reading the question, not [the OP].

When *I* am in the mood for writing an answer, I like it to first explain why the  OP is encountering the problem they are, then offer some alternatives, and finally present some trivial code that may or may not solve that problem for some specific instantiations of said problem.

Most questions however do not trigger this response of either me, nor other people willing to write such answers. Most questions boil down to a lack of experience in debugging and rubberducking. Indeed, most questions are actually a combination of multiple problems higher up in the stack (no, [reading *"What is a NullReferenceException"* isn't going to solve the problem that your query returns no records](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315643/are-broad-unspecific-questions-about-entire-topic-areas-preferred-over-specific/315664#315664)), or a lack in understanding spouting the typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. This actually [makes most questions "Too Localized"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns), one of the reasons that close reason was removed.

But you can't blame people for not knowing something, and you [can't close their questions for that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316028/extra-reason-for-closing-questions-or-a-modification-of-one/316032#316032).

What you *can* blame people for, and what I'm trying to aim for in this question, is posting poor-quality answers to ditto questions.

Do you *really* help the OP and the programming community in general by dumping fixed code without explanations? No search terms or links for them to learn more? The umpteenth version of an answer that is on the site hundreds of times already? Posting from your go-to [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) library of "useful snippets", without actually understanding what that code does?

What I'm trying to ask here of you, the answerers that make this site useful:

- **Do not guess**. If you don't understand the problem, ask for clarification using comments on the question. Don't post an answer. If the problem description is unclear or incomplete, downvote and closevote accordingly.
- **Search, then answer**. Really, most basic questions have already been asked and answered perfectly. No need to spread out knowledge over multiple answers. This is an actual problem. Google is already preferring other sites over Stack Overflow, which wouldn't surprise me to be caused by the massive duplication of oh-so-common questions and answers. Search for duplicates, and vote to close accordingly.
- **Explain and link**. If the code in your answer refers to certain principles, explain them. When you know those principles to be covered in other questions, link to them. The OP and later visitors can then visit those links, or search on the mentioned terms.
- **Edit the question**. There's *always* something to improve in a question (I dare you, [@Peter Mortensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen?tab=activity&sort=revisions)), especially when it's been asked a while ago. Cut the cruft, make it more broadly applicable. Remove irrelevant code.
- **Downvote**. Help answerers earn that sweet [Peer Pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure). When an answer is incorrect, contains outright incorrect statements or consists solely of a code dump that doesn't even attempt to address the OP's problem, downvote. It's not useful content for the OP or later readers.
- **[Make more canonical Q&As](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308371/how-to-organize-the-finding-or-writing-and-advertise-the-existence-of-canonical)**. This way you won't have to repeat yourself or others, but can simply link to canonical pages that perfectly explain what an ORM, DTO and other TLAs mean and can do for you.

So, what's my question, you ask? I don't know. Maybe this: do you agree? And if so, how can we point out to current and future answerers what really matters in an answer they post?

Comment: It's not that I disagree with your sentiment - I really do feel that people should be focused more on the quality of their answers more than the amount of answers they give.  It's just...this has been rehashed ***so*** many times before, and the whole "rep whore" stigma has left a bitter taste in my mouth.  It's like it's the new "accept rate" with which we instantly judge users by.

Comment: So if I remove my minor diatribe regarding "rep whore" from the above comment, I'm still not sure we need yet another rehashing of this sentiment.

Comment: The simple reality is that *vastly* more people actively encourage posting this kind of crap, so there really isn't much of anything that you can do.  If you tell people to actually downvote crap and encourage the people posting good answers, they're not even going to read those messages, and if for some reason they do, they won't care, and continue upvoting the people posting code only answers to someone else's homework assignment dump because, "the code works, so of course I'm supposed to upvote it."  You could go create a new site, and keep the crap out, at least until you flop or grow.

Comment: @Makoto the problem is still there, and hasn't been addressed to satisfaction. So I think it can't harm to shine a new light on it every now and then. The alternative would be to accept the situation as-is.

Comment: @Servy yeah, "strict overflow" or whatever. Ain't nobody got time for that.

Comment: @CodeCaster:  The people that *do* care about the quality of questions, answers, and edits on the site are generally people that participate on Meta.  In effect, you're preaching to the choir.

Comment: "you can't blame people for not knowing something, and [you can't close their questions for that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316028/extra-reason-for-closing-questions-or-a-modification-of-one/316032#316032)" Well, that or we could ignore the opinion of one self-contradictory moderator and do the right thing instead.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'd much rather just see an actual close reason be created (or an existing one edited) such that there would actually be a close reason that would actually apply to such questions, rather than closing questions for a reason that doesn't actually apply.

Comment: Oh, fully agreed, @Servy.

Comment: @CodeCaster, this suffers from the same problem of all documentation: the people who need it don't read it, and the converse. Who are you trying to address?

Comment: @Josh see the last sentence. I'm asking what we (frequent visitors, moderators) can decide to do about this, if anything.

Comment: Okay, I see that as an interesting discussion question; I just hadn't refreshed the page to see it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'd be interested to hear your views (as a comment on that answer) as to why I am "self contradictory" in that answer.

Comment: Not in that answer, @GeorgeStocker, and not on that subject, but on another perennial subject: NAA flags.

Comment: But I may have cast my net too broadly there, @GeorgeStocker, so I will apologize to you. (If you'd prefer to remove the adjective from my comment I do not object. Or it can stand as my error.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'd love to hear your reasons for me being self contradictory when I've talked about NAA flags; either I'll be able to explain why I think it's not self contradictory, or I'll walk away with a better understanding of why you do.

Comment: I'll up vote after Peter fixed your post...

Comment: How can we better discover canonical questions... that'd be a useful study.

Comment: I think [MichaelT highlighted it as well as it can be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290370/can-we-please-clear-misunderstanding-that-deleting-old-highly-upvoted-posts-caus), @GeorgeStocker, but, sure, I managed to scavenge these two for comparison: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275703/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284269/

Comment: The number of answers containing ["try this"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%22try+this%22) is twice as large as ["use this"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%22use+this%22). It seems a lot of answerers are not too confident. I usually try to *not* start with "try ..." Maybe the phrase "try this" should show one of the Red Popup warnings.

Comment: @Jongware That would be treating the symptom, not the root cause. Besides, content filters are easy to circumvent (not to mention annoying).

Comment: This question is based on the assumption that it is still useful or necessary to post elaborate answers.  It is just isn't.  The run of the mill question today just doesn't require that kind of answer.  They don't require an expert either.  Top rated answerers today are the people that dust these off at a high rate, dozens per day.  You can still invest time and energy in such an answer, nobody will stop you.  Given your stance, and mine, I recommend you do.  It is the only way you'll still enjoy spending your free time at SO.

Comment: @HansPassant - I am not disagreeing with you, but can you expand on why you believe that "*it just isn't still useful or necessary to post elaborate answers*"? I would be genuinely interested to hear some insight if you don't mind.

Comment: "*This actually makes most questions "Too Localized", one of the reasons that close reason was removed.*" And yet, the post you link to has data showing that "Too Localized" was the *least used* close reason. So I dispute your claim that it was removed because too many questions fell under that moniker. The given explanation for why it was closed was that it was rarely used and yet frequently *misapplied* and misunderstood. Its useful parts were replaced by other close reasons (like "it's a typo, STFU").

Comment: @TravisJ Your answer is in Hans' next sentences, "The run of the mill question today just doesn't require that kind of answer. They don't require an expert either." Simply put, the majority of new questions on SO are "gimme teh codes" or "how do I solve this very narrow and specific problem without applying my brain or using Google". There's a dearth of new high-quality questions that ask about in-depth things like compiler bugs or the implications of the choice of a specific algorithm in a specific language.

Comment: @Nicol that's why "Too Localized" is in quotation marks. The usage of that close reason represented community sentiment, not site policy.

Comment: Well thanks for closing this. I know it contains a lot of words, but check the last sentence perhaps? Close-voting a discussion is not the way to point out your disagreement.

Comment: I totally agree with this, and it would be in line with putting a time freeze before answers can be posted, this would be a good way to sort the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: I think you should post some suggestions about motivating users to raise their answer quality, they should raise their answer quality doesn't imply they are willing to do so, especially when your stated "low quality" answers are already enough to gain reputations...

Comment: @amuse right, but if I had a solution, I'd post an answer or a feature request. I'm merely looking for input from other members.

Comment: The whole text makes me bellow "YES! REVOLUTION!", except for this one statement: *"But you can't blame people for not knowing something"* - no? Well then I want the right to smack people in the head with a book. The most wonderful tool in the world that people refuse to use for their own benefit.

Comment: @IanKemp: "*There's a dearth of new high-quality questions that ask about in-depth things like compiler bugs or the implications of the choice of a specific algorithm in a specific language.*" You say that as though, in the past, there was a huge array of such questions just begging to be answered. The fact of the matter is, Stack Overflow has ***always*** has a majority of its questions be of the "give me teh codez". I was away from SO for 2 years, and from my perspective... it's no worse today than it was when I stopped posting in late 2013.

Comment: @Gimby "*The most wonderful tool in the world that people refuse to use for their own benefit*" You could say that about both the thing you are smacking with, and that which you smacked ;-).

Comment: *"how can we point out to current and future answerers what really matters in an answer they post?"* - that is an utterly hopeless task. **You're asking the wrong question**.

Comment: @Karoly why is it hopeless and what would be the right question?

Comment: As makoto said, "In effect, you're preaching to the choir". Trying to solve the problems by educating the questioners/answers assumes that once we educate people, things going to get better. Life doesn't work that way. SO is full of newcomers, who don't know anything about these efforts and will simply repeat the same mistakes until they learn the rules... and by that time the site is already full of fresh newcomers... it's an endless cycle. To solve some of these problems, you need a fundamentally new approach/interface/paradigm.

Comment: What the right questions would be? Something along the line of "How can we reduce the number of questions?" "What kind of interface do we have to build that solves most of the OP's problems without ever getting to the point that he has to post a question (that creates a zillionth duplicate)?"

Comment: In my opinion, the only way to achieve this in reality is to somehow turn Stack Overflow into a non-profit with a permanent guaranteed income to cover operating costs. Otherwise they'll never willingly sabotage their main avenue to revenue (yes, they make money from jobs, but the product they're selling to job posters is us, the user base).

Comment: There's going to be a paradigm shift, I'm sure of that. Whether SO is going to make the right steps toward that direction? Probably not. It has too much inertia.

Comment: @CodeCaster What, you don't think they're motivated by profit? Like *literally every other company out there*? First rule of business: make money. Any effective measure to return to the quality of yore would effectively castrate the growth of the site, and, therefore, the available pool of users targeted by Jobs and ads. SE isn't even profitable yet (since ever, even), so they're probably going to focus on making more money until they're net-positive.

Comment: @Tyler yeah I removed that comment, have to think about that some more.

Comment: It's just the nature of how a reputation-based privilege system works.  It's far easier to gain rep by answering 10 fairly trivial (or bad) questions, especially if you've answered a similar question before, than to toil and search for those few gem questions that could lead to a really great answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I joined Stack Overflow in 2009, when the site was still fairly new, and didn't perceive any quality problems until around 2012 when Jeff Atwood left. You might say this was because I've become more experienced and a better programmer in those 3 years, and/or because I started taking a more active role in the site (reviewing) around the same time... but I have a very clear memory of looking at the list of C# questions in those "early years" and seeing a bunch of high-quality questions with answers from guys like Jon Skeet. Today I look at the same list and it's just... bad.

Comment: @IanKemp: "*I have a very clear memory of*" It's hard to actually verify that, since low quality questions tend to be closed and automatically deleted. My memory from the C++ and OpenGL tags of 2011 is more or less the same as it is now. There's maybe a few more crappy "I'm making a crappy Minecraft clone, so how do I render cubes" questions these days. But overall, it's the same.

Comment: "try this" may indicate variance among, say versions of SSMS, VS, etc, as well as natural humility, and not just lack of confidence; not to mention one doesn't always have the relevant compiler handy, etc.)

Comment: @Joseph see [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/266143) for my stance on "try this" answers.

Comment: It's especially frustrating when I try to give that kind of in-depth, three-section answer -- only to have the OP accept a code dump (which maybe has fewer upvotes than my question). What that tells me is that the OP didn't want to learn or understand; they wanted just the simplest answer to the tightest scoping of their question. While I guess I can understand the "I just need to do this thing, can't you help me so I can get on with my work?" attitude, the idea of not wanting to generalize and learn is... sad.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not claiming my memory is perfect, or that I'm not looking back through rose-tinted spectacles. I'm also not claiming I haven't become a grumpy old man. :p That said, this particular memory is *extremely* vivid because I remember thinking "holy s__t, I found a site where I can actually get feedback on the 'whys' of C# **from people who either helped create it (Eric Lippert) or might as well have (Jon Skeet)**". That was a mindblowing experience for me.

Comment: For the future record, I finally remembered why in my head [I had George singled out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316112/can-we-care-a-little-more-about-quality-instead-of-quantity-please#comment302727_316112) in particular on NAA: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined/268413#comment145004_268369 It was his deletion of two Meta answers demonstrating the absurdity of the "stock" NAA reply.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This has been beaten to death on meta. I've posted like three or four questions saying the same thing, over the years. Nothing ever changes, and nothing ever will change. When it starts to really bother you, take a break for a while before the dark side starts gnawing at your soul. That's all you can do.

That is: ***do nothing.***

*(To be clear: I'm not blaming SE for not doing anything. I'm saying it's a fundamental societal problem and I've come to believe that we're stuck with it for as long as we're all human.)*

Comment: But everything *does* change! Every problem has a corresponding solution—we just haven't found the one to this yet.

Comment: @Anko: Not every problem does have a tractible solution. It's a good thing, too, otherwise the hackers would have won long ago (see: public-key cryptography) and I doubt we'd even be having this conversation!

Comment: So, if the problem are humans, why not just remove the problem?

Comment: @Braiam: Trump's working on it.

Comment: @Lightness _what_ did you change your nick to?

Comment: @Anko There is a solution. Unfortunately, it conflicts with Stack Exchange's goal of "make money".

Comment: @Braiam The problem is more specifically, *stupid and/or lazy* humans.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Inside joke ;p

Comment: If only we could build a *great big wall* around the southern border of this site to keep the bad questions out. And make the askers pay for it.

Comment: @CodyGray Clearly, the solution is to ban all questions until we can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 21):

I'm not a long time member or a high ranker by any means but so much of this rings true especially since I've just recently started Completing My Civic Duty by [reducing the Triage queue by 20 questions per day](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/). The amount of simply appalling stuff that appears in there is terrifying. And I'm not being big headed or thinking I'm sort of question asking god but it already seriously pains me to read through half the questions I see getting posted.

To me here are some of the issues that are causing *some* of the problems you are highlighting (in the same order as you've posted them):

- **Do not guess** - The nature of some problems mean you will not know what the actual issue is until several things have been tried, hence asking someone to try something as a suggested answer seems a sensible way to do it as it indicates you will continue to help if the given answer doesn't work (hopefully by editing in further assistance (rather than blatting the original) so as to show all possible remedies to future readers).

  Also comments for clarification don't get me rep. Whilst I'm busy asking you to clear something up in the comments someone else is busy writing an answer using the information I am drawing from you to write the answer I am working towards. See also **Fastest Gun in the West**.
- **Search, then answer** -  But then I won't get my rep since I'm not the Fastest Gun in the West. To this end I think we should **punish people for answering obvious dupes**. Nothing crazy, just remove the rep they got for answering (perhaps this happens already).
- **Downvote** - It costs rep to downvote and there are users with way more rep than me so why shouldn't they do it? Besides, if a question is *that* bad it'll get thrown on the trash heap anyway without it costing me anything.
- **Make more canonical Q&As** - Because when a user asks 'How do I get the SUM of these 2 fields in SQL?' they are really likely to want to read your 10 page, 3 year in the making answer on The Minutiae of SUM in SQL.

So for a large part I think the issues are caused by a running theme, **The (Perceived) Importance of Rep in Everything**. As a new user I was the same, I wanted to be taken seriously on the site and I (mistakenly or not) believed having a low rep score worked against me. Giving quick, correct answers even if they were duplicates, even if they were 'here is the codez', gains that initial rep that new users who don't know any better strive for.

Now that I'm above the initial 400 or so lower bound that many new users never pass I'm comfortable with my score and love getting it higher through **better** methods.

But the way I see it unless we actively discourage the gains gained through poor answers the problem won't go away.

SO can't tell people not to do something but still reward them for doing it.

*Please note my rep whoring attitude is tongue in cheek. I like rep but I prefer giving good answers that have rep as a side effect (and we all know badges are more important than rep anyway).

Comment: _"To this end I think we should punish people for answering obvious dupes. Nothing crazy, just remove the rep they got for answering (perhaps this happens already)."_ It doesn't. And it wouldn't actually punish anyone, because they'd still have the same amount of rep they had to start with ... _plus_ a little street cred from their cool answer. You'd have to dock some rep. I wouldn't support that — not everyone knows a post is a dupe when they answer it, even if they've spent some time searching for a dupe target, on a hunch, first.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvotes though. This all otherwise looks about right to me.

Comment: 1. If you can only guess what the problem is, don't pretend you can actually answer. Downvote, flag for closing, ask for clarifications. 2. Fact is that rep is earned and not ever revoked for dupes, due to insufficient downvoting/del-voting/close-voting and happy-go-lucky-upvoting. See next point. 3. Yes, it costs a tiny amount of rep, but if the post gets deleted, that's refunded. More downvoting makes that more likely, and if you hold back that makes it unlikely. 4. The canonical should be thorough, and if the asker doesn't want to learn, that's simply too bad for him. (..)

Comment: (..) He won't ever become a productive member that way anyway.

Comment: Punishing dupes one way or another has been proposed often, by various mechanisms.  Awarding good behavior seems to be easier to build a consensus around than punishing controversial (or even sometimes outright bad) behavior, so my proposal was to award badges and/or rep for consistent dupe and close voting, but so far, I have not seen any of the many proposal towards this end receive any substantial traction.

Comment: @PreferenceBean - "_And it wouldn't actually punish anyone, because they'd still have the same amount of rep they had to start with..._" - Exactly, they'd still have the same amount of rep but they'd have used their time to write an answer they are getting (in a rep sense) nothing for. That in itself is a punishment, albeit very lenient but intentionally so since as you said, not everyone knows a post is a dupe when they answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator - "_If you can only guess what the problem is, don't pretend you can actually answer_" - But EVERY answer you give on SO is a guess until confirmed otherwise. You can only ever believe you have the right answer for the question but before posting you can never be certain, even if **you** believe it 100%. Some questions don't deserve Dvote/Close but still have a degree of uncertainty about them. I reckon there is a level everyone has where they think if an answer is above N% probably right it is worth posting, for you it may be 100% for others 95%, others 2%.

Comment: @tripleee - "_ Awarding good behavior seems to be easier to build a consensus around than punishing controversial..._" - Why not both? :) Yup rewards for dupe closing sounds good. 'Improving SO 1 Dupe At A Time'

Comment: @Deduplicator - Thanks also for points 2 and 3, good to know more about how it works. Keep in mind though "_a tiny amount of rep_" is very relative. It would cost you 0.007% of your overall rep but it would cost me 0.372%, 53 times more! Quite a difference. And point 4 is sadly so, so true.

Comment: _"EVERY answer you give on SO is a guess until confirmed otherwise"_ - oh no, it isn't. I'm not talking about whether your answer will help OP. If you're not sure on _that_, then you either lack experience or the question is unclear. In both cases you should not post an answer. For every answer I post, I'm pretty damn sure that it fixes the problem stated in the question.

Comment: have a "popular question" badge (and some related badges) because one of my questions got lots of views... at the time, I needed an answer. I am altruistic, and glad it helped others, but if I didn't "need an answer now", I wouldn't have asked it.. Pretty sure this is true of the vast majority of questions here. We're software developers, not math professors ... stackoverflow.com/questions/334896/…

Comment: @CodeCaster - Pretty damn sure eh? So what's that, about 0.1% away from sure? ;-) Just read Yakk's answer on a (semi) related question about why we answer questions and it was pretty inspiring so dropping it in here as in may prompt people to answer better. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315041/971299

Answer (score 12):

The underling principle of Stack Exchange is that of gamification.  That you drive behaviour by awarding points.

It shouldn't be a surprise that people optimise for point scoring.

Writing an awesome answer to a difficult question is not a good way to do this. Because you probably score the same for a correct one liner response to a regex question.

Now, there are points of pride here, but certainly one of my higher scoring answers is very basic.

So you won't fix this problem until you address that. Until the scoring reflects "worthy" content, not just fast, correct and in a popular tag.

I don't know how, but maybe some bonus rep awards for a views to upvote ratio.  (If 90% of the people who saw it, upvoted, it is probably unusually good)..

Comment: I like your ratio idea. What bothers me most though is when "new users" don't accept deeply thought "awesome" answers, and your answer doesn't get any attention because the newbie used a cliche title and bad formatting.

Comment: @AaronGillion Crappy titles and bad formatting can and should be fixed by editing, and accepts don't really matter. What does suck is that awesome answers to obscure but interesting questions in low-traffic tags rarely get much attention. Even more so because hard questions take time to solve and good answers take time to write, so by the time the answer is posted, everybody has already moved on.

Comment: And if you stand to score more by improving the question, then that too is an incentive

Comment: I counter-intuitively suspect that your proposed views-to-upvotes ratio will, for positively-scored answers, actually be dramatically *negatively* correlated with answer quality. Why? Because most viewers on popular questions (which is where there's the most room for an answerer to truly shine and write something that makes the internet a better place) are random Googlers who don't have upvote powers, but most viewers of crap, low-view questions are established users who *do* have upvote powers. Your ratio will value people who answer crap fix-my-typo questions more than anyone else.

Comment: Point I am trying to make is that rep for upvote drives the wrong behaviour.  But yes, you may be right. Perhaps filter for upvote capability.  Perhaps just have an anonymous (useful) button?

Comment: Of course the ratio would be taking into account only people who can actually vote. Does the system keep track of specific views with account? Is it even thinkable?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes, anonymous feedback is tracked.

Answer (score 4):

It's a sad state of affairs and a sad state to be in, but a lot of high-rep users and even more low-rep users are actively caring about one thing only:

> How do I, for a given time investment, score the most reputation
>   quickly?

Any hint of following any of your procedures that you suggested does not do that and will thusly be ignored by these people at large.

Answer (score 4):

I do not answer often, compared to the frequency of my questions. When I do, it is usually debug help I offer. Most of my questions as a new user here, was lacking a lot of understanding, and had a lot of wrong assumptions. Most of all, I had no idea of what the different relevant methods/techniques/terms etc was called. I still struggle with that issue every now and then.

The five first bullet points are things that I am aware of, and try to live up to. The sixth not so much. Yet, This is an important thing that I will do more in the future.

The accepted answer here claims that "This has been beaten to death on meta. I've posted like three or four questions saying the same thing, over the years. Nothing ever changes, and nothing ever will change". You might be right, but status quo is a lot better than deterioating. I for one learned something from this post, and intend to become even better when answering questions from now on. These types of questions (not questions?) at least helps to educate the ever growing number of users, and might be the reason why stackoverflow, although not perfect, is the definitely best Q&A-community around for programmers.

Comment: What you say, about these types of not questions helping educating crowd, is beautiful in theory. Sadly, in practice, the ever growing amount of users sees an ever growing number of duplicates, broad and un reproducible questions. Not exactly sure where they will learn they shouldn't do the same...

Answer (score -21):

Sometimes you just need an answer.

Comment: truth is rarely accepted; however, if Microsoft has some strange bug that causes something to not work, I need a quick workaround, the chances dramatically increase such will exist with quantity.  Also, for particular situations that one encounters, it isn't always as easy as people think to either find a pre-existing answer on SO, or even anywhere on the web.  And we all know:  most Microsoft documentation is worthless.

Comment: NOTE:  most of the above can be generalized for people who don't work in the Microsoft stack...

Comment: if I have a specific problem, I'd rather see a "low quality answer" -- even one with the words "try this" (which may indicate variance among, say versions of SSMS, VS, etc, asa well as natural humility, and not just lack of confidence; not to mention one doesn't always have the relevant compiler handy, etc.) than no answer at all!  If too many "low quality answers" are deleted, than some specific problems will have no answer at all.... sometimes even a suggestion has helped me find my own answer, even though it didn't directly answer the question at hand.  Oh well...

Comment: Yeah, _you_. But this site isn't for the askers. If you need help _now_, it's best to not post on Stack Overflow. "Try this" and "see this link" answers are rarely helpful for later visitors.

Comment: ["there's no reason to keep questions around if the answers can't be found by the next person with the same problem"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: actually if it's not for the asker, it's of less value...

Comment: I have a "popular question" badge (and some related badges) because one of my questions got lots of views... at the time, I needed an answer.   I am altruistic, and glad it helped others, but if I didn't "need an answer now", I wouldn't have asked it..   Pretty sure this is true of the vast majority of questions here.  We're software developers, not math professors ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334896/clrdump-c-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-registerfilter8

Comment: even a question without any answers at all shows other people that someone is experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @JosephDoggie [How is that helpful?](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: believe me, it's good to know that is not unique to your system....