# 12,577 views and 0 votes. The differences in Stack Exchange Communities

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I happened to join another Stack Exchange community yesterday as I wanted my comment to be heard on a very opinionated question. It brought my attention to my points vs Badge ratio, and then to a particular question.

In [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) I have a score of 103. 100 for joining, then +2 for accepting the answer of my 1 and only question. *How this adds up to 103 is another question?*

My one and only question has had 12,577 views (at the time of writing). From this single question I have 1 Gold Badge (Famous Question), 1 Silver and 4 Bronze badges.

Yet both the question and accepted answer have 0 votes on them?

Now I am not really fussed about my reputation on this Stack Exchange site, but what about the people who are and find themselves in this situation? I read within another [meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316112/can-we-care-a-little-more-about-quality-instead-of-quantity-please/316212#316212)

> maybe some bonus rep awards for a views to upvote ratio

Would this be a good idea? Could something be done to assign upvotes based on a lack of upvotes to views?
Is this just something that is never going to change? I get the feeling that the different communities maybe don't feel the need to upvote when a question/answer helps them out.

I have no idea how many of those 12,577 views the question/answer has maybe helped since it was posted 4 years, 7 months ago.

**Edit**

I understand that views is not an indicator of quality, but with 0 votes of any kind, there is no way to judge the quality. I would have been happy to have had negative votes so I would know to improve the question, or have seen voting activity on the answer.

Comment: *How this adds up to 103 is another question?* - you start with 1, add 100 and add 2...

Comment: Not really. Views are not an indicator of quality. Views only mean that the title (and maybe content) are good click-bait / get high SEO ratings. There are plenty of terrible questions that get tons of views, and it would be detrimental to our system to start awarding them reputation just because their title is a good lure.

Comment: @animuson not to mention the HNQ sidebar is probably self-fulfilling in views...

Comment: @animuson Yeah I agree with this as I know there will be loads of bad questions/answers out there, however that is when you would use the downvote. But 0 voting activity in 4+ years?

Comment: I mean, who's to say it's not getting upvotes because it's low quality or poorly researched (or whatever the common downvote criteria is in said network?) Which vote should it get, up or down? A ton of  views and very few or no upvotes might indicate that it has a great title, but the question/answer doesn't match what people commonly visit the question for.

Comment: @JonClements ahh yes, you start with 1 :)

Comment: Perhaps people finding your question are coming from search engines and either don't have an account (or do but don't have the minimum to upvote) - so only a tiny amount of those 12k views could ever vote-up even if they wanted to.

Comment: Of course, the inverse of Jon's point is also true.  Those users coming that either don't have an account, or haven't earned much rep on their account, also can't downvote, in addition to not being able to upvote, so they simply can't provide *any* feedback on quality *in either direction*.  They might think it's good, they might think it's bad, but either way, we can't know.

Comment: There are [100 other questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a12577%20score%3a0) in a situation with the same score, more views.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now I am not really fussed about my reputation on this Stack Exchange site, but what about the people who are and find themselves in this situation?

Those people should simply stop being fussed about it, it's that easy.

It's possible that a question with over 10,000 views "deserves" a bunch of upvotes, but in the end it really doesn't matter at all.

Comment: We are going to hate you for it, but this answer is spot on. *It is my rep and I fuss over it if I want to.*

Answer (score 12):

How about I make a question like this?

> [TOP 10 REASONS WHY JAVA HAS THIS ONE SIMPLE TRICK THAT DEVS HATE](/a/358437/6388243)

Not to mention that this would encourage using a sock puppets or a botnet to rack up views on your question. Say, what if I google-bombed it to increase traffic from search engines? Or send out emails with a hidden iframes that load the question without their knowledge?

There are simply too many ways to abuse this.

Additionally, this is *not* specific to a single site. There are [*plenty*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000+score%3A0) of "famous" questions on Stack Overflow that have no votes.

Comment: [14,190](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000+score%3A0)

Comment: Missed a fantastic opportunity by not making that a link.

Comment: @CodyGray make what a link?

Comment: @StephenLeppik [TOP 10 REASONS WHY JAVA HAS THIS ONE SIMPLE TRICK THAT DEVS HATE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358437/1159478)