# Goodbye "off-topic", hello "community-specific reasons"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, user-experience

This is what I now see when I vote for closing:

[image]

i.e. the "off-topic" reason has been replaced with "A community-specific reason".

Is this permanent (and somehow I missed the announcement), or is it an experiment (for which I also missed the announcement)? Doesn't seem to relate to the [New Question Close Experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience), and I could not find anything in the [featured posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured).

Comment: There is a line in New Question Close Experience that says that they may be editing the text: *Changes to post notices have been rolling out over the last several months. We'll be continuously refining the content we show here based on user feedback.*

Comment: It's kind of like the "...and other duties as required" they tack onto your job description :).

Comment: Eh, I found the old dialog to be mildly confusing. After all, wouldn’t you say that too broad questions (for example) are off topic too?

Comment: Hmm, mixed feelings here. I never liked that "seeks debugging help" was under off-topic. Because it's *not* off-topic, what the actual close reason states is that it's a debugging question missing enough information. So, it didn't seem right to put it under "off-topic". However, things like "belongs on Super User" is most definitely off-topic. You can't more literal than "It should absolutely be elsewhere". The typo/cannot reproduce always seemed like grey area. It's basically "Not a bad question but can't help many others". An abstraction and slight classification of "too localised".

Comment: @Laurel yeah. It's like the close reasons are split into "can be made on-topic but requires <something>" and "most likely cannot be made on-topic" Yet even then not all fit. Like opinion-based belongs in off-topic and, like I said, "seeks debugging help" should be next to "needs details or clarity". The two sort of overlap some times, too.

Comment: @BSMP that's way too vague, and under the section *Edit UX Improvements*

Comment: "Off topic" also makes some people think we mean "unrelated to programming", because normally when you say something is off topic it's because it's a change in subject, when what we really mean is that it doesn't fit the rules. "A *community specific* reason" also points out that close reasons differ across sites. - *that's way too vague* - Maybe, but I'd bet money that they were talking about all the messaging around closing.

Comment: I presume the split is between reasons which appear on all sites and "community-specific reasons" which only apply to certain sites. And possibly this was always the case and now its just being made clearer that this is what the split is?

Comment: It's a really great and ingenious way to finally get rid of all these off-topic questions!

Comment: [Can we rename the off topic close reason label on the primary screen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024) [Shouldn't off topic be only about off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086) Finally complete after 6-8 time units.

Comment: Freaking finally! "Off-topic" was terrible, misleading UX.

Comment: Kudos in the use of Other - changes specified by user to provide convenient ability to duplicate that reason. (On downside - I can't give you the exact text because it won't let me look at the menu after having voted -- it is stuck at the [Retract Vote] -- that should be fixed)

Comment: What a menu! Needs improvement -> duplicate

Comment: @Laurel I do agree that the old text could've used some improvement. However, yesterday's change is the opposite of an improvement in my opinion.

Comment: I don't care really about the naming but why are these close reasons hidden away one additional click than the others? Are they less important or less often used? I never understood that and it seems like a bad decision to me. Just put them all in one list please.

Comment: @Trilarion The way I've always thought about it is that scanning through a list of 10-12 is... a lot all at once. It's too much. We've always tried to keep the list of options concise - it's why sites only get three site-specific reasons by default and have to have a strong argument to increase it. This way, the first page is the same network-wide and the second is specific to the site... It's not perfect but I think it's better than it was.

Comment: @Catija That's surely relevant for people curating across the network, but for someone only close voting on StackOverflow the "community specific category" wouldn't really be a meaningful categorization. One could maybe also just put the four general close reasons always on top of the list, then have a line separator and then put the remaining community specific reasons. It might be a bit faster overall. To me it feels like when making a close vote decision I have to have all the 8-12 possible close reasons in mind anyway.

Comment: @Trilarion If you find it annoying, you can check out my [One Click VTC](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/One-Click-VTC) userscript if you want

Comment: Suggest changing it to just "reasons"

Comment: Lol. ALL OF THEM are subtypes of "community reasons". It's the broadest reason ever! Doesn't meet guidelines... And what, duplicates are ok by guidelines :'D 
Should be named "Other" if you ain't got other ideas.

Comment: It's hilarious that there are people downvoting the *question*... :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The comments are... mostly correct. This was a change I pushed for so let me take you through my thinking.

Years ago, I answered this question on MSE: [Categories other than "off-topic" should allow custom close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons) - It was a problem I ran into on several of the sites I participated on and it looks like it also was a concern here ([from the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons/396597#comment765507_396592)):

> I never liked that "seeks debugging help" was under off-topic. Because it's not off-topic, what the actual close reason states is that it's a debugging question missing enough information. So, it didn't seem right to put it under "off-topic". However, things like "belongs on Super User" is most definitely off-topic. You can't more literal than "It should absolutely be elsewhere". The typo/cannot reproduce always seemed like grey area. It's basically "Not a bad question but can't help many others". An abstraction and slight classification of "too localised".

The [top answer from Nathan Tuggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267216/284336) gives a snapshot of what the close reasons looked like around the network at the time - many sites were in the same boat.

When I was asked to help work on [Phase 1 of the Close UX project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience#394871), there were some plans that would have addressed this somewhat but they also caused other problems so I suggested renaming "off-topic". We went through a lot of discussion to think about what the difference between the main page and the secondary page was - I even asked the mods about it on the Mod Team. I didn't get an answer that I thought was a better fit overall than my own.

For me, the big difference - the only consistent one - was that the front page was the same network-wide and the "Off-topic" page was full of site-specific reasons. On the recommendation of a moderator we chose "Community-specific" over my original recommendation of "site-specific". I still like the idea of adding custom close reasons to other categories but a simple text change was a much simpler solution and one I'm happy with.

I really hope that this change will help fix the problems we have with "Off-topic" not matching the content of the close reasons and also the various problems people have had understanding how questions about programming are off topic on this site. Now, people who have a question closed with a community-specific reason won't be confused when they see "off-topic" at the top of a question that isn't.

The other thing you can't see (unless you're a mod) is that we also changed the UI so that moderators can define the content of the post notice so that it matches the close reason more specifically rather than being generic text. It's more complicated to create one of these now but we hope the benefit for everyone will be worth it - plus, these reasons aren't created often.

[image: Screenshot of a new mod-interface for creating close reasons with sections to fill out with a description, usage guidance, and post notices for different user types.]
(Click for full size)

---

> Doesn't seem to relate to the New Question Close Experience,

It is! As I mentioned briefly, it's Phase 1 -

> #### Phase 1
>
> This first phase is made up of foundational changes and does not yet introduce the new concepts of automatic reopen or hidden questions. These are things we’d likely do anyway and provide the groundwork for the other phases.
>
> - **Updates to close/off topic dialogue reasons** <<-- This one
> - Updated editor for closed questions - pulling from the new Ask a Question design pattern, this provides better guidance through the editing flow.
> - Email and inbox notifications about closed questions - users will first receive an inbox notification when their question is closed. If the inbox notification isn’t seen, an email is sent to encourage them to make edits.

Now, granted, it's pretty easy to miss and it's not got a lot of detail. It's a long post and we were trying to give an overview.

Comment: Good, now I can finally restore the information that got lost from the close reasons during the last redesign. :-)

Comment: Would you mind addressing that the flag dialog got slightly different wording as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396599/unable-to-see-off-topic-option-while-flagging

Comment: @rene I don’t have an answer there but I’ll see what I can get.... when I wake up.

Comment: I quite like the different wording. It's less confusing. I'm however not fond of the removal of the ellipsis. I was initially confused about what choice brings up a new dialog. The "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" has consistently been missing the ellipsis. Now all of them do. Please bring them back. Then there's the size and font blowup of the dialog when picking "needs improvement" which is way to big. I hope the latter is a bug that's soon to be fixed.

Comment: I think it is horrible, mainly because I don't think migration to another site - to name just one - is not site specific at all. Furthermore, I think I've explained many times what I think of these unanounced changes. I think I made it pretty clear when it came to the app for instance. I am not waiting when a significant change is made that I have to look up what happened using a Google search for a meta. I thought SE team was going to communicate.

Comment: I absolutely hated the last time the close reasons were changed but I got used to them, now they have changed again, and the change is even worse then before.

Comment: Thanks. I would expect an announcement though, especially for something that common that has been there for ages; the quote from the long post is too vague and general, and even after the fact, nobody from the commenters seemed able to make the connection.

Comment: Current state looks like a big mess to me. On reopen review queue I see "It was initially closed as Not suitable for this site", no subreason available. When I click on the question, I see "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.". No subreason either. On close votes review queue I see "Not suitable for this site: It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." Good, subreason present. (1/2)

Comment: When I decide to close, I see "A community-specific reason" Am I taking part in some A/B testing? (2/2)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396613/not-suitable-for-this-site-off-topic-a-community-specific-reason-a-call-for-c

Comment: doesnt this deserve some kind of more visible announcment? Today and yesterday I noticed text of close reasons changed and the top result i found when searching for "close reasons change" is a 6 year old question about [Recent changes to close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @idclev463035818 There's one in the works. Been looking at it since yesterday but it still needs to be finalized and posted. Apologies for the delay. :(

Comment: Thanks for this change! It's a big improvement!

Comment: I think theoretically this is better than 'off topic', but the line below could actually be the title of that option: "Doesn't meet Stack Overflow guidelines". That's way more concrete than the current title. The explanation could then read" This question doesn't meet some of the community -specific guidelines for Stack Overflow", maybe followed by a link to those specific guidelines.

Comment: I'm wondering why the wording is not run past anyone on the Stack Exchange site for writing, linguistics or whatever. The wording, to me, is often vague, confusing, non-specific, etc. This new wording is just as bad if not worse.

Comment: Very disappointing that SE.inc springs these features unannounced. "Updates to close/off topic dialogue reasons" can mean literally _anything_. Since we are the ones using these features completely voluntary, we could at least be notified that a change has taken place. Mind you, not even "consult with us" (that ship has clearly sailed), but at least "tell us". Otherwise, even with the new corporate policy in place, you are simply doing SE.inc a disservice.

Comment: And why, when you vote to close because *"it belongs on another site"* does it only offer you a pathetic choice of 4 other sites and never the one it actually belongs on, i.e. AskDifferent or RaspberryPi. Surely you should be able to select from a list of **all** SE sites?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no. It’s by design. There’s many posts about it on MSE and MSO. Mods can migrate anywhere.

Comment: I like the new wording and the new look _except_ for the button being on the lower left instead of the lower right.

Comment: This is AWESOME! What a great direction to go in, fully support this change.

Comment: Meh... *"A rose by any other name would still smell as sweet"*, Off-Topic was short clear and concise. "A community-specific reason" doesn't even hint at what it does from a linguistic standpoint. (the other changes that came along with the name change are great) I'm just not sure the name change itself was needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - Off topic was short, clear, concise, and completely misleading.

Comment: I could go either way. It's not a big deal, and I apologize if the comment insinuated it was (seems I've picked up `Meh...` as a euphemism from my son at A&M) The change was a head snap at first -- and if you read the buttons together [Close][A community specific reason] it makes sense, but since they are separate pages, the Off-Topic (which corresponds the the page Off-Topic) made more sense to me.

Comment: I agree that swapping the sub-title and title around would help this make more sense.

Comment: An issue with the new implementation is that if I vote to close for some _"community-specific reason"_, I cannot later go back and verify that I selected the appropriate close reason. I get "You have already voted to close this question", and I am blocked from revisiting the _"community-specific reason"_ screen. My only option is to click the "Retract Close Vote" button. I don't know if that issue always existed, and I'm not sure whether it should be classed as a bug or a usability problem, but it's a limitation that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I feel like I've run into this in the past, @skomisa I don't think that behavior changed but I can check. I remember being able to see the top-level vote (broad, unclear, etc) but not the off-topic ones.

Comment: @Catija Yes, it may have always been that way. Regardless, it seems an odd constraint that I can review some of my close reason choices, but not all of them.

Comment: @skomisa See [I can no longer see the close reason I chose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346516/289905).

Comment: @user4642212 Interesting. I hovered over `close` for a question I had voted to close a couple of hours ago, and the approach described in an answer from your link (hovering over `close` displays a tooltip) works, but the reason stated _"You voted to close as 'Not suitable for this site'..."_ is obviously wrong, since that is not even presented as an option for closing a question. So even the workaround, which is not intuitive at all, doesn't work.

Answer (score -4):

Well, the true answer is that you are now discourraged from writing any hints in the comment to inform the OP. While in the past you could write

> Your question is OT. Please read the help

you now have to write

> Your question is subject to be closed due to a community specific reason. Please read the help

Comment: You don't have to write anything. That message should be conveyed by the close post notice. The bickering in comments is what makes this community be seen as unwelcome. If we lock down our self to only rely on post-notices at least the "system" is seen as unfriendly, not the care takers in this community. Use your comments on those posts where you feel your intelligence is appreciated and will lead to awesome content for future visitors.

Comment: @rene Hail the system. I always appreciate when I get DV uncommented. So I'll blame the system in the future.

Comment: @qwerty_so: It's imho not a bad thing to explain why a question will be closed in a comment **if the comment is specific to the post and gives op information on how to improve**. Leaving "Your question is OT, Please read the help" is imho worse than writing nothing because it helps op no more than the close message but makes it more personal. "Please include some code, especially where you do X and Y" is helpful because it tells op what to do.

Comment: @BDL Well, this is something you see often for newbies which actually did NOT read the help. I didn't when asking my first questions here until someone actully wrote about reading the help. Seems the guys working with SO for so many years simply forgot how new people get here. They first ask. And maybe later they read the help. Just like any IT guy will do.

Comment: The can still read the help when the question is closed. The close message points them to the help anyway.