# Unable to see off-topic option while flagging

Tags: discussion, flags

Is off-topic removed from the options at stackoverflow?

[image]

Comment: You have to navigate to "Needs Improvement". I guess they're trying to make things "friendlier", though it makes more sense to do that for those *receiving* the close message, not those *choosing* it

Comment: A topic about almost the same thing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396592

Comment: In Needs Improvement too, there is no off topic

Comment: @CertainPerformance The argument can be made that by making it friendlier for closers, more users will choose that option as well. Some users would have feel uncomfortable picking an option with "harsher" language may be OK with "needs improvement".