# UI Bug in The Triage Queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

I have been experiencing a UI bug in the Triage queue since today; when I clicked on the <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button, it would bring up a window for flagging (i.e., "***spam, rude or abusive, needs improvement, a duplicate, needs moderator intervention***") instead of the usual window I would normally see in the past when I'd click on the <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button.

I have yet tried clicking on other buttons such as <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>, <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> just to see if the bug exists only for the <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> button, mainly because the posts I have come across, coincidentally, today have not warranted the use of those.

Thanks.

---

[image]

Comment: Related: [Goodbye “off-topic”, hello “community-specific reasons”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons), [Unable to see off-topic option while flagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396599/unable-to-see-off-topic-option-while-flagging). I was also just surprised by these changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, SE chose remove any indication that some of those selections open further popups (in addition to changing "should be closed" to "needs improvement"). The information you're missing is that "needs improvement" is "should be closed" and selecting it opens the close-vote or close-flag dialog. In your case, given that you have > 3k reputation, it will open the close-vote dialog. The "a duplicate" selection also opens those dialogs, but navigates directly to the duplicate selection pane.

Comment: the whole triage queue UI is a bug in itself. "unsalvageable" meaning "salvageable by OP editing", and "requires editing" getting you banned for daring to suggest the OP needs to edit their post. furthermore, Carthage must be destroyed. I mean, **yelLow bLocKquOtes mUst be ResTorEd.**