# Not suitable for this site? Off topic? A community-specific reason? A call for consistency

Tags: bug, close-reasons

It's a followup to [Goodbye “off-topic”, hello “community-specific reasons”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons)

The idea of changing close message from "Off topic" to "Community specific reason" and revealing the specific reason, which got hidden during last UI change looks good, but the implementation apparently missed something.

**Let's have a look at reopen queue:**

> [image: It says "Not suitable for this site", no specific reason shown]

It says "Not suitable for this site", no specific reason shown.

**Now let's click on the question:**

> [image: "Off-topic", no specific reason shown]

Here we have good old Off-topic without specific reason shown.

**Now let's go to close votes queue**

> [image: "Not suitable for this site" with specific reason]

This one looks best, as it shows specific reason.

**And now let's vote to close**

> [image: "A community specific reason"]

Here "Not suitable for this site" changed to "Community specific reason".

So there are three different messages for the same thing and only in some cases specific close reason gets shown.

Comment: I have given up.  If a question needs closing, I click on one of the radio buttons at random.

Comment: @MartinJames that's fine. You usually have a very high chance to pick a relevant reason anyway.

Comment: I just let my fingers retrieve the correct position of the close vote from memory.