# Inconsistent conjunctions with new community close reasons

Tags: bug, close-reasons

The new close reasons have inconsistent verbage - some have "and" and others have "or". I would prefer "or" to be more consistent and allow for flexibility/clarity:

[image]

The "About general computing hardware and software" reason seems to imply the question *must* be about *both* hardware *and* software.

The "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries and more" seems to imply all 4 must fit. "More" is also ambiguous, for that, I'm also missing the "off-site resource" clause. It's not only opinion-based answers, but they tend to lead to spammy answers or broken link answers as well.

`/rant` over.

Comment: [I haven't had a chance to copy-edit these yet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons#comment765558_396597)... :-)

Comment: @CodyGray who did you piss off to be given that job?  :)

Comment: It is actually the way I piss other people off, @Martin.

Comment: Lol;) .............

Comment: Heads-up: [there is now an official announcement for the closure dialog changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1). I would suggest the bug report there.

Comment: @philipxy to me semicolons don’t mean a conjunction but a joining of related sentences

Comment: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear." "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." So semi-colon means "and" & it means "or". This canonical example epitomizes the extremely poor writing in the SO/SE use documentation. And the poor design of the underlying model it tries to document.

Comment: "joining of related sentences" is a vague general statement about natural language that that does not help to give meaning to these sentences. It is not clear what is trying to be said about "this question" by either sentence. (The semi-colons may well both be intended to mean "and", but then *the conditions overlap*. It may be intended that the semi-colon be taken "obviously" as "and" once & "or" once by the form of each entire sentence but that is obscure & unclear writing.)

Comment: I don't think the **"and more"** part should be changed to **"or more"** though because it won't make sense. Perhaps something like **"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, _etc._"** would be clear enough? It implies "OR" rather than "AND", IMO. Still ambiguous though. P.S. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @41686d6564: Agreed - [Steve Bennett's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1#comment766656_396769) on Daniel's answer to the post linked above suggests the same. (Steve also suggested there that the first "and" be changed to "or".)