# Close reason "seeking recommendations" text is still wrong

Tags: bug, close-reasons, recommendation-questions

The "seeking recommendations" close reason text is:

> Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more

There are no questions seeking recommendations for books *and* tools *and* libraries *and* other stuff. I've reported the "and more" typo before and it got "status-completed" (I can't find the meta post), but it was evidently not completed. It should say something like:

*Seeking recommendations for books, tools, libraries **or** other off-site resources*.

...like it did before someone decided to change it to the worse, just for the sake of changing things.

Comment: [Inconsistent conjunctions with new community close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396633/8967612)

Comment: Also reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396769/8967612).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's basic logic. You can use "and" when the purpose is to list things and all of them apply. "Recommendations that are off-topic: books and tools and libraries and more" All of these are off-topic. It can be better written as "books, tools, libraries and more". You cannot use it when the purpose is to tell that someone that they did one out of several things. This is wrong: "Your question was closed because it was seeking recommendations for books and tools and libraries and more". Unless someone did actually post a question asking for all of that. It should have said "or".

Comment: To avoid any ambiguity in interpreting conjunctions, how about a rewrite: "Seeking recommendations for off-site resources such as books, tools, libraries etc."