# "It does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines guidelines"

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions

[image]

Double "guidelines", one inside the link and one outside, should be removed.

Comment: That text was recently updated to be more consistent with our other close reasons, which is where this was introduced. It requires a staff member to make the edit, but otherwise should be an easy fix whenever one of them has the time to address it.

Comment: How does this sort of stuff get past QA to production? It doesn't seem like a rare occurrence... | Maybe... Is this just an edit in a production system, and there are no reviews done? So just broken process? Still quite puzzling.

Comment: @DanMašek the established procedure at SE is that they release a build and we as user community spot issues and report them, then the developers fix them (sometimes, and with response times ranging from minutes to years).

Comment: @DanMašek modern development is to release fast. When you release fast, you can also fix fast. There is no life or death situation here, this is not healthcare software. So nobody needs to go on the stake for not having costly QA cycles, minimum cost QA is good enough.

Comment: Are there any other related updates that need to be made to this close reason, while it's being edited? It's easy enough to fix this issue alone, but if there are any other changes needed here, we might as well implement those at the same time. (For instance, I found [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410999/1478931) about the improper use of "and more" at the end of this close reason ([this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396633/1478931) is closely related).)

Comment: "Double... should be removed." I eagerly await the fix that updates the message to read: "It does not meet Stack Overflow." ;)

Comment: This is why it matters that I'm talking to a person, and one who knows that would be a bad idea, not a robot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is fixed. We recently updated some of the guidance for this close reason (connected to its usage on the Staging Ground. Was my bad for not double-checking my work when copying it in.

> double repeated
> redundant "guidelines" word is
> not an issue now