# Questions closed as "other" still get described as "off-topic" in the post notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, post-notice

Despite the happy burial of the term "off-topic" as a closing reason as [recently announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons), I have just stumbled upon a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219073/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-o-desenvolvimento-de-uma-rede-lstm) just closed as, well, off-topic:

[image]

For what it may worth, the question was closed under "*A community-specific reason -> Other - add a comment*" as a non-English one. The template text there looks OK - "*I’m voting to close this question because*", i.e. no mention to off-topic, as was the case before.

I post this as a bug, as [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396592/goodbye-off-topic-hello-community-specific-reasons/396597?noredirect=1#comment765757_396597) by Catija in the comments of the other relevant thread linked above.

In any case, it seems that it will take a while for hunting down and exterminating all references to "off-topic" - maybe we should start from the descriptions of the Meta tags [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) and [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Catija's help, the brief explanation displayed in the close notice has now been updated.

Instead of:

> **Closed.** This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

It now says:

> **Closed.** This question does not meet [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

This brings the post notices in line with the descriptions that are displayed in the close reasons dialog box.

The Help Center page that is linked in the message still needs to be updated. That is on the to-do list.